# Fazer conexão no oracle 11 c

Tags: java, jdbc

Estou tentando conectar no oracle 11 c e a conexão não é realizada. Dá o erro:

> Erro de ES: Got minus one from a read call >

Estou testando a query numa servlet, ainda não estou buscando pelo formulário. Vejamos:

```
package connection; 

import java.sql.Connection;  
import java.sql.DriverManager;  
import java.sql.SQLException;  

public class Connect {

    public static Connection conexao;
    private static String servidor = "jdbc:mysql://127.0.0.1:3128/";

    public static boolean conectar() {
        try {

            Class.forName("oracle.jdbc.driver.OracleDriver");

            conexao = DriverManager.getConnection("jdbc:oracle:thin:@127.0.0.1:3128:xe", "andre", "root");
            if (conexao == null) {
                return false;
            }
        } catch (ClassNotFoundException e) {
            System.out.println(e.getMessage());
        } catch (SQLException e) {
            System.out.println(e.getMessage());
        }

        return true;
    }

}
```

#### Código para fazer a query:

```
package hospede;  

import java.io.IOException;
import java.sql.ResultSet;
import java.sql.SQLException;
import java.sql.Statement;

import javax.servlet.ServletException;
import javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet;
import javax.servlet.http.HttpServletRequest;
import javax.servlet.http.HttpServletResponse;

import connection.Connect;

//@WebServlet("/Hospede")
public class Hospede extends HttpServlet {
    private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;

    @Override
    protected void doGet(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response) throws ServletException, IOException {
        testar();
    }

    @Override
    protected void doPost(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response) throws ServletException, IOException {

    }

    private static void testar() {
        boolean conectado=Connect.conectar();
        String query = "select * from hospede";
        Statement busca = null;
        try {
            if (Connect.conexao!=null) {
                busca = Connect.conexao.createStatement();
                ResultSet resultado = busca.executeQuery(query);
                System.out.println(resultado.getString("nome"));
            }
        } catch (SQLException e) {
            System.out.println(e.getMessage());
        }
    }
}
```

Obs: Na linha  `conexao = DriverManager.getConnection("jdbc:oracle:thin:@127.0.0.1:3128:xe", "andre", "root");` O `xe` é o tipo de serviço? O arquivo que eu baixei é ojdbc6.jar.

Comment: Oi André, vamos tentar quebrar o problema em pedaços menores. Que erro você recebe ao tentar conectar? Consegue conectar de algum outro cliente (e.g., SQL Developer) da sua máquina ao host?

Comment: !Anthony Accioly consigo conectar na tela de comandos do oracle.

Comment: A sua `"jdbc:oracle:thin:@host:3128:nome do serviço"` está exatamente desse jeito no programa ou você colocou `host` e `nome do serviço` aqui em substituição ao que há de verdade em seu código para esconder detalhes confidenciais?

Comment: @Victor Stafusa
 nada a esconder. Eu não sabia o que é esse serviço, por isso não coloquei corretamente. Já editei o código.

Comment: Tenta o seguinte `jdbc:oracle:thin:@//localhost:1521:xe` (a não ser que você tenha [mudado a porta padrão](https://docs.oracle.com/cd/E17781_01/server.112/e18804/network.htm#ADMQS167)). Outra coisa, ao invés de imprimir o `getMessage()` tente obter o stack trace inteiro (`e.printStackTrace()`).

Comment: @Anthony Accioly
 a porta eu mudei porque estava usando a 8080 e estava dando conflito com o tomcat.

Comment: André, porta http e porta de conexão são diferentes. Veja o link do comentário acima (você encontra a porta de conexão no arquivo `listener.ora`).

Answer (score 2):

Primeiramente, o Oracle XE utiliza por padrão a porta [1521](https://docs.oracle.com/cd/B25329_01/doc/appdev.102/b25320/getconn.htm). A porta 3128 é usada normalmente pelo [Squid](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Squid_(software)). A menos que você tenha mudado a porta de propósito, provavelmente este não é o número correto.

Não confunda a porta utilizada pelo banco de dados com a porta utilizada pelo Tomcat. São coisas totalmente diferentes.

A porta padrão do MySQL é a [3306](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/workbench/en/wb-mysql-connections-methods-standard.html). A do SQL Server é a [1433](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc646023.aspx). A do Firebird é a [3050](http://www.firebirdfaq.org/faq259/). A do PostgreSQL é a [5432 ou 5433](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15100368/postgresql-port-confusion-5433-or-5432).

Dei uma revisada no código da sua classe `Connect`. Se ele vai conectar no Oracle, não precisa ter a String de conexão do MySQL no meio dele. Além disso, manter um único `Connection` em uma variável estática é uma má prática de programação, uma vez que isso não fecha a conexão adequadamente.

Além disso, o método `getConnection` nunca retorna `null`, então o seu método nunca retornaria `false`. Capturar a `SQLException` apenas para dar um `System.out.println` e então fingir que a exceção não aconteceu e retornar `true` do mesmo jeito também é uma pésssima idea, vez que você faz o método dizer que a conexão foi bem sucedida quando na verdade ela falhou. O correto neste caso é propagar a exceção.

Se ocorrer o `ClassNotFoundException`, então a sua aplicação está quebrada devido a um erro de classpath. Neste caso, pode propagar o erro mesmo.

Eis o código revisado:

```
package connection;

import java.sql.Connection;  
import java.sql.DriverManager;  
import java.sql.SQLException;  

public class Connect {

    private static final int porta = 1521;
    private static final String host = "127.0.0.1";
    private static final String servico = "xe";
    private static final String usuario = "andre";
    private static final String senha = "root"

    static {
        try {
            Class.forName("oracle.jdbc.driver.OracleDriver");
        } catch (ClassNotFoundException e) {
            throw new ExceptionInInitializerError(e);
        }
    }

    public Connection static conectar() throws SQLException {
        return DriverManager.getConnection("jdbc:oracle:thin:@" + host + ":" + porta + ":" + servico, usuario , senha);
    }
}
```

Agora é a vez do servlet:

```
import javax.servlet.ServletException;
import javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet;
import javax.servlet.http.HttpServletRequest;
import javax.servlet.http.HttpServletResponse;

import connection.Connect;

//@WebServlet("/Hospede")
public class Hospede extends HttpServlet {
    private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;

    @Override
    protected void doGet(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response) throws ServletException, IOException {
        testar();
    }

    @Override
    protected void doPost(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response) throws ServletException, IOException {

    }

    private static void testar() {
        String query = "select * from hospede";
        try (
            Connection c = Connect.conectar();
            Statement busca = c.createStatement();
            ResultSet resultado = busca.executeQuery(query)
        ) {
            System.out.println(resultado.getString("nome"));
        } catch (SQLException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }
}
```

Aqui, você pode usar [a sintaxe *try-with-resources* do Java 7+](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/172909/132) para garantir que o seu `Connection`, o seu `Statement` e o seu `ResultSet` serão fechados adequadamente.