# Como funciona o try-with-resources?

Tags: java, exceção, try-catch, try-finally, try-with-resources

No Java 7, o conceito do *try-with-resources* foi adicionado na linguagem.

O que é o *try-with-resources*? Como ele funciona? Para que ele serve? Como é que ele é usado? Que problema ele visa resolver?

Answer (score 59, accepted):

Abrir e fechar recursos no Java, até o Java 6, era uma tarefa muito tediosa de se fazer e muito propensa a erros. Fechar os recursos abertos (invocando o método `close()`) frequentemente é algo que ou acaba sendo esquecido de ser feito ou que o programador o faz de forma inadequada, pois há vários complicadores para se fazer isso.

Por exemplo, veja este código:

```java
public class ConexaoFalhouException extends Exception {
    public ConexaoFalhouException(Throwable cause) {
        super(cause);
    }
}
```

```java
public class AlunoDAO {

    private static final String SQL_ALUNOS_POR_TURMA = 
            "SELECT id, nome, telefone FROM alunos WHERE id_turma = ?";

    public static void localizarAlunos(String turma) throws ConexaoFalhouException {
        Connection c = null;
        PreparedStatement ps = null;
        ResultSet rs = null;

        try {
            c = Conexao.obter();
            ps = c.prepareStatement(SQL_ALUNOS_POR_TURMA);
            ps.setString(1, turma);
            rs = ps.executeQuery();

            List<Aluno> alunos = new ArrayList<Aluno>();
            while (rs.next()) {
                Aluno a = new Aluno();
                a.setInt(rs.getInt(1));
                a.setNome(rs.getString(2));
                a.setTelefone(rs.getString(3));
                alunos.add(a);
            }

            return alunos;
        } catch (SQLException e) {
            throw new ConexaoFalhouException(e);
        } finally {
            try {
                if (rs != null) rs.close();
                if (ps != null) ps.close();
                if (c != null) c.close();
            } catch (SQLException e) {
                throw new ConexaoFalhouException(e);
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Este é o código que um programador experiente em Java 6 tipicamente escreveria. Apesar de tudo, ainda há umas coisas chatas nele:

- O programador sempre tem que ter o cuidado de se lembrar de chamar o `close()` manualmente.
- Se o programador não usar o bloco `try-finally`, colocando o `close()` no `finally`, o recurso ficará aberto se uma exceção for lançada.
- Se o programador se esquecer de usar os `if`s no bloco `finally`, ele pode ter um `NullPointerException` como resultado.
- Se um dos métodos `close()` do bloco `finally` lançar uma exceção, os demais recursos não serão fechados adequadamente, a menos que cada um deles esteja isolado dentro do seu próprio `finally`.
- Se um dos métodos `close()` do bloco `finally` lançar uma exceção, essa exceção vai ser lançada e vai esconder qualquer exceção lançada no bloco `try`.
- Os métodos `close()` forçam você colocar um outro bloco `try-catch` dentro do bloco `finally`, mesmo já tendo um bloco `catch (SQLException e)` antes do `finally`, tendo que então duplicar o bloco `catch`. Isso é contornável ao se usar um bloco `try-finally` dentro do `try-catch`, mas mesmo assim, qualquer solução desse tipo é mais complicada do que o que deveria ser.

Esses problemas aí mostram que mesmo seguindo as melhores práticas, o código resultante ainda é bastante feio, confuso, propenso a erros, polui a lógica de negócio e é fácil de quebrar. E grande quantidade desse código é dedicado a lidar com a forma adequada de fechar o recurso prevendo todos os casos especiais possíveis que muitas vezes acaba ficando maior do que a parte que usa o recurso para fazer algum trabalho útil.

Pensando-se nesse problema, é que a sintaxe do *try-with-resources* foi concebida. A finalidade dessa sintaxe é exatamente a de livrar o programador da necessidade e da complexidade de fechar explicitamente os recursos abertos, além de lidar com todos esses casos especiais automaticamente sem que o programador precise se preocupar com eles.

Eis como fica o mesmo código usando o *try-with-resources*:

```java
public class ConexaoFalhouException extends Exception {
    public ConexaoFalhouException(Throwable cause) {
        super(cause);
    }
}
```

```java
public class AlunoDAO {

    private static final String SQL_ALUNOS_POR_TURMA = 
            "SELECT id, nome, telefone FROM alunos WHERE id_turma = ?";

    public static void localizarAlunos(String turma) throws ConexaoFalhouException {
        try (
            Connection c = Conexao.obter();
            PreparedStatement ps = c.prepareStatement(SQL_ALUNOS_POR_TURMA);
        ) {
            ps.setString(1, turma);
            try (ResultSet rs = ps.executeQuery()) {

                List<Aluno> alunos = new ArrayList<>();
                while (rs.next()) {
                    Aluno a = new Aluno();
                    a.setInt(rs.getInt(1));
                    a.setNome(rs.getString(2));
                    a.setTelefone(rs.getString(3));
                    alunos.add(a);
                }

                return alunos;
            }
        } catch (SQLException e) {
            throw new ConexaoFalhouException(e);
        }
    }
}
```

Observe que usando o *try-with-resources*, não é mais necessário colocar-se um bloco `finally` para se fechar os recursos e nem mesmo chamar o método `close()` e você não precisa mais codificar toda essa parafernália. Um bloco `finally` adequado é acrescentado *automagicamente* pelo compilador, e ele já sabe lidar com todos os casos bizarros citados acima. Note também que apenas um `catch (SQLException e)` é necessário.

A sintaxe do *try-with-resources* é assim:

1. A palavra-chave `try`
2. Um abre parênteses `(`.
3. Uma ou mais declarações de recursos separadas/terminadas por ponto-e-vírgula.
4. Um fecha parênteses `)`.
5. Um abre chaves `{`.
6. Várias instruções que são executadas dentro do bloco `try`.
7. Um fecha chaves `}`.
8. Opcionalmente um ou mais blocos `catch`.
9. Opcionalmente um bloco `finally`.

Os itens 8 e 9 acima significam que o fato de você estar usando um bloco *try-with-resources* não significa que você perde a capacidade de usar os blocos `catch` ou `finally`. Você pode continuar usando-os se quiser.

Quanto ao item 3, você deve estar imaginando como o compilador sabe o que é ou não um recurso. Por exemplo, isso daqui dá erro de compilação porque `String` não é um recurso válido:

```java
try (String x = "aaa") {
    // blablabla
}
```

A resposta está na interface [`java.lang.AutoCloseable`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/10/docs/api/java/lang/AutoCloseable.html). Esta interface foi acrescentada no Java 7 para denotar quais são as classes que representam recursos que podem ser usados dentro dos parênteses do *try-with-resources*. A interface [`java.io.Closeable`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/10/docs/api/java/io/Closeable.html) que já existia antes passou a herdar de `java.lang.AutoCloseable`.

A interface `AutoCloseable` tem apenas um método:

```java
void close() throws Exception;
```

E é esse o método que vai ser invocado no bloco `finally`. Implementações podem refinar ele ao substituir a exceção lançada por outras mais específicas (por exemplo, `SQLException` ou `IOException`). Isso também significa que se você quiser criar a sua classe personalizada e específica de recurso e usar ela no *try-with-resources*, basta implementar a interface `AutoCloseable`.

Como o bloco `finally` acrescentado automaticamente pode lançar essas exceções de dentro do método `close()`, elas também tem que ser capturadas ou relançadas tais como seriam com quaisquer outras *checked exceptions*. Por exemplo, veja o seguinte código:

```java
class MeuException extends Exception {}

class Teste implements AutoCloseable {
    @Override
    public void close() throws MeuException {}
}

class Principal {
    public void metodo() {
        try (Teste t = new Teste()) {
            // ...
        }
    }
}
```

Ele gera o seguinte erro de compilação:

> Unhandled exception type MeuException thrown by automatic close() invocation on t.

Que traduzindo, seria isso:

> Exceção não-tratada do tipo MeuException lançada pela invocação automática do close() no t.

Assim sendo, essa exceção também tem que ser ou capturada ou relançada:

```java
class Principal {
    public void metodoQueRelancaExcecoes() throws MeuException {
        try (Teste t = new Teste()) {
            // ...
        }
    }

    public void metodoQueTrataExcecoes() {
        try (Teste t = new Teste()) {
            // ...
        } catch (MeuException e) {
            // Trata a exceção.
        }
    }
}
```

Outras regras específicas do *try-with-resources* que o compilador considera são que:

- As variáveis declaradas dentro dos parênteses do `try` não podem ser redefinidas dentro dele. Ou seja, isso é um erro de compilação:

  ```java
  try (Connection conn = teste1()) {
      conn = teste2();
  }
  ```

  Para todos os efeitos, a variável usada como recurso é "*effectively final*". Ou seja, o compilador considera ela como se o modificador `final` estivesse presente.

  Essa restrição é importante e extremamente bem-vinda, porque sem ela, seria possível usar o *try-with-resources* para abrir um recurso e fechar um outro, o que acabaria por minar o propósito para o qual o *try-with-resources* foi concebido e abrir um caminho para o surgimento de muitos bugs difíceis de rastrear no fechamento adequado de recursos.
- No Java 7 e no Java 8, as variáveis declaradas dentro dos parênteses do `try` **não** podem ser reutilizadas, elas têm que ser declaradas neste ponto. Isso significa que os três códigos abaixo dão erros de compilação:

  ```java
  Connection conn1 = teste1();
  try (conn1 = teste2()) {
      // blablabla
  }
  ```

  ```java
  Connection conn2;
  try (conn2 = teste2()) {
      // blablabla
  }
  ```

  ```java
  Connection conn3 = teste1();
  try (conn3) {
      // blablabla
  }
  ```

  A partir do Java 9, essa restrição foi relaxada, desde que a variável reutilizada ainda seja *effectively final*. Logo, no Java 9, o primeiro `try` acima continua sem compilar, enquanto que o segundo e o terceiro compilam.

Por fim, ainda há mais um detalhe. O que ocorre quando o bloco `try` lança uma exceção e o `close()` também? O que é feito para evitar-se que a exceção original seja perdida?

A resposta está no conceito de exceções suprimidas (*suppressed exceptions*), que foi criado no Java 7 para lidar com este tipo de problema. Uma exceção pode ter uma causa (desde o Java 1.4) e várias outras exceções que ela suprime (desde o Java 7). Na classe `Throwable`, os métodos [`addSuppressed(Throwable)`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/10/docs/api/java/lang/Throwable.html#addSuppressed-java.lang.Throwable-) e [`getSuppressed()`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/10/docs/api/java/lang/Throwable.html#getSuppressed--) foram adicionados. No bloco `finally` gerado automagicamente, se o bloco `try` tiver lançado uma exceção e o método `close()` lançar outra exceção, então a exceção que vai ser lançada para fora do `finally` será a exceção do bloco `try` tendo a exceção gerada no `close()` como suprimida. Assim, o *stacktrace* conterá informações também da exceção suprimida. Eis um exemplo:

```java
class MeuException1 extends Exception {}
class MeuException2 extends Exception {}

class Teste implements AutoCloseable {
    @Override
    public void close() throws MeuException1 {
        throw new MeuException1();
    }
}

public class Principal {
    public static void main(String[] args) throws MeuException1, MeuException2 {
        try (Teste t = new Teste()) {
            throw new MeuException2();
        }
    }
}
```

Eis a saída:

> ```
> MeuException2
>     at Main.foo(Main.java:21)
>     at Main.main(Main.java:13)
>     Suppressed: MeuException1
>         at Teste.close(Main.java:6)
>         at Main.foo(Main.java:22)
>         ... 1 more
> ```

Comment: Ótima iniciativa! A maioria das explicações em português que encontramos conseguem complicar a exlplicação, e eu sempre fico perdido. Favoritado para futuras referencias :)

Comment: Bacana, conhecia o recurso mas não sabia que era possível iniciar mais de um objeto no `try`, +1.

Comment: Resposta excelente e completa!

Answer (score 21):

## TL;DR do [`try-with-resources`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/essential/exceptions/tryResourceClose.html)

- **O que é:** um recurso sintático do Java para uso seguro de recursos de forma segura.
- **Objetivo:** garantir que recursos escassos - como conexões com o banco de dados, referências a arquivos, conexões de rede - sejam devidamente fechadas após o uso, mesmo num cenário excepcional.
- **Funcionamento:** os recursos declarados no `try` (entre os parêntesis) devem implementar a interface `AutoCloseable` e terão seu método `close()` automaticamente chamado ao final do bloco `try`.
- **Uso simples:**

  ```
  try (BufferedReader br = new BufferedReader(new FileReader(path))) {
      return br.readLine();
  }
  ```
- **Benefícios**:

  - Substitui o tratamento manual de exceções:

    - Menos propenso a erros de codificação, quando o programador não sabe ou esquece de executar todo o tratamento necessário.
    - Evita vazamento de recursos, quando o programador esquece de fechá-lo ou não trata corretamente uma situação excepcional.
  - Menos código *boilerplate*:

    - Facilita e agiliza a codificação.
    - Menos chance de esquecer algo.
    - Menos código significa menos bugs e menos coisas para dar manutenção.

## Funcionamento detalhado

[Ver a excelente resposta do @Victor](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/a/172910/227).

Comment: Excelente resposta complementar. :) +1