# Problema em realizar um INSERT linguagem Java

Tags: java, sql, jdbc, sql-insert

Olá pessoal da comunidade, estou com um problema que acho que deve ser muito fácil mas como sou iniciante para mim não é rs, tenho um *insert* para realizar que fica em uma classe chamada `ClienteDAO` segue código abaixo:

```
public class clienteDAO {   
public void Create(cliente c){    
   Connection conn = javaConnect.ConnectDb();

   PreparedStatement pstmt = null;

    try {
        pstmt = conn.prepareStatement("INSERT INTO cliente (cliente_nome,cliente_rg,cliente_cpf,end_rua,end_numero,end_bairro,end_cidade,end_estado,end_cep) VALUES (?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?)");
        pstmt.setString(1, c.getNome());
        pstmt.setString(2, c.getRg());
        pstmt.setString(3, c.getCpf());
        pstmt.setString(4, c.getRua());
        pstmt.setString(5, c.getNumero());
        pstmt.setString(6, c.getBairro());
        pstmt.setString(7, c.getCidade());
        pstmt.setString(8, c.getEstado());
        pstmt.setString(9, c.getCep());

        pstmt.executeUpdate();

        JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, "Cadastro Realizado!");

    } catch (SQLException ex) {
        JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null,"Erro ao salvar: " + ex);
    }finally{
        javaConnect.DesconnectDb(conn);
    }
}}
```

Reparem que ao eu não coloquei:

```
pstmt.executeQuery();
```

e no lugar coloquei

```
psmt.executeUpdate();
```

pois quando eu coloco `ExecuteQuery` me retorna o seguinte erro:

> "Java.sql.SQLException: query does not return result"

mas quando eu coloco `ExecuteUpdate` ele retorna outro erro que é:

> "Java.sql.SQLException: cliente.id_cliente may not be NULL"

ou seja o *update* não estaria correto, certo ? e isso ficou claro para mim, agora o por que `executeQuery` não funcionar ?

E ai eu fico, oque fazer ? rs,a conexão com o banco aparenta estar correta, a forma como escrevi o INSERT também parece estar correta, e como sou novo na area não sei oque fazer.

Vou deixar o script da criação da tabela cliente :

```
CREATE TABLE cliente (
id_cliente integer increment(1,1) PRIMARY KEY NOT NULL,
cliente_cpf varchar(20),
cliente_rg varchar(20),
cliente_nome varchar(60),
end_rua varchar(40),
end_numero varchar(10),
end_bairro varchar(50),
end_cep varchar(20),
end_estado varchar(40),
end_cidade varchar(40)
)
```

Detalhe: ja tentei substituir o increment(1,1) por identity(1,1) mas não resolveu, o banco que estou utilizandoé o SQLite.

Comment: Leia [essa pergunta](http://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/172909/132) e suas respostas.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

O `executeUpdate()` está correto. O Java exibe o erro mas ao que parece o problema é o SQL e não o Java.

Você tentou inserir um registro sem informar o `id_perfil`, que por padrão o SQL está tentando inserir como nulo. Provavelmente faltou declarar esse campo como `AUTO INCREMENT`.

Um `ALTER TABLE` (ou então alterar a tabela interativamente no visualizador de banco de dados de sua preferência) deve resolver.

O `AUTO INCREMENT` atribui um valor numérico para o campo em questão automaticamente, seguindo uma ordem crescente de valores. Aí você não precisa ser obrigado a incluir esse campo nos seus `INSERTs`.

Comment: Olá Piovezan agradeço o apoio, tentei arrumar o banco criando a tabela da seguinte maneira: ` CREATE TABLE cliente (
id_cliente integer increment(1,1) PRIMARY KEY NOT NULL,
cliente_cpf varchar(20),
cliente_rg varchar(20),
cliente_nome varchar(60),
end_rua varchar(40),
end_numero varchar(10),
end_bairro varchar(50),
end_cep varchar(20),
end_estado varchar(40),
end_cidade varchar(40)
)` mas não deu certo, em seguida substitui o increment por identity(1,1) mas também obtive os mesmos resultados

Comment: Tem que dizer qual é o banco (também eu não perguntei né rs) para a gente saber qual a sintaxe correta do create table.

Comment: Estou utilizando SQLite

Comment: Então use id_cliente integer PRIMARY KEY AUTOINCREMENT,

Comment: Piovezan, agradeço a paciencia e o tempo por me ajudar neste problema, realmente o problema estava na criação errada do banco usando a sintaxe errada. Obrigado!