# Reescrever código utilizando do recurso try-with-resources

Tags: java, sintaxe, try-catch, try-with-resources

Meu problema é reescrever um código utilizando o recurso try-with-resources, como sou novo no mundo da programação não estou conseguindo aprender a fazer isso, oque está se tornando algo extressante, pois aparentemente é simples, mas não estou conseguindo.

Tenho um código de validação (é um simples login) porém toda vez que eu efetuo o login a conexão com o banco permanecia aberta e não conseguia fazer nenhuma outra operação, insert, update, drop, etc. Logo me foi apresentado o recurso try-with-resources, e preciso deste código passado com este recurso.

Estou refazendo essa pergunta poís mesmo com este [Tutorial do try-with-resources](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/172909/como-funciona-o-try-with-resources/172910#172910) ainda não estou conseguindo resolver. Espero que entendam que eu sou extremamente novo na programação.

Código do login direto do Jframe (o que é algo errado, eu sei):

```
Connection conn = null;
    ResultSet rs = null;
    PreparedStatement pst = null;

    conn = JavaConnect.connectDb();
       String sql = "SELECT * FROM usuarios where nome_usuario= ? and senha_usuario= ?";
        try{
            pst = conn.prepareStatement(sql);
            pst.setString(1,jtxtUsuario.getText());
            pst.setString(2,jtxtSenha.getText());

            rs = pst.executeQuery();
            if(rs.next()){
                jfrmPrincipal principal = new jfrmPrincipal();
                principal.setVisible(true);
                this.dispose();
            }
            else{
                JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, "Senha ou Usuário Incorreto");
            }
        }catch(Exception e){
            JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, e);
        }
}
```

Então tentei passar esse mesmo código para uma classe já tentando utilizar do recurso try-with-resources, porém mal consegui terminar pois não consegui entender mais nada, rs:

```
public class LoginDAO {

    private static final String SQL_CONSULTA = 
            "SELECT * FROM usuarios WHERE nome_usuario = ? AND senha_usuario = ?";

    public void search(Login l){

    try
    {
       Connection conn = JavaConnect.connectDb();
       PreparedStatement pstmt = conn.prepareStatement(SQL_CONSULTA);
       ){

       pstmt = setString(1, l.getNome());
       pstmt = setString(2, l.getSenha());

       pstmt.executeQuery();
    }
    }
    catch(SQLException ex)
    {
        JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null,"Erro ao inserir dados no DataBase.");
    }
    finally
    {
        JavaConnect.DesconnectDb(l,pstmt);
    }
    }
```

Porém este código ta com erros como:

- O setString não está correto, me retorna erro dizendo para criar o método.
- o DesconnectDB ta todo vermelho.

Seguindo, como eu não estava conseguindo chamar os TextBox do Jframe para a classe eu criei um GET/SET (não sei se esse era o caminho certo), para chama-los:

```
public class Login {

    private int id;
    private String nome;
    private String senha;

    public int getId() {
        return id;
    }

    public void setId(int id) {
        this.id = id;
    }

    public String getNome() {
        return nome;
    }

    public void setNome(String nome) {
        this.nome = nome;
    }

    public String getSenha() {
        return senha;
    }

    public void setSenha(String senha) {
        this.senha = senha;
    } 
}
```

Assim para passar os valores do TextBox eu fui no Jframe e escreve o seguinte código:

```
 private void jbtnConfimarActionPerformed(java.awt.event.ActionEvent evt) {                                             
       Login l = new  Login();
       LoginDAO dao = new LoginDAO();

       l.setNome(jtxtUsuario.getText());
       l.setSenha(jtxtSenha.getText());

       dao.search(l);

       this.dispose();
       jfrmPrincipal principal = new jfrmPrincipal();
       principal.setVisible(true);
    }
```

Pessoal peço a paciência de vocês mas sinceramente eu já não consigo entender mais isso, pareceu simples escrever o código pegando o aprendizado de um vídeo da internet mas entende-lo e tentar dissertar para mim mesmo é mais complicado do que eu estava imaginando.

Comment: Olá, estou refazendo esta pergunta pois, mesmo com [essa outra resposta](http://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/172909/como-funciona-o-try-with-resources/172910#172910) ainda estou com dificuldade em passar este código.

Comment: Os erros estão relacionados na forma como você escreveu o código, tente assim: http://pastebin.com/3Lv9x6yt

Comment: @DenisRudneideSouza no finally o pstmt retorna com o erro " cannot find symbol" pode me explicar o porque  ?

Comment: Perdão pela minha falta de atenção, pstmt não existe no finally, ele foi fechado automaticamente pelo try-with-resources, nesse caso o  JavaConnect.DesconnectDb(l,pstmt); é desnecessário

Comment: @DenisRudneideSouza Agradeço seu tempo, o código que você reescreveu funcionou perfeitamente, isso me ajudou a identificar onde estavam meus erros de colocação, obrigado!

Comment: @DenisRudneideSouza Poste isso como resposta.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

O problema encontra-se em:

```
pstmt = setString(1, l.getNome());
pstmt = setString(2, l.getSenha());
```

Onde você atribui o retorno do método `setString` a `pstmt`, o correto seria:

```
pstmt.setString(1, l.getNome());
pstmt.setString(2, l.getSenha());
```

Onde se acessa o método setString do seu PreparedStatement para definir os valores para a consulta.

O finally com o fechamento do banco é desnecessário, visto que a conexão será fechada automaticamente com o try-with-resources.

O código final ficaria assim:

```
public class LoginDAO {

    private static final String SQL_CONSULTA = "SELECT * FROM usuarios WHERE nome_usuario = ? AND senha_usuario = ?";

    public void search(Login l) {

        try (Connection conn = JavaConnect.connectDb(); PreparedStatement pstmt = conn.prepareStatement(SQL_CONSULTA);) {
            pstmt.setString(1, l.getNome());
            pstmt.setString(2, l.getSenha());
            pstmt.executeQuery();
        } catch (SQLException ex){
            JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, "Erro ao inserir dados no DataBase.");
        }
    }
}
```