# NullPointerException SelectOneMenu [JSF + PRIMEFACES]

Tags: java, jsf, primefaces, nullpointerexception, jdbc

Em uma página feita em JSF acerca de uma loja de carros, primeiro seleciono a marca do carro para em seguida escolher o modelo. Porém, ao selecionar um item do primeiro menu "Hyundai", ele dá `NullPointerException` e não consigo entender. Já procurei bastante, sou iniciante em JSF.

> ATUALIZADO ( JA NO MANEGED BEAN VINDO NULO).
>   Depois que sai do metodo
>   ConsultarMarca() do DAO o marcaSelecionada ja vem nulo, no caso quando
>   eu selecionasse o outro menu era pra ele pegar o valor relacionado ao
>   primeiro menu "marcaSelecionada" (Hyundai) e ver quais os modelos
>   disponiveis mostrando no menu2.

View:

```xml
 <h:form id="frmVendas">
    <p:outputPanel id="venderCarro" />
    <h:panelGrid id="painel" columns="1">

        <p:outputLabel for="comboMarca" value="Marcas*: " />
        <p:selectOneMenu id="comboMarca" converter="conversorObjetoId" value="#{vendasMB.marcaSelecionada}">
            <f:selectItem itemLabel="--Selecione--" itemValue="" />
            <f:selectItems value="#{vendasMB.listaMarca}" var="marca" itemLabel="#{marca.nome}" itemValue="#{marca}" />
            <p:ajax event="change" update="comboModelos" listener="#{vendasMB.carregarModelos}" />
        </p:selectOneMenu>
    </h:panelGrid>

    <h:panelGrid id="painel2" columns="1">
        <p:outputLabel for="comboModelos" value="Modelos*: " />
        <p:selectOneMenu id="comboModelos" value="#{vendasMB.modeloSelecionado}" converter="conversorObjetoId">
            <f:selectItem itemLabel="--Selecione--" itemValue="" />
            <f:selectItems value="#{vendasMB.listaModelo}" var="carro" itemLabel="#{carro.modelo}" itemValue="#{carro}" />
        </p:selectOneMenu>
    </h:panelGrid>
 </h:form>
```

*Managed bean*

Dois métodos para o `SelectOneMenu`

```java
private List<Carro> listaCarros = new ArrayList<Carro>();
private List<Marca> listaMarca = new ArrayList<Marca>();
private List<Carro> listaModelo = new ArrayList<Carro>();
private String carroSelecionado;
private Marca marcaSelecionada ;
private Carro modeloSelecionado;

@PostConstruct
public void init() {
    listaMarca = carrosDAO.consultarMarca();
    System.out.println("--> init*()");
}
public void carregarModelos() {
    listaModelo = carrosDAO.consultarModelos(marcaSelecionada);
    //return listaModelo;
}
```

DAO:

```java
public List<Marca> consultarMarca() {
        List<Marca> listaMarca = new ArrayList<Marca>();
        StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();
        Marca marca;
        Integer idMarca = 0;
        try {
            Connection con;
            Statement stmt = null;
            PreparedStatement ps = null;
            ResultSet rs = null;
            String urloracle = "jdbc:oracle:thin:@172.30.0.25:1521:desv";
            String useroracle = "rodrigoscs";
            String passwordoracle = "regueiro";

            OracleDataSource ds;
            ds = new OracleDataSource();
            ds.setURL(urloracle);
            con = ds.getConnection(useroracle, passwordoracle);
            stmt = con.createStatement();


                sb.append("SELECT NOME, ID FROM MARCA ");


            ps = con.prepareStatement(sb.toString());
            rs = ps.executeQuery();

            // percorre o resultado da consulta
            while (rs.next()) {

                marca = new Marca();

                marca.setMarcaID(++idMarca);
                marca.setNome(rs.getString("NOME"));
                marca.setMarcaID(rs.getInt("ID"));
                listaMarca.add(marca);

            }

            // fechando a connection
            if (con != null) {
                con.close();
                con = null;
            }
            if (stmt != null) {
                stmt.close();
                stmt = null;
            }

            if (rs != null) {
                rs.close();
                rs = null;
            }

        } catch (SQLException ex) {
            System.out.println("Erro: " + ex.getMessage());
        }
        return listaMarca;
    }
```

Método que esta dando `NullPointerException`:

```java
public List<Carro> consultarModelos(Marca marcaSelecionada) {
        List<Carro> listaModelo = new ArrayList<Carro>();
        StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();
        Carro carro;
        Integer idCarro = 0;
        try {
            Connection con;
            Statement stmt = null;
            PreparedStatement ps = null;
            ResultSet rs = null;
            String urloracle = "jdbc:oracle:thin:@172.30.0.25:1521:desv";
            String useroracle = "rodrigoscs";
            String passwordoracle = "regueiro";

            OracleDataSource ds;
            ds = new OracleDataSource();
            ds.setURL(urloracle);
            con = ds.getConnection(useroracle, passwordoracle);
            stmt = con.createStatement();

            sb.append("SELECT C.CARROS_MODELO, M.NOME FROM CARROS C, MARCA M WHERE ID = CARROS_ID AND M.ID= ? ");

            ps = con.prepareStatement(sb.toString());
            ps.setInt(1, marcaSelecionada.getMarcaID());

            rs = ps.executeQuery();

            // percorre o resultado da consulta
            while (rs.next()) {

                carro = new Carro();
                carro.setId(++idCarro);
                carro.setModelo(rs.getString("CARROS_MODELO"));
                listaModelo.add(carro);

            }

            // fechando a connection
            if (con != null) {
                con.close();
                con = null;
            }
            if (stmt != null) {
                stmt.close();
                stmt = null;
            }

            if (rs != null) {
                rs.close();
                rs = null;
            }

        } catch (SQLException ex) {
            System.out.println("Erro: " + ex.getMessage());
        }
        return listaModelo;
    }
```

get e set

```
    public List<Marca> getLista() {
        return listaMarca;
    }

    public void setLista(List<Marca> lista) {
        this.listaMarca = lista;
    }

    public List<Marca> getListaMarca() {
        return listaMarca;
    }

    public void setListaMarca(List<Marca> listaMarca) {
        this.listaMarca = listaMarca;
    }

    public Marca getMarcaSelecionada() {
        return marcaSelecionada;
    }

    public void setMarcaSelecionada(Marca marcaSelecionada) {
        this.marcaSelecionada = marcaSelecionada;
    }

    public List<Carro> getListaModelo() {
        return listaModelo;
    }

    public void setListaModelo(List<Carro> listaModelo) {
        this.listaModelo = listaModelo;
    }

    public Carro getModeloSelecionado() {
        return modeloSelecionado;
    }

    public void setModeloSelecionado(Carro modeloSelecionado) {
        this.modeloSelecionado = modeloSelecionado;
    }
}
```

ERRO:

--> init*()

```
Jan 11, 2017 9:00:46 AM com.sun.faces.lifecycle.InvokeApplicationPhase execute
Advertência: /telaDeVendas.xhtml @21,107 listener="#{vendasMB.carregarModelos}": java.lang.NullPointerException
javax.el.ELException: /telaDeVendas.xhtml @21,107 listener="#{vendasMB.carregarModelos}": java.lang.NullPointerException
    at com.sun.faces.facelets.el.TagMethodExpression.invoke(TagMethodExpression.java:111)
    at org.primefaces.component.behavior.ajax.AjaxBehaviorListenerImpl.processAjaxBehavior(AjaxBehaviorListenerImpl.java:53)
    at javax.faces.event.AjaxBehaviorEvent.processListener(AjaxBehaviorEvent.java:113)
    at javax.faces.component.behavior.BehaviorBase.broadcast(BehaviorBase.java:106)
    at javax.faces.component.UIComponentBase.broadcast(UIComponentBase.java:762)
    at javax.faces.component.UIViewRoot.broadcastEvents(UIViewRoot.java:786)
    at javax.faces.component.UIViewRoot.processApplication(UIViewRoot.java:1251)
    at com.sun.faces.lifecycle.InvokeApplicationPhase.execute(InvokeApplicationPhase.java:81)
    at com.sun.faces.lifecycle.Phase.doPhase(Phase.java:101)
    at com.sun.faces.lifecycle.LifecycleImpl.execute(LifecycleImpl.java:118)
    at javax.faces.webapp.FacesServlet.service(FacesServlet.java:593)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:305)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:210)
    at org.primefaces.webapp.filter.FileUploadFilter.doFilter(FileUploadFilter.java:98)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:243)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:210)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapperValve.invoke(StandardWrapperValve.java:222)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContextValve.invoke(StandardContextValve.java:123)
    at org.apache.catalina.authenticator.AuthenticatorBase.invoke(AuthenticatorBase.java:502)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHostValve.invoke(StandardHostValve.java:171)
    at org.apache.catalina.valves.ErrorReportValve.invoke(ErrorReportValve.java:99)
    at org.apache.catalina.valves.AccessLogValve.invoke(AccessLogValve.java:953)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardEngineValve.invoke(StandardEngineValve.java:118)
    at org.apache.catalina.connector.CoyoteAdapter.service(CoyoteAdapter.java:408)
    at org.apache.coyote.http11.AbstractHttp11Processor.process(AbstractHttp11Processor.java:1023)
    at org.apache.coyote.AbstractProtocol$AbstractConnectionHandler.process(AbstractProtocol.java:589)
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.JIoEndpoint$SocketProcessor.run(JIoEndpoint.java:312)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1145)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:615)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:744)
Caused by: java.lang.NullPointerException
    at DAO.CarrosDAO.consultarModelos(CarrosDAO.java:168)
    at MB.VendasMB.carregarModelos(VendasMB.java:82)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:57)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:606)
    at org.apache.el.parser.AstValue.invoke(AstValue.java:278)
    at org.apache.el.MethodExpressionImpl.invoke(MethodExpressionImpl.java:274)
    at com.sun.faces.facelets.el.TagMethodExpression.invoke(TagMethodExpression.java:105)
    ... 29 more

Jan 11, 2017 9:00:46 AM com.sun.faces.context.AjaxExceptionHandlerImpl handlePartialResponseError
Grave: java.lang.NullPointerException
    at DAO.CarrosDAO.consultarModelos(CarrosDAO.java:168)
    at MB.VendasMB.carregarModelos(VendasMB.java:82)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:57)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:606)
    at org.apache.el.parser.AstValue.invoke(AstValue.java:278)
    at org.apache.el.MethodExpressionImpl.invoke(MethodExpressionImpl.java:274)
    at com.sun.faces.facelets.el.TagMethodExpression.invoke(TagMethodExpression.java:105)
    at org.primefaces.component.behavior.ajax.AjaxBehaviorListenerImpl.processAjaxBehavior(AjaxBehaviorListenerImpl.java:53)
    at javax.faces.event.AjaxBehaviorEvent.processListener(AjaxBehaviorEvent.java:113)
    at javax.faces.component.behavior.BehaviorBase.broadcast(BehaviorBase.java:106)
    at javax.faces.component.UIComponentBase.broadcast(UIComponentBase.java:762)
    at javax.faces.component.UIViewRoot.broadcastEvents(UIViewRoot.java:786)
    at javax.faces.component.UIViewRoot.processApplication(UIViewRoot.java:1251)
    at com.sun.faces.lifecycle.InvokeApplicationPhase.execute(InvokeApplicationPhase.java:81)
    at com.sun.faces.lifecycle.Phase.doPhase(Phase.java:101)
    at com.sun.faces.lifecycle.LifecycleImpl.execute(LifecycleImpl.java:118)
    at javax.faces.webapp.FacesServlet.service(FacesServlet.java:593)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:305)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:210)
    at org.primefaces.webapp.filter.FileUploadFilter.doFilter(FileUploadFilter.java:98)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:243)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:210)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapperValve.invoke(StandardWrapperValve.java:222)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContextValve.invoke(StandardContextValve.java:123)
    at org.apache.catalina.authenticator.AuthenticatorBase.invoke(AuthenticatorBase.java:502)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHostValve.invoke(StandardHostValve.java:171)
    at org.apache.catalina.valves.ErrorReportValve.invoke(ErrorReportValve.java:99)
    at org.apache.catalina.valves.AccessLogValve.invoke(AccessLogValve.java:953)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardEngineValve.invoke(StandardEngineValve.java:118)
    at org.apache.catalina.connector.CoyoteAdapter.service(CoyoteAdapter.java:408)
    at org.apache.coyote.http11.AbstractHttp11Processor.process(AbstractHttp11Processor.java:1023)
    at org.apache.coyote.AbstractProtocol$AbstractConnectionHandler.process(AbstractProtocol.java:589)
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.JIoEndpoint$SocketProcessor.run(JIoEndpoint.java:312)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1145)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:615)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:744)
```

Comment: Relacionado, recomendo a leitura para simplificar o seu DAO: http://pt.stackoverflow.com/a/172910/132

Comment: Coloque um breakpoint no método de carregar os modelos e veja se ele é acionado quando seleciona a marca.

Comment: Qual linha que lança a Exceção? Você já debugou para ver se o parâmetro `marcaSelecionada` vem preenchido corretamente? Não é nulo?

Comment: @Douglas ele é acionado sim,  e vem da nell pointer na método do  Dão para buscar os modekos marcaSelecionada.getNome nessa linha para ser exato.

Comment: @igorventurelli já debuguei marcaSelecionada  vem nulo no MB e No DAO também quando chamo marcaSelecionada.getNome na consulta do modelo

Comment: Poste o código completo do ManagedBean, por favor.

Comment: @igorventurelli igor para esse select one menu so usa esses dois metodos por isso nao coloquei tudo.

Comment: Poste os get&set dos atributos que tem relação então, por favor.

Comment: @igorventurelli ta ai seria so esses os envolvidos

Comment: Valeu! Tente tirar o `event="change"` do ajax, por favor.

Comment: @igorventurelli ja tinha feito isso, tentei novamente e nada.

Comment: No Bean, na declaração da variavel, incialize-a com uma nova instância. Por favor. `private Marca marcaSelecionada = new Marca();` e no método `carregarModelos()` faça um `System.out.println(marcaSelecionada);` antes de consultar o banco.

Comment: Ao inicializar com uma nova instancia ele da o erro Jan 11, 2017 10:20:37 AM com.sun.faces.application.view.FaceletViewHandlingStrategy handleRenderException
Grave: Error Rendering View[/telaDeVendas.xhtml]
java.lang.ClassCastException: Entidade.Marca cannot be cast to Entidade.Carro

Comment: https://github.com/rodrigoscsx/LojaDeCarros O projeto aqui so com a source e o html

Answer (score 1):

Cara, refiz o seu DAO inteiro:

```
public class CarrosDAO() {

    private static final URL_DB = "jdbc:oracle:thin:@172.30.0.25:1521:desv";
    private static final USUARIO = "rodrigoscs";
    private static final SENHA = "regueiro";

    private final OracleDataSource ds;

    public CarrosDAO() {
        try {
            ds = new OracleDataSource();
            ds.setURL(URL_DB);
            ds.setUser(URL_DB);
            ds.setPassword(URL_DB);
        } catch (SQLException e) {
            throw new RuntimeException(e);
        }
    }

    private Connection conectar() {
        return ds.getConnection();
    }

    public List<Marca> consultarMarca() {
        List<Marca> listaMarca = new ArrayList<>();
        try (
            Connection con = conectar();
            PreparedStatement ps = con.prepareStatement("SELECT NOME, ID FROM MARCA");
            ResultSet rs = ps.executeQuery()
        ) {
            while (rs.next()) {
                Marca marca = new Marca();
                marca.setNome(rs.getString("NOME"));
                marca.setMarcaID(rs.getInt("ID"));
                listaMarca.add(marca);
            }
        } catch (SQLException ex) {
            System.out.println("Erro: " + ex.getMessage());
            // ATENÇÃO: Comer exceções só dando um System.out.println nelas é uma má prática de programação!
        }
        return listaMarca;
    }

    public List<Carro> consultarModelos(Marca marcaSelecionada) {
        if (marcaSelecionada == null) throw new IllegalArgumentException("Nenhuma marca foi selecionada.");
        List<Carro> listaModelo = new ArrayList<>();
        try (
            Connection con = conectar();
            PreparedStatement ps = con.prepareStatement("SELECT C.CARROS_ID, C.CARROS_MODELO, M.NOME FROM CARROS C, MARCA M WHERE M.ID = C.CARROS_ID AND M.ID = ? ")
        ) {
            ps.setInt(1, marcaSelecionada.getMarcaID());
            try (ResultSet rs = ps.executeQuery()) {

            while (rs.next()) {
                Carro carro = new Carro();
                carro.setId(rs.getInt("CARROS_ID"));
                carro.setModelo(rs.getString("CARROS_MODELO"));
                listaModelo.add(carro);
            }
        } catch (SQLException ex) {
            System.out.println("Erro: " + ex.getMessage());
            // ATENÇÃO: Comer exceções só dando um System.out.println nelas é uma má prática de programação!
        }
        return listaModelo;
    }
}
```

Mantenha em mente o seguinte:

- Não repita ou copie e cole códigos. Ter em cada método, repetidos, a URL, o usuário, a senha, o `OracleDataSource`, o `Connection`, etc. não é uma boa coisa. Uma das ideias para as quais funções, procedimentos e métodos foram criados é para que coisas repetidas como essas só precisem ser codificadas uma única vez.
- Use o [*try-with-resources*](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/a/172910/132) - ele foi criado para que a lógica de criação de objetos que precisem ser fechados não seja tão difícil de se codificar. E por sinal, a sua lógica para fechar as conexões, *statements*, etc estava errada, pois se ocorrer uma exceção (ex: `NullPointerException`), eles permaneciam abertos.
- No seu código havia isso:

  ```
  carro.setId(++idCarro);
  ```

  Adivinha o que aconteceria se você deletasse um carro do banco de dados? Ele bagunçaria os IDs! A solução para isso é simplesmente pegar o ID do banco de dados ao invés de ficar contando as linhas e presumir que isso vai coincidir com os IDs esperados.
- Você estava trabalhando com uma variável `ps` e uma outra `stmt`. Você só precisa de uma.
- No seu código original, se você chamar o método `carrosDAO.consultarModelos(marcaSelecionada)` quando `marcaSelecionada` for `null`, dentro do DAO o `ps.setInt(1, marcaSelecionada.getMarcaID());` vai te dar um `NullPointerException`. Troquei isso por uma exceção mais amigável. Se isso acontecer, você pode ter certeza que o problema não estará no `CarrosDAO`, e sim no *managed bean*.

Não consegui ver algo de errado no seu XHTML, mas pode ter algo lá que não tenha percebido. Não sei se isso vai resolver o seu problema, mas pelo menos vai facilitar e simplificar as coisas.

Comment: Boa noite victor obrigado pelas orientações irei alterar isso ai , e te digo . pelo que vi faz todo sentido. O carro.setId(++idCarro); foi um amigo que colocou porcausa do converter

Comment: Bom dia eu queria agradecer as dicas terminando esse projeto vou economizar nas linhas e deixar o programa mais elegante com isso ai. Vi aqui que O problema deve ser na view porque no managed bean ele ja ta nulo tambem ao dar um getMarcaSelecionada();

Comment: github.com/rodrigoscsx/LojaDeCarros Projeto