# Problema com array em Java para ler do banco de dados

Tags: java, array, jdbc

Tenho uma função Java onde eu pesso um número telefone e ele me retorna qual o tronco que a chamada vai sair de acordo com o expressão regular que está salva em banco de dados em uma coluna chamada "`exten_discador`".

Se essa minha consulta pode obter *n* resultados, com ela eu vou ter que utilizar um array armazenando `$array[operadora] = id_tronco`.

Caso o meu código entre no `if` eu preciso ver qual foi a operadora obtida do banco de dados e buscar o `id_tronco` do array.

Exemplo:

```
------------------------------------------------------------------------
exten_discador                  id_tronco    Operadora
'^(00\d{2}[7-9]\d{7,8})$'           1           GVT
'^(00\d{2}[7-9]\d{7,8})$'           87          NET

---------------------------------------------------------------------------
```

A Minha validação da expressão `exten_discador` está funcionando ok, o meu problema e na hora de armazenar em um array a operadora com valor do tronco: 
`$array[operadora] = id_tronco`.

Aqui vai o meu código:

```java
public Integer getTroncoChamada(String numero) throws SQLException {

    Integer retorno = null;

    String sqlExten = "SELECT "
                 + " r.id_rota,"
                 + " r.rota,"
                 + " reo.exten_discador,"
                 + " reot.remove_left,"
                 + " reot.remove_right,"
                 + " reot.add_left,"
                 + " reot.add_right,"
                 + " reot.operadora,"
                 + " reot.prioridade,"
                 + " t.id_tronco,"
                 + " t.tronco,"
                 + " t.dial"
                 + " FROM asterisk.rota r"
                 + " LEFT JOIN asterisk.rota_exten_out reo ON (r.id_rota = reo.id_rota)"
                 + " LEFT JOIN asterisk.rota_exten_out_tronco reot ON (reo.id_rota_exten_out = reot.id_rota_exten_out)"
                 + " LEFT JOIN asterisk.tronco t ON (t.id_tronco = reot.id_tronco)"
                 + " WHERE r.habilitar = 1"
                 + " AND reot.datahora_fim is null"
                 + " AND reo.exten_discador is not null"
                 + " AND t.habilitar = 1"
                 + " AND r.tipo_rota = 'OUT' ";


    PreparedStatement psExten = connection.prepareStatement(sqlExten);
    ResultSet rsExten = psExten.executeQuery();

    String exten_discador;
    int i = 1;
    int[] id_tronco = null;
    String operadora;
    String operadora_numero;
    Integer prioridade = 0;

    while (rsExten.next()) {

        exten_discador = rsExten.getString("exten_discador");


        id_tronco[Integer.parseInt(rsExten.getString("operadora"))] = rsExten.getInt("id_tronco");  /*  PROBLEM  */

        if(numero.trim().matches(exten_discador)){

            if(i>1){
                operadora_numero = "GVT";
                operadora = "^"+rsExten.getString("operadora")+"$";                 
                prioridade = rsExten.getInt("prioridade");
                if(operadora_numero.trim().matches(operadora)){
                    retorno =  id_tronco[Integer.parseInt(rsExten.getString("operadora"))];  **/*  PROBLEM  */**
                }

            }else{
                retorno = rsExten.getInt("id_tronco");
                i++;
            }

        }

    }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

## O problema que você está relatando

Olhe isso, aqui o array é `null`:

```
int[] id_tronco = null;
```

Se ele é `null`, então o que vai acontecer aqui?

```
id_tronco[Integer.parseInt(rsExten.getString("operadora"))] = rsExten.getInt("id_tronco");
```

Vai dar um `java.lang.NullPointerException`! Você não pode acessar uma posição de um array que é `null`, porque `null` nem mesmo é um array para começo de conversa.

Na verdade, há ainda um outro problema. Antes de dar `NullPointerException`, vai dar um `java.lang.NumberFormatException`. Se o campo `operadora` pode ser "`GVT`" ou "`NET`", tentar dar um `Integer.parseInt` nisso não vai funcionar!

## Outros problemas do seu código

Observe também isso:

```
operadora_numero = "GVT";
// ...
operadora = "^"+rsExten.getString("operadora")+"$"
if(operadora_numero.trim().matches(operadora)){
    // ...
```

Essa é uma das piores formas de se abusar de expressões regulares que eu já vi. Basicamente o objetivo disso tudo é apenas verificar se a operadora em questão é a GVT. Isso seria bem mais fácil de se fazer assim:

```
if ("GVT".equals(rsExten.getString("operadora")) {
    // ...
```

O seu código também tem outros problemas:

- Não há necessidade de se construir a SQL desse jeito dentro do método uma vez que sempre a mesma SQL será gerada.
- Você não fecha o `PreparedStatement` e o `ResultSet` adequadamente. Para fazer isso, é recomendável usar o [***try-with-resources***](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/172909/132).
- O fato da sua linha `id_tronco[Integer.parseInt(rsExten.getString("operadora"))] = rsExten.getInt("id_tronco");` estar antes da linha `if(numero.trim().matches(exten_discador)){` provavelmente poderá poluir o seu array com `id_tronco`s que não casam com a expressão regular do `exten_discador`. Não deve ser isso o que você quer.
- A própria ideia de usar inteiros lidos do banco de dados como índices de um array é uma péssima ideia, pois nada garante que você estará acessando o array em posições válidas.
- Você parece estar querendo usar como chave do array, o nome da operadora. Forçar o nome da operadora a ser um inteiro com um `Integer.parseInt` não vai dar certo e não vai te ajudar, mas usar um `Map` seria uma ideia bem melhor. Acho que o seu `$array[operadora] = id_tronco` indica isso.
- Entretanto, você só lê dados do array se a chave for "GVT", o que significa que você parece estar tentando ler o array sempre da mesma posição. Ora, se você só acessa o array em uma única posição, então você nem precisa de array coisa nenhuma e uma variável simples com um `idTroncoGVT` resolveria.
- A variável `i` serve apenas para separar o primeiro elemento dos resultados dos demais, assumindo apenas os valores 1 e 2. Usar um `boolean` seria mais eficiente. Se quiser, você poderia também usar, o método [`ResultSet.getRow()`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/sql/ResultSet.html#getRow--) para obter o número da linha no `ResultSet`.
- Uma vez que a prioridade nunca vai ser `null`, então não há porque ela ser `Integer`. Use o tipo `int`.
- Você faz `SELECT` nas colunas `r.id_rota`, `r.rota`, `reot.remove_left`, `reot.remove_right`, `reot.add_left`, `reot.add_right`, `t.tronco` e `t.dial` e não usa nenhuma dessas colunas para nada.
- Você não postou o código todo do seu método. Vou supor que faltou apenas um `return retorno; }`. Se tiver faltado mais coisas, pode ser que haja ainda outros problemas além desses.
- Você lê o campo `prioridade` do banco de dados e não faz nada com ele, supondo que você não o use no final do método que ficou faltando.

## O que você realmente queria

Pelo que entendi o que você realmente quer fazer é:

> Retornar o valor do campo `id_tronco` de uma linha na qual um número de telefone seja aceito pela expressão regular do campo `exten_discador`. Deve ser preferencialmente obtido um `id_tronco` da operadora GVT, escolhendo algum outro apenas se não tiver nenhum da GVT.

Ou seja, **você fez a pergunta errada!** O que você tem é um [exemplo do problema XY](https://pt.meta.stackoverflow.com/q/499/132), onde você perguntou sobre a sua lógica em colocar elementos no array, sendo que esse não era o seu problema real.

Você não disse qual é o seu banco de dados, mas quase todos os bancos de dados têm funcionalidades de expressões regulares embutidas e você pode se aproveitar do `ORDER BY`. Assim sendo, supondo que você esteja usando o MySQL ou MariaDB, você poderia fazer tudo isso dessa forma, usando o operador `REGEXP` ([**fonte**](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/regexp.html)):

```
private static final String SQL_TRONCO_CHAMADA =
        "SELECT t.id_tronco"
             + " FROM asterisk.rota r"
             + " LEFT JOIN asterisk.rota_exten_out reo ON (r.id_rota = reo.id_rota)"
             + " LEFT JOIN asterisk.rota_exten_out_tronco reot ON (reo.id_rota_exten_out = reot.id_rota_exten_out)"
             + " LEFT JOIN asterisk.tronco t ON (t.id_tronco = reot.id_tronco)"
             + " WHERE r.habilitar = 1"
             + " AND reot.datahora_fim is null"
             + " AND reo.exten_discador is not null"
             + " AND t.habilitar = 1"
             + " AND r.tipo_rota = 'OUT'"
             + " AND ? REGEXP reo.extenDiscador"
             + " ORDER BY reot.operadora = 'GVT' DESC, t.id_tronco ASC";

public Integer getTroncoChamada(String numero) throws SQLException {
    try (PreparedStatement psExten = connection.prepareStatement(SQL_TRONCO_CHAMADA)) {
        psExten.setString(1, numero);
        try (ResultSet rsExten = psExten.executeQuery()) {
            if (!rsExten.next()) return null;
            return rsExten.getInt("id_tronco");
        }
    }
}
```

Se você estiver usando o Oracle, então pode trocar o "`AND ? REGEXP reo.extenDiscador`" por "`AND REGEXP_LIKE (?, reo.extenDiscador)`" ([**fonte**](https://docs.oracle.com/cd/B12037_01/server.101/b10759/conditions018.htm#SQLRF00501)).

Se estiver no PostgreSQL, troque o "`AND ? REGEXP reo.extenDiscador`" por "`AND ? ~ reo.extenDiscador`" ([**fonte**](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/9.3/static/functions-matching.html#FUNCTIONS-POSIX-REGEXP)).

Se estiver usando o Firebird, troque o "`AND ? REGEXP reo.extenDiscador`" por "`AND ? SIMILAR TO reo.extenDiscador`" ([**fonte**](https://firebirdsql.org/refdocs/langrefupd25-similar-to.html)).

O SQL Server não vem com funcionalidades de expresssões regulares embutidas, mas com um pouquinho de trabalho, você também pode convencer ele a aceitá-las. [**1**](https://www.codeproject.com/Articles/42764/Regular-Expressions-in-MS-SQL-Server), [**2**](https://github.com/zzzprojects/Eval-SQL.NET/wiki/SQL-Server-Regex-%7C-Use-regular-expression-to-search,-replace-and-split-text-in-SQL). Dependendo de qual dessas funções você instalar, você vai acabar usando um "`AND dbo.RegExpLike(?, reo.extenDiscador)`" ou coisa parecida.

Há ainda mais um detalhe no código: Você não deixa claro de onde vem a variável `connection`, então pode ser que o seu `connection` não esteja sendo manipulado de forma adequada. Idealmente você teria um método `getConnection()` que abriria uma conexão. Tendo isso, você modificaria o início do primeiro `try` do código acima para ficar assim:

```
    try (
        Connection conn = getConnection();
        PreparedStatement psExten = conn.prepareStatement(SQL_TRONCO_CHAMADA);
    ) {
```

Ah, e quanto a sua pergunta, um último detalhe é que você fala em `$array`. Essa notação com o `$` não existe no Java. Isso é uma notação do mundo do PHP, mas como PHP não é Java, esta notação não deve ser usada no Java.

Comment: Excelente, muito obrigado!