# JDBC - Executar uma query e utilizar o retorno desta como parâmetro para outra query

Tags: java, jdbc

Estou aprendendo em programar em java, sozinho com ajuda de tutorias e estou tentando fazer um procedimento onde o resultado de uma consulta será um cláusula `where` para uma segunda consulta.

No exemplo abaixo, tenho uma conexão que realiza uma consulta, e pega o resultado e o armazena numa variável `String hash`.

Quero pegar esse resultado e criar um nova consulta.

Não consigo fazer isso. Tentei, mas só dá erro.

```
package br.com.jdbc;

import java.sql.*;

public class ConectaBanco {

    public static void main(String [] args) {
        try {
            Class.forName("oracle.jdbc.driver.OracleDriver");             
            Connection con = DriverManager.getConnection("jdbc:oracle:thin:user/pass@host:1522/base");

            Statement stmt = con.createStatement();
            String sql ="Select * from acesso where nrdocumento ='999999999999'";
            ResultSet res = stmt.executeQuery(sql);

            while (res.next()); {
                String hash = res.getString(3);
                System.out.println(hash);
            }

            con.close();
        } catch (Exception e ) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Qual é o erro? Edite sua pergunta e o adicione. Além disso, quais são as colunas da sua tabela?

Comment: [Como funciona o try-with-resources?](http://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/172909/28595)

Comment: *"Quero pegar esse resultado e criar um nova consulta."* - Qual nova consulta?

Answer (score 3):

O primeiro ponto a notar é um ponto-e-vírgula a mais no seu `while`:

```
            while (res.next()); {
                String hash = res.getString(3);
                System.out.println(hash);
            }
```

Vê aquele ponto-e-vírgula depois do `(res.next())`? Então, ele vai fazer o seu programa ficar maluquinho, vai consumir todo o `ResultSet` sem fazer nada com ele e depois tentar produzir o hash já estando além da última posição, estourando uma `SQLException`.

Aliás, porque você usa um `while` ao invés de um `if`? Não há muito sentido em ler-se vários resultados disso se apenas o último vai importar.

O segundo ponto é que você deveria utilizar o [*try-with-resources*](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/172909/132). Veja nesse link as razões para isso e como fazer.

Além disso, dáa para mover o processo para fazer a conexão em um método a parte, pois você decerto vai precisar fazer isso várias vezes e não é bom ficar copiando-e-colando códigos.

O processo de inicialização do driver, usando o `Class.forName` não é mais necessário nas versões mais recentes do Java. Entretanto, ao fazê-lo assim mesmo, você denuncia logo de cara a presença de eventuais erros de classpath. Além disso, ele só precisa ser feito uma vez, durante o carregamento do programa, e se falhar, o programa está irremediavelmente quebrado. Assim sendo, esse processo pode ser mantido em um bloco de inicialização estático.

Não sei em que consulta você vai usar o hash, mas vou supor que seja um `"SELECT nome, idade FROM tabela WHERE campo = <hash>"`. O ideal é usar [`PreparedStatement`s](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/sql/PreparedStatement.html) para evitar problemas de [injeção de SQL](https://pt.wikipedia.org/wiki/Inje%C3%A7%C3%A3o_de_SQL). A ideia é você já ter uma SQL preparada e parametrizável, com partes denotadas com `?` representando coringas a serem preenchidos e especificados em momento oportuno. Eis como fazer:

```
package br.com.jdbc;

import java.sql.Connection;
import java.sql.DriverManager;
import java.sql.PreparedStatement;
import java.sql.ResultSet;
import java.sql.SQLException;

public class ConectaBanco {
    private static final String SQL_ACESSO_DOC ="SELECT * FROM acesso WHERE nrdocumento ='999999999999'";

    private static final String SQL_HASH ="SELECT nome, idade FROM tabela WHERE campo = ?";

    static {
        try {
            Class.forName("oracle.jdbc.driver.OracleDriver");
        } catch (ClassNotFoundException e) {
            throw new ExceptionInInitilizerError(e);
        }
    }

    private static Connection conectar() throws SQLException {
        return DriverManager.getConnection("jdbc:oracle:thin:user/pass@host:1522/base");
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) throws SQLException {
        try (
            Connection con = conectar();
            PreparedStatement stmt = con.prepareStatement(SQL_ACESSO_DOC);
            PreparedStatement stmtHash = con.createStatement(SQL_HASH);
        ) {
            String hash = "";
            try (ResultSet res = stmt.executeQuery()) {
                if (res.next()) {
                    hash = res.getString(3);
                    System.out.println(hash);
                }
            }
            stmtHash.setString(1, hash);
            try (ResultSet res = stmtHash.executeQuery()) {
                while (res.next()) {
                    String nome = res.getString(1);
                    int idade = res.getInt(2);
                    System.out.println(nome + " tem " + idade + " anos.");
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: obrigado imensamente pela atenção