# Como implementar uma classe para utilizar PreparedStatement através dela?

Tags: java, java-8, prepared-statement

Tenho a seguinte classe Conecta.java

```
package util;

import java.sql.Connection;
import java.sql.DriverManager;
import java.sql.PreparedStatement;
import java.sql.SQLException;
import java.sql.Statement;

public class Conecta {
    //Pode ser alterado para Mysql...
    private String DRIVER = "com.mysql.jdbc.Driver";
    private String BD = "testes";
    private String URL = "jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306/"+BD;
    private String USERNAME = "root";
    private String PASSWORD = "";
    private Connection conexao;
    private Statement stm; //trocar por PreparedStatement

    private String msg;

    public Conecta() {
        this.msg = this.iniciaConexao();

    }

    public Conecta(String bd, String user, String senha) {
        this.BD = bd;
        this.USERNAME = user;
        this.PASSWORD = senha;
        this.msg = this.iniciaConexao();

    }

    public String iniciaConexao() {
        try {
            Class.forName(this.DRIVER);
            this.conexao = DriverManager.getConnection(URL, USERNAME, PASSWORD);
            // Definimos o objeto responsável por executar os comandos
            this.stm = this.getConexao().createStatement();
            return "sucesso";

        } catch (ClassNotFoundException e) {
            this.conexao = null;
            return "Não foi possivel encontrar o driver de banco: " + e.getMessage();
        } catch (SQLException e) {
            this.conexao = null;
            return "Erro!" + e.getMessage();
        }
    }

    public PreparedStatement getPS(String sql) {
        try {
            return this.getConexao().prepareStatement(sql);
        } catch (SQLException ex) {
            System.err.println("Erro: "+ex);
            return null;
        }
    }


    public String fechaConexao() {
        try {
            if (this.getConexao() != null) {
                this.getConexao().close();
                this.conexao = null;
            }
            if (this.getStm() != null) {
                this.stm = null;
            }
            return "Conexão Encerrada";
        } catch (SQLException ex) {
            return "Houve erro no fechamento da conexão! "+ex.getMessage();
        }
    }

    public Connection getConexao() {
        return conexao;
    }

    public Statement getStm() {
        return stm;
    }

    public String getMsg() {
        return msg;
    }


    public boolean insert(String sql) throws SQLException {

        this.stm = this.getConexao().prepareStatement(sql);


        return false;
        //Obter um statement
        //Statement stmt = con.getConection().createStatement();
        //executar o comando de Update seguido de um select
        //res = stmt.executeUpdate(sql);
    }

}
```

Preciso inicializa-la em minha classe principal para inserção de dados no meu banco de dados fazendo uso do PreparedStatement, passando os parâmetros para a classe Conecta.java.

Estou tentando fazer da seguinte forma:

```
public static void main(String[] args) {

        try {
            Conecta c = new Conecta();


            String nomeCraque = "Coca";
            String sql = "insert into produto (nome) values (?)";

            c.getPS(sql).setString(1, "Cerveja");
            c.getPS(sql).execute();

            //DUUUUUUUVIDA AQUI, como executar?
            //PreparedStatement ps = c.getStm().execute(sql);
               // c.getStm().execute(sql);


            c.fechaConexao();


        } catch (Exception ex) {
            System.err.println("Erro:" + ex.getStackTrace());
        }
    }
```

Saberiam me ajudar a resolver este problema. O que preciso modificar em minhas classes?

Caso necessário posso fornecer mais detalhes.

Obrigado desde já.

Comment: Vale a pena ler: [Como funciona o try-with-resources?](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/172909/como-funciona-o-try-with-resources)

Answer (score 7, accepted):

O Agnaldo Junior se eu entendi bem o que você quer é utilizar o PreparedStatement certo!

Então vamos lá

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
    try {
        Conecta c = new Conecta();

        String nomeCraque = "Coca";
        String sql = "insert into produto(nome) values(?)";

        //Criando o objeto PreparedStatement
        PreparedStatement ps = c.getPS(sql)
        //Adicionando os dados ao Objeto PS.
        //O número indica a posição da coluna na sequencia o valor que será inserido neste campo.
        ps.setString(1,nomeCraque);
        ps.executeUpdate();
        ps.close();
        c.fechaConexao();


    } catch (Exception ex) {
        System.err.println("Erro:" + ex.getStackTrace());
    }
}
```

Veja se isso resolve seu problema...

Answer (score 1):

Você pode fazer assim:

```
public static void main(String[] args) {

    try {
        Conecta c = new Conecta();

        String nomeCraque = "Coca";
        String sql = "insert into produto (nome) values (?)";

        //Cria um PreparedStatement para a sql definida na variável sql
        PreparedStatement preparedStatement = dbConnection.prepareStatement(sql);
        //Inclui o parâmetro "Cerveja" do tipo String no index 1 de parâmetros
        preparedStatement.setString(1, "Cerveja");
        //Executa a consulta
        preparedStatement.executeUpdate();

        c.fechaConexao();


    } catch (Exception ex) {
        System.err.println("Erro:" + ex.getStackTrace());
    }
}
```

---

Veja o link que o @diegofm comentou na sua pergunta, pois sempre que trabalhamos com conexões ao banco de dados (e alguns outros recursos) precisamos encerrá-los.