# Leitura de Arquivo em Java

Tags: java, arquivo, scanner

Estou tentando ler um arquivo (`arquivo.txt`) que está na mesma pasta da minha classe, mas executo o código aparece um erro que não encontrou o arquivo. Alguém poderia conferir o que tem de errado? Desde já agradeço.

Meu `arquivo.txt`:

```
Industria;2;90000
Comercio;3;45000
Residencia;1;3000
```

Minha classe Java:

```
package jogo;
import java.io.FileNotFoundException;
import java.io.FileReader;
import java.util.Scanner;

public class Tabuleiro {

    private static Scanner scanner;

    public static void main(String[] args) {

        try {
            scanner = new Scanner(new FileReader("arquivo.txt"));
            scanner = scanner.useDelimiter(";");
        } catch (FileNotFoundException e) {
            // TODO Auto-generated catch block
            e.printStackTrace();
        }

        while (scanner.hasNext()) {
            String imovel = scanner.next();
            String posicao = scanner.next();
            String valor = scanner.next();
            System.out.println(imovel);
            System.out.println(posicao);
            System.out.println(valor);
        }

    }

}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Aqui vai um exemplo básico e funcional, caso você tenha algum problema pode comentar abaixo. 
Não esqueça de passar o caminho correto do arquivo.

---

```
try {
        BufferedReader br = new BufferedReader(new FileReader("/root/Documentos/teste.txt"));
        while (br.ready()) {
            String linha = br.readLine();
            System.out.println(linha);
        }
        br.close();
    } catch (IOException ioe) {
        ioe.printStackTrace();
    }
```

Comment: E o separador por virgula? Seu código é mais do mesmo do código dele, e faltando o delimitador ainda.

Comment: Ofereci uma maneira de ler o arquivo e o resto pode ser tratado da forma que ele quiser.

Comment: Consegui resolver, quando salvo o arquivo no meu pc e passo o caminho consigo ler.

Comment: Qual foi o motivo da votação negativa em minha resposta ?

Comment: Foi mal cara, vou arrumar isso. Acabei de fazer o cadastro no site. Ainda não sei usar direto. rsrsr

Comment: Obrigada pela ajuda.

Comment: Obrigado @IsadoraOliv, qualquer coisa estaremos sempre aqui.

Comment: Se no meio da leitura do arquivo ocorrer um `IOException`, o método `close()` não será chamado. Para arrumar isso, use o [*try-with-resources*](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/172909/132).