# Qual é a melhor forma para eliminar os espaços e os pontos?

Tags: java

Este e o meu código, mas o output não está a corresponder com o que eu quero e não está a separar o espaço nem a eliminar os pontos de todas as linhas do ficheiro.

```
BufferedReader inf = null;
String line;
String ficheiro;
try {

    inf = new BufferedReader(new FileReader("musicas.txt"));


    while ((line = inf.readLine()) != null) {
        String linha = inf.readLine();
        System.out.println(line);
        String espaco[] = inf.readLine().split(" : ");
        for (String sp: espaco) {
            System.out.println(sp);

        }


    }
} catch (IOException e) {}
```

Comment: Por favor não use o rollback de forma desnecessária.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Você pode tentar da seguinte maneira:

```
FileReader fr = new FileReader("musicasentrada.txt"); 
BufferedReader br = new BufferedReader(fr); 
FileWriter fw = new FileWriter("musicassaida.txt"); 
String line;

while((line = br.readLine()) != null)
{ 
    line = line.trim();
    if (!line.equals(""))
    {
        fw.write(line, 0, line.length());
    }
} 
fr.close();
fw.close();
```

Comment: Não se esqueça de usar o [try-with-resources](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/172909/132).