# Preciso fechar a conexão em cada consulta?

Tags: java, banco-de-dados, desempenho

Atualmente eu tenho uma aplicação web que faz consulta com múltiplos bancos de dados em um mesmo controller. Para cada banco eu gero uma conexão na inicialização do servidor e mantenho elas numa classe estática onde as respectivas DAOs à utilizaram e fecho no *context destroy* da aplicação.

A minha duvida é, eu realmente preciso abrir e fechar a conexão a cada chamada do controller? Do modo que utilizo hoje não ira me trazer problemas de performance?

Comment: Tenho a mesma dúvida, porém além da performance ainda perguntaria sobre a segurança de manter uma conexão aberta durante todo clico de vida da aplicação.

Comment: Não precisa, desde que use o [try-with-resources](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/172909/28595), pois ele fecha para você. Agora se quer reaproveitar, o interessante é trabalhar com pool de conexões.

Comment: @diegofm, mesmo assim ainda não estaria abrindo e fechando a conexão?

Comment: não estaria, pois o pool de conexões diz para a aplicação que fechou a conexão mas a mantém dentro do pool para ser reutilizada. Esta é a mágica do pool de conexões a reutilização delas para melhor aproveitamento e performance.

Comment: Sim, no caso, a pool seria mesmo a melhor solução. Obrigado :)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

> A minha duvida é, eu realmente preciso abrir e fechar a conexão a cada chamada do controller?

Conexões com bancos de dados costumam ser *stateless*. Ou seja, abre, faz o que tem que fazer e fecha.

Eu, particularmente, não vejo motivos para segurar uma conexão aberta com o banco, até mesmo porque existem [configurações de datasources](https://developer.jboss.org/wiki/ConfigDataSources) que justamente verificam se existem conexões ociosas e as fecham.

Quando digo "faz o que tem que fazer" não significa executar uma única consulta. Você pode executar N consultas, N transações e etc.

Se você tiver uma lista de clientes para cadastrar no banco, por exemplo, você não precisa abrir e fechar uma conexão para cada item dessa lista. Você pode muito bem abrir uma conexão, iterar a lista inserindo todos os clientes no banco através dessa conexão e depois fechá-la. O importante é não segurar a conexão aberta "pra sempre".

---

> Do modo que utilizo hoje não ira me trazer problemas de performance?

Se você usar *Pool de Conexões* não. O pool foi concebido exatamente com o propósito de facilitar/deixar menos custoso resgatar uma conexão com o banco.

Comment: Muito obrigado, eu já tinha pensado em utilizar Pool Connections. Parece que não terei como fugir.