# Buscando variável de outro método da mesma Classe

Tags: java, escopo-de-variáveis

Tenho uma classe `BancoDeDados` e nela contem dois métodos: `conexao` e `addDespesa`. O método `conexao` faz conexão com o meu Banco de Dados local. O método `addDespesa` adiciona `values` em uma das minhas tabelas, porém não consegue "pegar" a variável do tipo `Statement` cujo nome é `mysql`.

```
public class BancoDeDados {
    public void conexao(){
        try {
            System.out.println("Conectando ao Banco de Dados..");
            Class.forName("com.mysql.jdbc.Driver");
            Connection conexao = DriverManager.getConnection("jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306/despesas?useSSL=true","root","local");
            Statement mysql = conexao.createStatement();
            System.out.println("Conectado. \n");
        } catch (ClassNotFoundException | SQLException e) {
            System.out.println("Erro na Conexão");
        }
    }

    public void addDespesa(String addDesp){
        String sqlInsert;
        sqlInsert = "insert into tipo_de_despesa(descricao) values ('"+addDesp+"')";
        mysql.execute(sqlInsert);
    }

}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Não consegue por causa do [**escopo da variável**](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/135572/qual-a-diferen%C3%A7a-entre-escopo-e-tempo-de-vida). Você criou a variável como sendo local dentro do método `conexão()` - ela só vai existir ai dentro. Se, por acaso, quiser que a variável seja acessível em toda classe, precisa aumentar o escopo dela, tornando-a em uma variável de classe:

```
public class BancoDeDados {

    private Statement mysql;

    public void conexao(){
        try {
            System.out.println("Conectando ao Banco de Dados..");
            Class.forName("com.mysql.jdbc.Driver");
            Connection conexao = DriverManager.getConnection("jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306/despesas?useSSL=true","root","local");
            this.mysql = conexao.createStatement();
            System.out.println("Conectado. \n");
        } catch (ClassNotFoundException | SQLException e) {
            System.out.println("Erro na Conexão");
        }
    }

    public void addDespesa(String addDesp){
        String sqlInsert;
        sqlInsert = "insert into tipo_de_despesa(descricao) values ('"+addDesp+"')";
        mysql.execute(sqlInsert);
    }

}
```

Você também precisa iniciar a conexão antes de chamar o método `addDespesa`, senão irá ocorrer um `nullPointerException`.

Recomendo a leitura [**deste post**](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/172909/28595) sobre o uso de *try-with-resources* para tratamentos de conexões com banco de dados.