# Problema ao inserir dados com métodos. Java/Mysql

Tags: java, mysql, banco-de-dados, tabela-banco-de-dados

Recebo o seguinte erro quando tento adicionar um novo dado em uma tabela do meu Banco de Dados. Possuo uma classe cujo nome é `Banco de Dados` , outra cujo nome é `ShowMenu` e outra cujo nome é `Principal`.

E recebo o seguinte erro:

```
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.NullPointerException
    at BancoDeDados.addDespesa(BancoDeDados.java:27)
    at ShowMenu.novoTipo(ShowMenu.java:55)
    at ShowMenu.menu(ShowMenu.java:30)
```

Acredito que o erro estaria na comunicação dos métodos `addDesp` com o `novoTipo`.

**ShowMenu.java**

```
public void novoTipo() throws SQLException{
    BancoDeDados insertInto = new BancoDeDados();
    String nomeDesp;
    System.out.println("\nDigite o nome da despesa:");
    nomeDesp = teclado.next();
    insertInto.addDespesa(nomeDesp);
}
```

**BancoDeDados.java**

```
public class BancoDeDados {

private Statement comando;

public void conexao(){
    try {
        System.out.println("Conectando ao Banco de Dados..");
        Class.forName("com.mysql.jdbc.Driver");
        Connection conexao = DriverManager.getConnection("jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306/despesas?useSSL=true","root","local");
        comando = conexao.createStatement();
        System.out.println("Conectado. \n");
    } catch (ClassNotFoundException | SQLException e) {
        System.out.println("Erro na Conexão");
    }
}

public void addDespesa(String addDesp) throws SQLException{
    String sqlInsert, sqlSelect;
    sqlInsert = "insert into tipo_de_despesa(descricao) values ('"+addDesp+"')";
    comando.execute(sqlInsert); 
}
```

}

Comment: Cara porque você não questionou na outra pergunta?

Comment: Desculpe achei que não poderia ter questionado na mesma.

Comment: Você não iniciou a variavel comando, por isso ela está null. O método conexao precisa ser chamando antes do metodo addDespesa. Você leu o link que deixei na outra resposta?

Comment: Relacionada: [Buscando variável de outro método da mesa Classe Java](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/237976/28595)

Answer (score 0):

`comando` nunca foi inicializado e você tenta utilizar

```
comando.execute(sqlInsert);
```

Daí ocorre o erro, pois `comando` é `null`.

Antes de chamar `addDespesa`, lembre de inicializar seu objeto `comando` dessa forma:

```
comando = conexao.createStatement();
```