# Webservice delete error

Tags: java, web-service, jdbc, jax-rs

Estou com um problema no meu webservice. Está dando esse erro:

> SolicitaçãoFailed RequestFailed --> Status: (405)

O código que estou utilizando:

```
@DELETE
@Produces("text/plain")
@Path("ExcluirLista/{usuario}")
public boolean excluirTodos(@PathParam("usuario") String usuario)
{
    ProdutoDAO dao = new ProdutoDAO();
    return dao.excluir(usuario);
}

public boolean excluir(String usuario)
{
    String sql = "delete * from listaproduto where uclogin=?";
    Boolean retorno = false;
    PreparedStatement pst = Conexao.getPreparedStatement(sql);
    try {
        pst.setString(1,usuario);
        if(pst.executeUpdate()>0)
        {
            retorno = true;
        }   
    } catch (SQLException ex) {
        Logger.getLogger(ProdutoDAO.class.getName()).log(Level.SEVERE, null, ex);
        retorno = false;
    }
    return retorno;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

O erro 405 é o **Method not allowed**. Este erro indica que houve uma requisição em uma determinada URL utilizando-se de um verbo HTTP que não era o adequado.

O `@DELETE` deixa bem claro que a requisição deveria ser feita por meio do método HTTP DELETE. Se este erro foi produzido, é porque algum outro método HTTP (tal como POST) foi utilizado em seu lugar.

---

E embora não seja o que você perguntou, é possível melhorar o seu código assim:

```
@DELETE
@Produces("text/plain")
@Path("ExcluirLista/{usuario}")
public void excluirTodos(@PathParam("usuario") String usuario) {
    ProdutoDAO dao = new ProdutoDAO();
    dao.excluir(usuario);
}

public void excluir(String usuario) {
    String sql = "delete * from listaproduto where uclogin = ?";

    try (PreparedStatement pst = Conexao.getPreparedStatement(sql)) {
        pst.setString(1, usuario);
        if (pst.executeUpdate() == 0) throw new RuntimeException();
    } catch (SQLException ex) {
        Logger.getLogger(ProdutoDAO.class.getName()).log(Level.SEVERE, null, ex);
        throw new RuntimeException(ex);
    }
}
```

Não use `boolean`s para indicar erros, isso é uma má prática de programação. As exceções foram concebidas exatamente para que os programadores não tivessem que fazer isso, e portanto aproveite-se desse recurso que a linguagem te oferece.

E nunca deixe `PreparedStatement`s abertos por aí a toa. A melhor forma de gerenciá-los é por meio do [*try-with-resources*](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/172909/132).

Comment: Mesmo utilizando os códigos como vc passou, ele deu o erro 405, o que eu percebi é que em cima da minha busca no teste, ele não aparece a url que será usada, mas nos outros get's e post's que eu tenho mostra...

Comment: @RenatoCrispim Esses códigos não vão mudar o status HTTP. A causa desse erro está no código que tenta chamar o seu método `excluirTodos`. Esse método nem sequer está sendo invocado porque deve estar sendo chamado com o método HTTP incorreto.

Comment: Mas porque isso acontece? Saberia me dizer? Porque se eu criar um post ou get ele chama normalmente.

Comment: @RenatoCrispim Porque o código que está tentando invocar o seu método não está usando DELETE. Talvez ele esteja usando POST ou GET.

Comment: Não sei arrumar isso. O que posso fazer?

Comment: Como você está fazendo para chamar a url?

Comment: @RenatoCrispim Poste o código que você usa para chamar o seu serviço. Sem ele não dá para te dizer como arrumar.

Comment: Você diz código em outro sistema que chama o webservice? Eu só estou testando ele no netbeans... Tudo sobre o que está dando problema está ai... Eu só estou criando o delete e ta dando erro, como eu disse se eu criar um post ele funciona...