# Erro ao inserir dados do banco na JTable

Tags: java, nullpointerexception, conexão

Estou com um problema ao carregar os dados em uma JTable, uso BD Derby, a conexão do banco de dados funciona mais ao tentar abrir o JFrame Cad_Usuarios aparece o erro abaixo:

> ```
> Exception in thread "AWT-EventQueue-0" java.lang.NullPointerException
> at Controle.ConexaoBD.executaSQL(ConexaoBD.java:57)
> at Visao.Cad_Usuarios.preencherTabela(Cad_Usuarios.java:235)
> at Visao.Cad_Usuarios.<init>(Cad_Usuarios.java:32)
> at Visao.cadastro.jMUsuariosActionPerformed(cadastro.java:147)
> at Visao.cadastro.access$300(cadastro.java:9)
> at Visao.cadastro$4.actionPerformed(cadastro.java:96)
> at javax.swing.AbstractButton.fireActionPerformed(AbstractButton.java:2022)
> at javax.swing.AbstractButton$Handler.actionPerformed(AbstractButton.java:2348)
> at javax.swing.DefaultButtonModel.fireActionPerformed(DefaultButtonModel.java:402)
> at javax.swing.DefaultButtonModel.setPressed(DefaultButtonModel.java:259)
> at javax.swing.AbstractButton.doClick(AbstractButton.java:376)
> at javax.swing.plaf.basic.BasicMenuItemUI.doClick(BasicMenuItemUI.java:833)
> at javax.swing.plaf.basic.BasicMenuItemUI$Handler.mouseReleased(BasicMenuItemUI.java:877)
> at java.awt.Component.processMouseEvent(Component.java:6533)
> at javax.swing.JComponent.processMouseEvent(JComponent.java:3324)
> at java.awt.Component.processEvent(Component.java:6298)
> at java.awt.Container.processEvent(Container.java:2236)
> at java.awt.Component.dispatchEventImpl(Component.java:4889)
> at java.awt.Container.dispatchEventImpl(Container.java:2294)
> at java.awt.Component.dispatchEvent(Component.java:4711)
> at java.awt.LightweightDispatcher.retargetMouseEvent(Container.java:4888)
> at java.awt.LightweightDispatcher.processMouseEvent(Container.java:4525)
> at java.awt.LightweightDispatcher.dispatchEvent(Container.java:4466)
> at java.awt.Container.dispatchEventImpl(Container.java:2280)
> at java.awt.Window.dispatchEventImpl(Window.java:2746)
> at java.awt.Component.dispatchEvent(Component.java:4711)
> at java.awt.EventQueue.dispatchEventImpl(EventQueue.java:758)
> at java.awt.EventQueue.access$500(EventQueue.java:97)
> at java.awt.EventQueue$3.run(EventQueue.java:709)
> at java.awt.EventQueue$3.run(EventQueue.java:703)
> at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
> at java.security.ProtectionDomain$JavaSecurityAccessImpl.doIntersectionPrivilege(ProtectionDomain.java:80)
> at java.security.ProtectionDomain$JavaSecurityAccessImpl.doIntersectionPrivilege(ProtectionDomain.java:90)
> at java.awt.EventQueue$4.run(EventQueue.java:731)
> at java.awt.EventQueue$4.run(EventQueue.java:729)
> at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
> at java.security.ProtectionDomain$JavaSecurityAccessImpl.doIntersectionPrivilege(ProtectionDomain.java:80)
> at java.awt.EventQueue.dispatchEvent(EventQueue.java:728)
> at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpOneEventForFilters(EventDispatchThread.java:201)
> at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEventsForFilter(EventDispatchThread.java:116)
> at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEventsForHierarchy(EventDispatchThread.java:105)
> at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEvents(EventDispatchThread.java:101)
> at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEvents(EventDispatchThread.java:93)
> at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.run(EventDispatchThread.java:82)
> ```

Classe Usuario:

```
package Modelo;

import java.io.Serializable;
import javax.persistence.Column;
import javax.persistence.Entity;
import javax.persistence.Id;
import javax.persistence.Table;


@Entity
@Table(name="ROOT.USUARIO")
public class Usuario implements Serializable{


    @Id
    @Column(name = "LOGIN", nullable = false)
    private String login;

    @Column(name = "SENHA", nullable = false)
    private String senha;


    @Column(name = "NOME", nullable = false)
    private String nome;

    public String getLogin() {
        return login;
    }

    public void setLogin(String login) {
        this.login = login;
    }

    public String getSenha() {
        return senha;
    }

    public void setSenha(String senha) {
        this.senha = senha;
    }

    public String getNome() {
        return nome;
    }

    public void setNome(String nome) {
        this.nome = nome;
    }

     public Usuario(){}

}
```

Form Cad_Usuarios

```
package Visao;

import Controle.ConexaoBD;
import Modelo.ModeloTabela;
import Modelo.Usuario;
import java.sql.SQLException;
import java.util.ArrayList;
import javax.persistence.EntityManager;
import javax.persistence.EntityManagerFactory;
import javax.persistence.Persistence;
import javax.swing.JOptionPane;
import javax.swing.ListSelectionModel;
import static org.eclipse.persistence.jpa.jpql.parser.Expression.SQL;


public class Cad_Usuarios extends javax.swing.JFrame {
    EntityManagerFactory factory;
    EntityManager manager;

    ConexaoBD conecta = new ConexaoBD();

    public Cad_Usuarios() {
        initComponents();
        preencherTabela("select * from usuarios order by login");
        try{
            factory = Persistence.createEntityManagerFactory("Ponto_DablioPU");
            manager = factory.createEntityManager();
        }catch(Exception e){
            System.exit(1);
        }
    }

    public void limpar(){
        jTLogin.setText(null);
        jTNome.setText(null);
        jPFSenha.setText(null);    
    }
    private void jBSalvarActionPerformed(java.awt.event.ActionEvent evt) {                                         

        Usuario user = new Usuario();

        user.setLogin(jTLogin.getText());

        user.setNome(jTNome.getText());

        user.setSenha(jPFSenha.getText());

        manager.getTransaction().begin();

        manager.persist(user);

        manager.getTransaction().commit();

        JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, "Usuário Cadastrado com Sucesso!");

        limpar();

    }                                        

    private void jBSairActionPerformed(java.awt.event.ActionEvent evt) {                                       
        dispose();
    }                                      

    private void jBLimparActionPerformed(java.awt.event.ActionEvent evt) {                                         
        limpar();
    }                                        

    public void preencherTabela(String SQL){
        ArrayList dados = new ArrayList();

        String[] Colunas = new String[]{"Login","Senha","Nome"};


        conecta.executaSQL(SQL);
        try{
            conecta.rs.first();
            do{
                dados.add(new Object[]{conecta.rs.getInt("login"),conecta.rs.getString("senha"),conecta.rs.getString("nome")});
            }while(conecta.rs.next());
        }catch (SQLException ex){
            JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null,"Erro ao preencher o ArrayList! \n ERRO:");
        }

        ModeloTabela modelo = new ModeloTabela(dados, Colunas);
        jTable1.setModel(modelo);
        jTable1.getColumnModel().getColumn(0).setPreferredWidth(150);
        jTable1.getColumnModel().getColumn(0).setResizable(false);

        jTable1.getColumnModel().getColumn(1).setPreferredWidth(150);
        jTable1.getColumnModel().getColumn(1).setResizable(false);

        jTable1.getColumnModel().getColumn(2).setPreferredWidth(80);
        jTable1.getColumnModel().getColumn(2).setResizable(false);

        jTable1.getTableHeader().setReorderingAllowed(false);
        jTable1.setAutoResizeMode(jTable1.AUTO_RESIZE_OFF);

        jTable1.setSelectionMode(ListSelectionModel.SINGLE_SELECTION);

    }
```

Classe ModeloTabela

```
package Modelo;

import java.util.ArrayList;
import javax.swing.table.AbstractTableModel;

public class ModeloTabela extends AbstractTableModel{
private ArrayList linhas = null;
private String[] colunas = null;


public ModeloTabela(ArrayList lin,String[] col){
    setLinhas(lin);
    setColunas(col);

}

public ArrayList getLinhas(){
    return linhas;
}

public void setLinhas(ArrayList dados){
    linhas = dados;
}

public String []  getColunas(){
    return colunas;
}

public void setColunas(String[] nomes){
    colunas = nomes;
}

public int getColumnCount(){
    return colunas.length;
}

public int getRowCount(){
    return linhas.size();
}

public String getColumnName(int numCol){
    return colunas[numCol];
}

public Object getValueAt(int numLin, int numCol){
    Object[] linha = (Object[])getLinhas().get(numLin);
    return linha[numCol];
}
}
```

Classe ConexaoBD

```
import java.sql.*;
import java.util.logging.Level;
import java.util.logging.Logger;
import javax.swing.JOptionPane;

public class ConexaoBD {


public Statement stm;
public ResultSet rs;
private String driver = "org.apache.derby.jdbc.EmbeddedDriver";
private String caminho = "jdbc:derby://localhost:1527/ponto_dablio";
private String usuario = "root";
private String senha = "root";
public Connection connection;

public void conexao(){

    try {
        System.setProperty("jdbc.Drivers", driver);
        connection = DriverManager.getConnection(caminho, usuario, senha);
    } catch (SQLException ex) {
        JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null,"CONECTADO COM SUCESSO!!\n Erro:" + ex.getMessage());
    }

}

public void executaSQL(String sql) { 

   try {
       stm =     connection.createStatement(rs.TYPE_SCROLL_INSENSITIVE,rs.CONCUR_READ_ONLY);
       rs = stm.executeQuery(sql);
       } catch (SQLException ex) {
         JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null,"ERRO DE EXECUTASQL!!\n ERRO: " + ex.getMessage());
       }
}

public void desconecta(){
    try{
        connection.close();
    }catch (SQLException ex){
        JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null,"Erro ao fechar conexão!\n Erro:"         + ex.getMessage());
    }
}


}
```

---

fiz a alteração mais continua dando erro diz que a tabela "usuarios" não existe, erro:

> ```
> `Exception in thread "AWT-EventQueue-0" java.lang.NullPointerException
> at Visao.Cad_Usuarios.preencherTabela(Cad_Usuarios.java:238)
> at Visao.Cad_Usuarios.<init>(Cad_Usuarios.java:32)
> at Visao.cadastro.jMUsuariosActionPerformed(cadastro.java:147)
> at Visao.cadastro.access$300(cadastro.java:9)
> at Visao.cadastro$4.actionPerformed(cadastro.java:96)
> at javax.swing.AbstractButton.fireActionPerformed(AbstractButton.java:2022)
> at javax.swing.AbstractButton$Handler.actionPerformed(AbstractButton.java:2348)
> at javax.swing.DefaultButtonModel.fireActionPerformed(DefaultButtonModel.java:402)
> at javax.swing.DefaultButtonModel.setPressed(DefaultButtonModel.java:259)
> at javax.swing.AbstractButton.doClick(AbstractButton.java:376)
> at javax.swing.plaf.basic.BasicMenuItemUI.doClick(BasicMenuItemUI.java:833)
> at javax.swing.plaf.basic.BasicMenuItemUI$Handler.mouseReleased(BasicMenuItemUI.java:877)
> at java.awt.Component.processMouseEvent(Component.java:6533)
> at javax.swing.JComponent.processMouseEvent(JComponent.java:3324)
> at java.awt.Component.processEvent(Component.java:6298)
> at java.awt.Container.processEvent(Container.java:2236)
> at java.awt.Component.dispatchEventImpl(Component.java:4889)
> at java.awt.Container.dispatchEventImpl(Container.java:2294)
> at java.awt.Component.dispatchEvent(Component.java:4711)
> at java.awt.LightweightDispatcher.retargetMouseEvent(Container.java:4888)
> at java.awt.LightweightDispatcher.processMouseEvent(Container.java:4525)
> at java.awt.LightweightDispatcher.dispatchEvent(Container.java:4466)
> at java.awt.Container.dispatchEventImpl(Container.java:2280)
> at java.awt.Window.dispatchEventImpl(Window.java:2746)
> at java.awt.Component.dispatchEvent(Component.java:4711)
> at java.awt.EventQueue.dispatchEventImpl(EventQueue.java:758)
> at java.awt.EventQueue.access$500(EventQueue.java:97)
> at java.awt.EventQueue$3.run(EventQueue.java:709)
> at java.awt.EventQueue$3.run(EventQueue.java:703)
> at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
> at java.security.ProtectionDomain$JavaSecurityAccessImpl.doIntersectionPrivilege(ProtectionDomain.java:80)
> at java.security.ProtectionDomain$JavaSecurityAccessImpl.doIntersectionPrivilege(ProtectionDomain.java:90)
> at java.awt.EventQueue$4.run(EventQueue.java:731)
> at java.awt.EventQueue$4.run(EventQueue.java:729)
> at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
> at java.security.ProtectionDomain$JavaSecurityAccessImpl.doIntersectionPrivilege(ProtectionDomain.java:80)
> at java.awt.EventQueue.dispatchEvent(EventQueue.java:728)
> at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpOneEventForFilters(EventDispatchThread.java:201)
> at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEventsForFilter(EventDispatchThread.java:116)
> at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEventsForHierarchy(EventDispatchThread.java:105)
> at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEvents(EventDispatchThread.java:101)
> at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEvents(EventDispatchThread.java:93)
> at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.run(EventDispatchThread.java:82)
> ```

Comment: fiz a alteração mais ainda continuou dando erro, escrevi o erro abaixo, obrigado

Comment: desculpe, sou novato, adicionei acima o erro apresentado apos fazer a alteração informada.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Você não iniciou a conexão no método `preencheTabela()`. Faltou invocar o método `conexao()` da classe `ConexaoBD`:

```
public void preencherTabela(String SQL){
    ArrayList dados = new ArrayList();

    String[] Colunas = new String[]{"Login","Senha","Nome"};

    conecta.conexao();

    conecta.executaSQL(SQL);
    try{
        conecta.rs.first();
        do{
            dados.add(new Object[]{conecta.rs.getInt("login"),conecta.rs.getString("senha"),conecta.rs.getString("nome")});
        }while(conecta.rs.next());
    }catch (SQLException ex){
        JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null,"Erro ao preencher o ArrayList! \n ERRO:");
    }

...
```

---

Quanto ao segundo erro, observando seu model, a tabela se chama "USUARIO" e na query que popula a tabela você está passando como "usuarios". Conserte o nome da tabela na query:

```
public Cad_Usuarios() {
    initComponents();
    preencherTabela("select * from usuario order by login");
    try{
        factory = Persistence.createEntityManagerFactory("Ponto_DablioPU");
        manager = factory.createEntityManager();
    }catch(Exception e){
        System.exit(1);
    }
}
```

Leitura recomendada: [Como funciona o try-with-resources?](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/172909/28595)

Comment: Resolvi o erro por enquanto, amanhã vou continuar no projeto e se surgir o erro novamente volto a informar, muito Obrigado mesmo Articuno. Tinha um String no banco que estava como .getInt ao add no banco e o nome da tabela estava errada mesmo, obrigado!!

Comment: @DhouglasSilvaGomes caso a resposta tenha lhe ajudado a resolver a duvida da pergunta, [**veja aqui**](https://pt.meta.stackoverflow.com/a/1079/28595) como concluir a pergunta.