# Dois filtros funcionando em um relatório em JAVA

Tags: java, jdbc, jasper-reports

Pessoal estou fazendo um trabalho para a faculdade cheguei na parte dos relatórios e criei o relatório como mostra a imagem

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Contudo consegui apenas fazer o campo nome funcionar  em uma segunda classe java que criei usando o seguinte código

```
public class rela_clientes_nome {
    conexaoBD conn = new conexaoBD();

    public void rela_clientes(String nome) {

        try {
            conn.conexao();
            conn.executaSql("select * from clientes where nome like '%"+nome+"%'");
            JRResultSetDataSource relatResul = new JRResultSetDataSource(conn.rs);
            JasperPrint jpPrint = JasperFillManager.fillReport("src/rela_ireport/clientes.jasper", new HashMap(), relatResul);
            JasperViewer jv = new JasperViewer(jpPrint, false);
            jv.setVisible(true);
            jv.toFront();
        } catch (JRException ex) {
            Logger.getLogger(rela_clientes_nome.class.getName()).log(Level.SEVERE, null, ex);
        }
    }
}
```

Bom dessa forma eu chamei no botão imprimir o relatório criado com o IREPORT e esta puchando apenas pelo FILTRO NOME como mostra o código:

```
private void jButtonImprimirActionPerformed(java.awt.event.ActionEvent evt) {                                                
    // TODO add your handling code here:
    rela_clientes relatorio = new rela_clientes();
    relatorio.rela_clientes(jTextFieldNome.getText());
}
```

Bom gostaria de saber como arrumar os dois filtros NOME e CPF funcionando juntos?

Comment: Leia sobre [**injeção de SQL**](https://pt.wikipedia.org/wiki/Inje%C3%A7%C3%A3o_de_SQL).

Comment: O que é `conn`? Você pode editar a pergunta e colocar o código dessa classe? Recomendo a você dar uma olhada [**nessa pergunta e em suas respostas também**](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/172909/132).

Comment: conn é a instância com o banco de dados conexaoBD conn = new conexaoBD();