# Erro com SQL e MariaDB (Current position is before the first row)

Tags: java, mysql, sql, jdbc, mariadb

Eu estou com um problema no meu banco de dados e não faço a menor ideia do que seja.

```
public String getBlockPermission(String blockstring){
    String permission = "";
    try{
        ResultSet res = connection.createStatement().executeQuery("select permission from limitedblocks where blockstring='" + blockstring + "';");
        permission = res.getString("permission");
    }catch(Exception e){
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
    return permission;
}
```

**Erro:**

```
java.sql.SQLDataException: Current position is before the first row
[04:49:08] [Server thread/INFO] [STDERR/]: [me.vitoremnoel.blocklimiter.BlockLimiter:getBlockPermission:242]:   at org.mariadb.jdbc.internal.util.ExceptionMapper.get(ExceptionMapper.java:115)
[04:49:08] [Server thread/INFO] [STDERR/]: [me.vitoremnoel.blocklimiter.BlockLimiter:getBlockPermission:242]:   at org.mariadb.jdbc.internal.util.ExceptionMapper.throwException(ExceptionMapper.java:69)
[04:49:08] [Server thread/INFO] [STDERR/]: [me.vitoremnoel.blocklimiter.BlockLimiter:getBlockPermission:242]:   at org.mariadb.jdbc.internal.queryresults.resultset.MariaSelectResultSet.throwError(MariaSelectResultSet.java:566)
[04:49:08] [Server thread/INFO] [STDERR/]: [me.vitoremnoel.blocklimiter.BlockLimiter:getBlockPermission:242]:   at org.mariadb.jdbc.internal.queryresults.resultset.MariaSelectResultSet.checkObjectRange(MariaSelectResultSet.java:549)
[04:49:08] [Server thread/INFO] [STDERR/]: [me.vitoremnoel.blocklimiter.BlockLimiter:getBlockPermission:242]:   at org.mariadb.jdbc.internal.queryresults.resultset.MariaSelectResultSet.getString(MariaSelectResultSet.java:820)
[04:49:08] [Server thread/INFO] [STDERR/]: [me.vitoremnoel.blocklimiter.BlockLimiter:getBlockPermission:242]:   at org.mariadb.jdbc.internal.queryresults.resultset.MariaSelectResultSet.getString(MariaSelectResultSet.java:828)
[04:49:08] [Server thread/INFO] [STDERR/]: [me.vitoremnoel.blocklimiter.BlockLimiter:getBlockPermission:242]:   at me.vitoremnoel.blocklimiter.BlockLimiter.getBlockPermission(BlockLimiter.java:240)
[04:49:08] [Server thread/INFO] [STDERR/]: [me.vitoremnoel.blocklimiter.BlockLimiter:getBlockPermission:242]:   at me.vitoremnoel.blocklimiter.BlockLimiter.canPlace(BlockLimiter.java:250)
[04:49:08] [Server thread/INFO] [STDERR/]: [me.vitoremnoel.blocklimiter.BlockLimiter:getBlockPermission:242]:   at me.vitoremnoel.blocklimiter.listeners.MainListeners.placeBlockEvent(MainListeners.java:33)
[04:49:08] [Server thread/INFO] [STDERR/]: [me.vitoremnoel.blocklimiter.BlockLimiter:getBlockPermission:242]:   at org.spongepowered.common.event.listener.PlaceListener_MainListeners_placeBlockEvent7.handle(Unknown Source)
[04:49:08] [Server thread/INFO] [STDERR/]: [me.vitoremnoel.blocklimiter.BlockLimiter:getBlockPermission:242]:   at org.spongepowered.common.event.RegisteredListener.handle(RegisteredListener.java:95)
[04:49:08] [Server thread/INFO] [STDERR/]: [me.vitoremnoel.blocklimiter.BlockLimiter:getBlockPermission:242]:   at org.spongepowered.mod.event.SpongeModEventManager.post(SpongeModEventManager.java:313)
[04:49:08] [Server thread/INFO] [STDERR/]: [me.vitoremnoel.blocklimiter.BlockLimiter:getBlockPermission:242]:   at org.spongepowered.mod.event.SpongeModEventManager.post(SpongeModEventManager.java:297)
[04:49:08] [Server thread/INFO] [STDERR/]: [me.vitoremnoel.blocklimiter.BlockLimiter:getBlockPermission:242]:   at org.spongepowered.mod.event.SpongeModEventManager.post(SpongeModEventManager.java:338)
[04:49:08] [Server thread/INFO] [STDERR/]: [me.vitoremnoel.blocklimiter.BlockLimiter:getBlockPermission:242]:   at org.spongepowered.mod.event.SpongeModEventManager.post(SpongeModEventManager.java:326)
[04:49:08] [Server thread/INFO] [STDERR/]: [me.vitoremnoel.blocklimiter.BlockLimiter:getBlockPermission:242]:   at org.spongepowered.common.SpongeImpl.postEvent(SpongeImpl.java:143)
[04:49:08] [Server thread/INFO] [STDERR/]: [me.vitoremnoel.blocklimiter.BlockLimiter:getBlockPermission:242]:   at org.spongepowered.common.event.tracking.TrackingUtil.iterateChangeBlockEvents(TrackingUtil.java:629)
[04:49:08] [Server thread/INFO] [STDERR/]: [me.vitoremnoel.blocklimiter.BlockLimiter:getBlockPermission:242]:   at org.spongepowered.common.event.tracking.TrackingUtil.processBlockCaptures(TrackingUtil.java:536)
[04:49:09] [Server thread/INFO] [STDERR/]: [me.vitoremnoel.blocklimiter.BlockLimiter:getBlockPermission:242]:   at org.spongepowered.common.event.tracking.phase.packet.PacketFunction.lambda$null$41(PacketFunction.java:848)
[04:49:09] [Server thread/INFO] [STDERR/]: [me.vitoremnoel.blocklimiter.BlockLimiter:getBlockPermission:242]:   at org.spongepowered.common.event.tracking.CapturedSupplier.ifPresentAndNotEmpty(CapturedSupplier.java:57)
[04:49:09] [Server thread/INFO] [STDERR/]: [me.vitoremnoel.blocklimiter.BlockLimiter:getBlockPermission:242]:   at org.spongepowered.common.event.tracking.phase.packet.PacketFunction.lambda$static$44(PacketFunction.java:846)
[04:49:09] [Server thread/INFO] [STDERR/]: [me.vitoremnoel.blocklimiter.BlockLimiter:getBlockPermission:242]:   at org.spongepowered.common.event.tracking.phase.packet.PacketPhase.unwind(PacketPhase.java:324)
[04:49:09] [Server thread/INFO] [STDERR/]: [me.vitoremnoel.blocklimiter.BlockLimiter:getBlockPermission:242]:   at org.spongepowered.common.event.tracking.CauseTracker.completePhase(CauseTracker.java:226)
[04:49:09] [Server thread/INFO] [STDERR/]: [me.vitoremnoel.blocklimiter.BlockLimiter:getBlockPermission:242]:   at org.spongepowered.common.event.tracking.CauseTracker.switchToPhase(CauseTracker.java:168)
[04:49:09] [Server thread/INFO] [STDERR/]: [me.vitoremnoel.blocklimiter.BlockLimiter:getBlockPermission:242]:   at org.spongepowered.common.network.PacketUtil.onProcessPacket(PacketUtil.java:156)
[04:49:09] [Server thread/INFO] [STDERR/]: [me.vitoremnoel.blocklimiter.BlockLimiter:getBlockPermission:242]:   at net.minecraft.network.PacketThreadUtil$1.redirect$onProcessPacket$zjj000(SourceFile:539)
[04:49:09] [Server thread/INFO] [STDERR/]: [me.vitoremnoel.blocklimiter.BlockLimiter:getBlockPermission:242]:   at net.minecraft.network.PacketThreadUtil$1.run(SourceFile:13)
[04:49:09] [Server thread/INFO] [STDERR/]: [me.vitoremnoel.blocklimiter.BlockLimiter:getBlockPermission:242]:   at java.util.concurrent.Executors$RunnableAdapter.call(Unknown Source)
[04:49:09] [Server thread/INFO] [STDERR/]: [me.vitoremnoel.blocklimiter.BlockLimiter:getBlockPermission:242]:   at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(Unknown Source)
[04:49:09] [Server thread/INFO] [STDERR/]: [me.vitoremnoel.blocklimiter.BlockLimiter:getBlockPermission:242]:   at net.minecraft.util.Util.func_181617_a(SourceFile:45)
[04:49:09] [Server thread/INFO] [STDERR/]: [me.vitoremnoel.blocklimiter.BlockLimiter:getBlockPermission:242]:   at org.spongepowered.common.SpongeImplHooks.onUtilRunTask(SpongeImplHooks.java:239)
[04:49:09] [Server thread/INFO] [STDERR/]: [me.vitoremnoel.blocklimiter.BlockLimiter:getBlockPermission:242]:   at net.minecraft.server.MinecraftServer.redirect$onRun$zhp000(MinecraftServer.java:3948)
[04:49:09] [Server thread/INFO] [STDERR/]: [me.vitoremnoel.blocklimiter.BlockLimiter:getBlockPermission:242]:   at net.minecraft.server.MinecraftServer.func_71190_q(MinecraftServer.java:668)
[04:49:09] [Server thread/INFO] [STDERR/]: [me.vitoremnoel.blocklimiter.BlockLimiter:getBlockPermission:242]:   at net.minecraft.server.dedicated.DedicatedServer.func_71190_q(DedicatedServer.java:387)
[04:49:09] [Server thread/INFO] [STDERR/]: [me.vitoremnoel.blocklimiter.BlockLimiter:getBlockPermission:242]:   at net.minecraft.server.MinecraftServer.func_71217_p(MinecraftServer.java:613)
[04:49:09] [Server thread/INFO] [STDERR/]: [me.vitoremnoel.blocklimiter.BlockLimiter:getBlockPermission:242]:   at net.minecraft.server.MinecraftServer.run(MinecraftServer.java:471)
[04:49:09] [Server thread/INFO] [STDERR/]: [me.vitoremnoel.blocklimiter.BlockLimiter:getBlockPermission:242]:   at java.lang.Thread.run(Unknown Source)
[04:49:09] [Server thread/INFO] [STDERR/]: [java.lang.Throwable:printStackTrace:-1]: Caused by: org.mariadb.jdbc.internal.util.dao.QueryException: Current position is before the first row
[04:49:09] [Server thread/INFO] [STDERR/]: [java.lang.Throwable:printStackTrace:-1]:    ... 35 more
[04:49:09] [Server thread/INFO] [STDERR/]: [me.vitoremnoel.blocklimiter.BlockLimiter:placed:270]: java.sql.SQLDataException: Current position is before the first row
[04:49:09] [Server thread/INFO] [STDERR/]: [me.vitoremnoel.blocklimiter.BlockLimiter:placed:270]:   at org.mariadb.jdbc.internal.util.ExceptionMapper.get(ExceptionMapper.java:115)
[04:49:09] [Server thread/INFO] [STDERR/]: [me.vitoremnoel.blocklimiter.BlockLimiter:placed:270]:   at org.mariadb.jdbc.internal.util.ExceptionMapper.throwException(ExceptionMapper.java:69)
[04:49:09] [Server thread/INFO] [STDERR/]: [me.vitoremnoel.blocklimiter.BlockLimiter:placed:270]:   at org.mariadb.jdbc.internal.queryresults.resultset.MariaSelectResultSet.throwError(MariaSelectResultSet.java:566)
[04:49:09] [Server thread/INFO] [STDERR/]: [me.vitoremnoel.blocklimiter.BlockLimiter:placed:270]:   at org.mariadb.jdbc.internal.queryresults.resultset.MariaSelectResultSet.checkObjectRange(MariaSelectResultSet.java:549)
[04:49:09] [Server thread/INFO] [STDERR/]: [me.vitoremnoel.blocklimiter.BlockLimiter:placed:270]:   at org.mariadb.jdbc.internal.queryresults.resultset.MariaSelectResultSet.getInt(MariaSelectResultSet.java:942)
[04:49:09] [Server thread/INFO] [STDERR/]: [me.vitoremnoel.blocklimiter.BlockLimiter:placed:270]:   at org.mariadb.jdbc.internal.queryresults.resultset.MariaSelectResultSet.getInt(MariaSelectResultSet.java:949)
[04:49:09] [Server thread/INFO] [STDERR/]: [me.vitoremnoel.blocklimiter.BlockLimiter:placed:270]:   at me.vitoremnoel.blocklimiter.BlockLimiter.placed(BlockLimiter.java:267)
[04:49:09] [Server thread/INFO] [STDERR/]: [me.vitoremnoel.blocklimiter.BlockLimiter:placed:270]:   at me.vitoremnoel.blocklimiter.listeners.MainListeners.placeBlockEvent(MainListeners.java:37)
[04:49:09] [Server thread/INFO] [STDERR/]: [me.vitoremnoel.blocklimiter.BlockLimiter:placed:270]:   at org.spongepowered.common.event.listener.PlaceListener_MainListeners_placeBlockEvent7.handle(Unknown Source)
[04:49:09] [Server thread/INFO] [STDERR/]: [me.vitoremnoel.blocklimiter.BlockLimiter:placed:270]:   at org.spongepowered.common.event.RegisteredListener.handle(RegisteredListener.java:95)
[04:49:09] [Server thread/INFO] [STDERR/]: [me.vitoremnoel.blocklimiter.BlockLimiter:placed:270]:   at org.spongepowered.mod.event.SpongeModEventManager.post(SpongeModEventManager.java:313)
[04:49:09] [Server thread/INFO] [STDERR/]: [me.vitoremnoel.blocklimiter.BlockLimiter:placed:270]:   at org.spongepowered.mod.event.SpongeModEventManager.post(SpongeModEventManager.java:297)
[04:49:09] [Server thread/INFO] [STDERR/]: [me.vitoremnoel.blocklimiter.BlockLimiter:placed:270]:   at org.spongepowered.mod.event.SpongeModEventManager.post(SpongeModEventManager.java:338)
[04:49:09] [Server thread/INFO] [STDERR/]: [me.vitoremnoel.blocklimiter.BlockLimiter:placed:270]:   at org.spongepowered.mod.event.SpongeModEventManager.post(SpongeModEventManager.java:326)
[04:49:09] [Server thread/INFO] [STDERR/]: [me.vitoremnoel.blocklimiter.BlockLimiter:placed:270]:   at org.spongepowered.common.SpongeImpl.postEvent(SpongeImpl.java:143)
[04:49:09] [Server thread/INFO] [STDERR/]: [me.vitoremnoel.blocklimiter.BlockLimiter:placed:270]:   at org.spongepowered.common.event.tracking.TrackingUtil.iterateChangeBlockEvents(TrackingUtil.java:629)
[04:49:09] [Server thread/INFO] [STDERR/]: [me.vitoremnoel.blocklimiter.BlockLimiter:placed:270]:   at org.spongepowered.common.event.tracking.TrackingUtil.processBlockCaptures(TrackingUtil.java:536)
[04:49:09] [Server thread/INFO] [STDERR/]: [me.vitoremnoel.blocklimiter.BlockLimiter:placed:270]:   at org.spongepowered.common.event.tracking.phase.packet.PacketFunction.lambda$null$41(PacketFunction.java:848)
[04:49:09] [Server thread/INFO] [STDERR/]: [me.vitoremnoel.blocklimiter.BlockLimiter:placed:270]:   at org.spongepowered.common.event.tracking.CapturedSupplier.ifPresentAndNotEmpty(CapturedSupplier.java:57)
[04:49:09] [Server thread/INFO] [STDERR/]: [me.vitoremnoel.blocklimiter.BlockLimiter:placed:270]:   at org.spongepowered.common.event.tracking.phase.packet.PacketFunction.lambda$static$44(PacketFunction.java:846)
[04:49:09] [Server thread/INFO] [STDERR/]: [me.vitoremnoel.blocklimiter.BlockLimiter:placed:270]:   at org.spongepowered.common.event.tracking.phase.packet.PacketPhase.unwind(PacketPhase.java:324)
[04:49:09] [Server thread/INFO] [STDERR/]: [me.vitoremnoel.blocklimiter.BlockLimiter:placed:270]:   at org.spongepowered.common.event.tracking.CauseTracker.completePhase(CauseTracker.java:226)
[04:49:09] [Server thread/INFO] [STDERR/]: [me.vitoremnoel.blocklimiter.BlockLimiter:placed:270]:   at org.spongepowered.common.event.tracking.CauseTracker.switchToPhase(CauseTracker.java:168)
[04:49:09] [Server thread/INFO] [STDERR/]: [me.vitoremnoel.blocklimiter.BlockLimiter:placed:270]:   at org.spongepowered.common.network.PacketUtil.onProcessPacket(PacketUtil.java:156)
[04:49:09] [Server thread/INFO] [STDERR/]: [me.vitoremnoel.blocklimiter.BlockLimiter:placed:270]:   at net.minecraft.network.PacketThreadUtil$1.redirect$onProcessPacket$zjj000(SourceFile:539)
[04:49:09] [Server thread/INFO] [STDERR/]: [me.vitoremnoel.blocklimiter.BlockLimiter:placed:270]:   at net.minecraft.network.PacketThreadUtil$1.run(SourceFile:13)
[04:49:09] [Server thread/INFO] [STDERR/]: [me.vitoremnoel.blocklimiter.BlockLimiter:placed:270]:   at java.util.concurrent.Executors$RunnableAdapter.call(Unknown Source)
[04:49:09] [Server thread/INFO] [STDERR/]: [me.vitoremnoel.blocklimiter.BlockLimiter:placed:270]:   at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(Unknown Source)
[04:49:09] [Server thread/INFO] [STDERR/]: [me.vitoremnoel.blocklimiter.BlockLimiter:placed:270]:   at net.minecraft.util.Util.func_181617_a(SourceFile:45)
[04:49:09] [Server thread/INFO] [STDERR/]: [me.vitoremnoel.blocklimiter.BlockLimiter:placed:270]:   at org.spongepowered.common.SpongeImplHooks.onUtilRunTask(SpongeImplHooks.java:239)
[04:49:09] [Server thread/INFO] [STDERR/]: [me.vitoremnoel.blocklimiter.BlockLimiter:placed:270]:   at net.minecraft.server.MinecraftServer.redirect$onRun$zhp000(MinecraftServer.java:3948)
[04:49:09] [Server thread/INFO] [STDERR/]: [me.vitoremnoel.blocklimiter.BlockLimiter:placed:270]:   at net.minecraft.server.MinecraftServer.func_71190_q(MinecraftServer.java:668)
[04:49:09] [Server thread/INFO] [STDERR/]: [me.vitoremnoel.blocklimiter.BlockLimiter:placed:270]:   at net.minecraft.server.dedicated.DedicatedServer.func_71190_q(DedicatedServer.java:387)
[04:49:09] [Server thread/INFO] [STDERR/]: [me.vitoremnoel.blocklimiter.BlockLimiter:placed:270]:   at net.minecraft.server.MinecraftServer.func_71217_p(MinecraftServer.java:613)
[04:49:09] [Server thread/INFO] [STDERR/]: [me.vitoremnoel.blocklimiter.BlockLimiter:placed:270]:   at net.minecraft.server.MinecraftServer.run(MinecraftServer.java:471)
[04:49:09] [Server thread/INFO] [STDERR/]: [me.vitoremnoel.blocklimiter.BlockLimiter:placed:270]:   at java.lang.Thread.run(Unknown Source)
[04:49:09] [Server thread/INFO] [STDERR/]: [java.lang.Throwable:printStackTrace:-1]: Caused by: org.mariadb.jdbc.internal.util.dao.QueryException: Current position is before the first row
[04:49:09] [Server thread/INFO] [STDERR/]: [java.lang.Throwable:printStackTrace:-1]:    ... 34 more
[04:49:09] [Server thread/INFO] [STDERR/]: [me.vitoremnoel.blocklimiter.BlockLimiter:getBlockPermission:242]: java.sql.SQLDataException: Current position is before the first row
[04:49:09] [Server thread/INFO] [STDERR/]: [me.vitoremnoel.blocklimiter.BlockLimiter:getBlockPermission:242]:   at org.mariadb.jdbc.internal.util.ExceptionMapper.get(ExceptionMapper.java:115)
[04:49:09] [Server thread/INFO] [STDERR/]: [me.vitoremnoel.blocklimiter.BlockLimiter:getBlockPermission:242]:   at org.mariadb.jdbc.internal.util.ExceptionMapper.throwException(ExceptionMapper.java:69)
[04:49:09] [Server thread/INFO] [STDERR/]: [me.vitoremnoel.blocklimiter.BlockLimiter:getBlockPermission:242]:   at org.mariadb.jdbc.internal.queryresults.resultset.MariaSelectResultSet.throwError(MariaSelectResultSet.java:566)
[04:49:09] [Server thread/INFO] [STDERR/]: [me.vitoremnoel.blocklimiter.BlockLimiter:getBlockPermission:242]:   at org.mariadb.jdbc.internal.queryresults.resultset.MariaSelectResultSet.checkObjectRange(MariaSelectResultSet.java:549)
[04:49:09] [Server thread/INFO] [STDERR/]: [me.vitoremnoel.blocklimiter.BlockLimiter:getBlockPermission:242]:   at org.mariadb.jdbc.internal.queryresults.resultset.MariaSelectResultSet.getString(MariaSelectResultSet.java:820)
[04:49:09] [Server thread/INFO] [STDERR/]: [me.vitoremnoel.blocklimiter.BlockLimiter:getBlockPermission:242]:   at org.mariadb.jdbc.internal.queryresults.resultset.MariaSelectResultSet.getString(MariaSelectResultSet.java:828)
[04:49:09] [Server thread/INFO] [STDERR/]: [me.vitoremnoel.blocklimiter.BlockLimiter:getBlockPermission:242]:   at me.vitoremnoel.blocklimiter.BlockLimiter.getBlockPermission(BlockLimiter.java:240)
[04:49:09] [Server thread/INFO] [STDERR/]: [me.vitoremnoel.blocklimiter.BlockLimiter:getBlockPermission:242]:   at me.vitoremnoel.blocklimiter.listeners.MainListeners.placeBlockEvent(MainListeners.java:38)
[04:49:09] [Server thread/INFO] [STDERR/]: [me.vitoremnoel.blocklimiter.BlockLimiter:getBlockPermission:242]:   at org.spongepowered.common.event.listener.PlaceListener_MainListeners_placeBlockEvent7.handle(Unknown Source)
[04:49:09] [Server thread/INFO] [STDERR/]: [me.vitoremnoel.blocklimiter.BlockLimiter:getBlockPermission:242]:   at org.spongepowered.common.event.RegisteredListener.handle(RegisteredListener.java:95)
[04:49:09] [Server thread/INFO] [STDERR/]: [me.vitoremnoel.blocklimiter.BlockLimiter:getBlockPermission:242]:   at org.spongepowered.mod.event.SpongeModEventManager.post(SpongeModEventManager.java:313)
[04:49:09] [Server thread/INFO] [STDERR/]: [me.vitoremnoel.blocklimiter.BlockLimiter:getBlockPermission:242]:   at org.spongepowered.mod.event.SpongeModEventManager.post(SpongeModEventManager.java:297)
[04:49:09] [Server thread/INFO] [STDERR/]: [me.vitoremnoel.blocklimiter.BlockLimiter:getBlockPermission:242]:   at org.spongepowered.mod.event.SpongeModEventManager.post(SpongeModEventManager.java:338)
[04:49:09] [Server thread/INFO] [STDERR/]: [me.vitoremnoel.blocklimiter.BlockLimiter:getBlockPermission:242]:   at org.spongepowered.mod.event.SpongeModEventManager.post(SpongeModEventManager.java:326)
[04:49:09] [Server thread/INFO] [STDERR/]: [me.vitoremnoel.blocklimiter.BlockLimiter:getBlockPermission:242]:   at org.spongepowered.common.SpongeImpl.postEvent(SpongeImpl.java:143)
[04:49:09] [Server thread/INFO] [STDERR/]: [me.vitoremnoel.blocklimiter.BlockLimiter:getBlockPermission:242]:   at org.spongepowered.common.event.tracking.TrackingUtil.iterateChangeBlockEvents(TrackingUtil.java:629)
[04:49:09] [Server thread/INFO] [STDERR/]: [me.vitoremnoel.blocklimiter.BlockLimiter:getBlockPermission:242]:   at org.spongepowered.common.event.tracking.TrackingUtil.processBlockCaptures(TrackingUtil.java:536)
[04:49:09] [Server thread/INFO] [STDERR/]: [me.vitoremnoel.blocklimiter.BlockLimiter:getBlockPermission:242]:   at org.spongepowered.common.event.tracking.phase.packet.PacketFunction.lambda$null$41(PacketFunction.java:848)
[04:49:09] [Server thread/INFO] [STDERR/]: [me.vitoremnoel.blocklimiter.BlockLimiter:getBlockPermission:242]:   at org.spongepowered.common.event.tracking.CapturedSupplier.ifPresentAndNotEmpty(CapturedSupplier.java:57)
[04:49:09] [Server thread/INFO] [STDERR/]: [me.vitoremnoel.blocklimiter.BlockLimiter:getBlockPermission:242]:   at org.spongepowered.common.event.tracking.phase.packet.PacketFunction.lambda$static$44(PacketFunction.java:846)
[04:49:09] [Server thread/INFO] [STDERR/]: [me.vitoremnoel.blocklimiter.BlockLimiter:getBlockPermission:242]:   at org.spongepowered.common.event.tracking.phase.packet.PacketPhase.unwind(PacketPhase.java:324)
[04:49:09] [Server thread/INFO] [STDERR/]: [me.vitoremnoel.blocklimiter.BlockLimiter:getBlockPermission:242]:   at org.spongepowered.common.event.tracking.CauseTracker.completePhase(CauseTracker.java:226)
[04:49:09] [Server thread/INFO] [STDERR/]: [me.vitoremnoel.blocklimiter.BlockLimiter:getBlockPermission:242]:   at org.spongepowered.common.event.tracking.CauseTracker.switchToPhase(CauseTracker.java:168)
[04:49:09] [Server thread/INFO] [STDERR/]: [me.vitoremnoel.blocklimiter.BlockLimiter:getBlockPermission:242]:   at org.spongepowered.common.network.PacketUtil.onProcessPacket(PacketUtil.java:156)
[04:49:09] [Server thread/INFO] [STDERR/]: [me.vitoremnoel.blocklimiter.BlockLimiter:getBlockPermission:242]:   at net.minecraft.network.PacketThreadUtil$1.redirect$onProcessPacket$zjj000(SourceFile:539)
[04:49:09] [Server thread/INFO] [STDERR/]: [me.vitoremnoel.blocklimiter.BlockLimiter:getBlockPermission:242]:   at net.minecraft.network.PacketThreadUtil$1.run(SourceFile:13)
[04:49:09] [Server thread/INFO] [STDERR/]: [me.vitoremnoel.blocklimiter.BlockLimiter:getBlockPermission:242]:   at java.util.concurrent.Executors$RunnableAdapter.call(Unknown Source)
[04:49:09] [Server thread/INFO] [STDERR/]: [me.vitoremnoel.blocklimiter.BlockLimiter:getBlockPermission:242]:   at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(Unknown Source)
[04:49:09] [Server thread/INFO] [STDERR/]: [me.vitoremnoel.blocklimiter.BlockLimiter:getBlockPermission:242]:   at net.minecraft.util.Util.func_181617_a(SourceFile:45)
[04:49:09] [Server thread/INFO] [STDERR/]: [me.vitoremnoel.blocklimiter.BlockLimiter:getBlockPermission:242]:   at org.spongepowered.common.SpongeImplHooks.onUtilRunTask(SpongeImplHooks.java:239)
[04:49:09] [Server thread/INFO] [STDERR/]: [me.vitoremnoel.blocklimiter.BlockLimiter:getBlockPermission:242]:   at net.minecraft.server.MinecraftServer.redirect$onRun$zhp000(MinecraftServer.java:3948)
[04:49:09] [Server thread/INFO] [STDERR/]: [me.vitoremnoel.blocklimiter.BlockLimiter:getBlockPermission:242]:   at net.minecraft.server.MinecraftServer.func_71190_q(MinecraftServer.java:668)
[04:49:09] [Server thread/INFO] [STDERR/]: [me.vitoremnoel.blocklimiter.BlockLimiter:getBlockPermission:242]:   at net.minecraft.server.dedicated.DedicatedServer.func_71190_q(DedicatedServer.java:387)
[04:49:09] [Server thread/INFO] [STDERR/]: [me.vitoremnoel.blocklimiter.BlockLimiter:getBlockPermission:242]:   at net.minecraft.server.MinecraftServer.func_71217_p(MinecraftServer.java:613)
[04:49:09] [Server thread/INFO] [STDERR/]: [me.vitoremnoel.blocklimiter.BlockLimiter:getBlockPermission:242]:   at net.minecraft.server.MinecraftServer.run(MinecraftServer.java:471)
[04:49:09] [Server thread/INFO] [STDERR/]: [me.vitoremnoel.blocklimiter.BlockLimiter:getBlockPermission:242]:   at java.lang.Thread.run(Unknown Source)
[04:49:09] [Server thread/INFO] [STDERR/]: [java.lang.Throwable:printStackTrace:-1]: Caused by: org.mariadb.jdbc.internal.util.dao.QueryException: Current position is before the first row
[04:49:09] [Server thread/INFO] [STDERR/]: [java.lang.Throwable:printStackTrace:-1]:    ... 34 more
```

Answer (score 2):

Utilize o `next` ou `first` antes de capturar o valor.

```
public String getBlockPermission(String blockstring){
    String permission = "";
    try{
        ResultSet res = connection.createStatement().executeQuery("select permission from limitedblocks where blockstring='" + blockstring + "';");

        res.first(); /* Move para primeira ocorrência */

        permission = res.getString("permission");
    }catch(Exception e){
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
    return permission;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Primeiro que o seu código está susceptível a injeção de SQL e não fecha o `connection`, o `res` ou o statement criado. Veja mais sobre isso [nessa pergunta](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/172909/132).

Corrigindo-se esses problemas, chegamos a isso:

```
private static final String SQL_BLOCK_PERMISSION =
        "SELECT permission FROM limitedblocks WHERE blockstring = ?";

public String getBlockPermission(String blockString) {
    try (PreparedStatement ps = connection.prepareStatement(SQL_BLOCK_PERMISSION)) {
        ps.setString(1, blockString);
        try (ResultSet res = ps.executeQuery()) {
            if (res.next()) return res.getString("permission");
            return "";
        }
    } catch (SQLException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
        throw new RuntimeException(e);
    }
}
```

Não sei como você cria o objeto `connection` e como você o gerencia, mas eu também suspeitaria que ele não está gerenciado adequadamente.

Outro detalhe é o tratamento de exceções. Capturar a exceção, lançar um `printStackTrace()` e seguir como se nada tivesse acontecido é uma má prática de programação. Entretanto, tendo apenas o código que você deu, não há material suficiente para sugerir-se coisa melhor.

Finalmente, observe a chamada ao método `next()` dentro do `if`. É ele que coloca o `ResultSet` na primeira posição do resultado, caso ela exista. Se não existir, não entramos no `if` e caímos no `return "";`. Pode ser que no caso de não existir, você prefira lançar uma exceção ao invés disso. Quando você trabalha com `ResultSet`s que contém múltiplos resultados, convém usar um `while` ao invés de um `if`.

Comment: Importante salientar que o recurso [try-with-resources](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/essential/exceptions/tryResourceClose.html) só está disponível a partir do Java 7.

Comment: Vlw mano, me ajudo muito, resolvi todos esses problemas.