# Simular Update do Banco de Dados com Select

Tags: java, mysql, sql, sql-select

Como eu poderia fazer um select na tabela abaixo (MySQL) para resolver o método (Java)?

```
re         data        is_folga
10     01/01/2017         0
10     02/01/2017         0 
10     03/01/2017         0
10     04/01/2017         0
10     05/01/2017         1
10     06/01/2017         1
10     07/01/2017         0
10     08/01/2017         0 
10     09/01/2017         0
10     10/01/2017         0
10     11/01/2017         1
10     12/01/2017         1
20     01/01/2017         0
20     02/01/2017         0 
20     03/01/2017         0
20     04/01/2017         1
20     05/01/2017         1
20     06/01/2017         0
20     07/01/2017         0
20     08/01/2017         0 
20     09/01/2017         0
20     10/01/2017         1
20     11/01/2017         1
20     12/01/2017         0
```

```java
public boolean trocaFolga(int re_A, int re_B, String data_A, String data_B){
boolean ok = false;

....
//fazer um select que verifique quantos dias o re_A trabalharia sem folga se a troca for feita 
//e o mesmo select para o re_B

  if(retorno do select < 7){
       ok=true;
    }
....

return ok;
}
```

Exemplo:

> Sou o re 10 quero trocar o dia 04/01 pelo dia 04/01 do re 20. Se for
>   feita a troca, eu ou o re 20 vamos ficar mais de 7 dias sem folgar?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Primeiro, considerei que a estrutura da tabela é essa:

```sql
CREATE TABLE tabela (
  re INTEGER NOT NULL,
  data DATE NOT NULL,
  is_folga BIT NOT NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY(re, data)
);
```

Em especial, observe que `data` é do tipo `DATE`, e não `VARCHAR`. Isso é importante.

Acho que a solução seria isso:

```
private static final String URL = "jdbc:mysql://localhost/folgas";
private static final String USERNAME = "root";
private static final String SENHA = "root";

private static final String SQL_FOLGAS = ""
        "SELECT a.is_folga "
        "FROM tabela a "
        "WHERE a.re = ? "
        "AND a.data >= DATE_ADD(?, INTERVAL 6 DAY) "
        "AND a.data <= DATE_SUB(?, INTERVAL 6 DAY) "
        "ORDER BY a.data";

private Connection conectar() throws SQLException {
    return DriverManager.getConnection(URL, USERNAME, SENHA);
}

private static enum ResultadoFolga {
    NAO_PODE_TROCAR,
    VAI_FOLGAR,
    NAO_VAI_FOLGAR,
}

private ResultadoFolga trocaFolgas(Connection c, int re, LocalDate data)
        throws SQLException
{
    try (PreparedStatement ps = c.prepareStatement(SQL_FOLGAS)) {
        ps.setInt(1, re);
        ps.setDate(2, java.sql.Date.valueOf(data));
        ps.setDate(3, java.sql.Date.valueOf(data));
        int consecutivos = 0;
        int contador = 0;
        boolean folgandoNoDia = false;
        try (ResultSet rs = ps.executeQuery()) {
            while (rs.next()) {
                boolean folga = rs.getInt(1) == 1;
                if (folga != (contador == 6)) {
                    consecutivos++;
                } else {
                    consecutivos = 0;
                }
                if (consecutivos == 7) return ResultadoFolga.NAO_PODE_TROCAR;
                if (contador == 6 && folga) folgandoNoDia = true;
                contador++;
            }
            return folgandoNoDia
                    ? ResultadoFolga.NAO_VAI_FOLGAR
                    : ResultadoFolga.VAI_FOLGAR;
        }
    }
}

public boolean trocaFolgas(int reA, int reB, LocalDate dataA, LocalDate dataB)
        throws SQLException
{
    try (Connection c = conectar()) {
        ResultadoFolga a = trocaFolgas(c, reA, dataA);
        ResultadoFolga b = trocaFolgas(c, reB, dataB);
        return a != ResultadoFolga.NAO_PODE_TROCAR
                && b != ResultadoFolga.NAO_PODE_TROCAR
                && a != b;
    }
}
```

Se entendi direito a sua pergunta, ninguém pode ficar 7 ou mais dias consecutivos sem descanso. Ou seja, não podem haver 7 zeros seguidos caso a troca seja efetuada.

A ideia então é verificar o funcionário ao fazer o `SELECT` de 13 campos `is_folga` de dias consecutivos, indo de 6 dias antes da folga até 6 dias depois, e trocando o valor do dia desejado, e ver se ocorre o caso de haver 7 zeros consecutivos. É suficiente verificar-se 6 para trás e 6 para frente, por que se o primeiro dia dos 7 dias sem folgar for a data desejada, o último seria 6 dias depois. Da mesma forma, se o último dia dos 7 dias sem folgar for essa data, então o primeiro seria 6 dias antes.

Não é necessário verificar-se mais além porque se houver uma sequência de 7 ou mais dias sem folga antes ou depois desse período, ela já estará longe o suficiente para que a troca na data desejada não possa alterar essa situação. Se você garantir que o banco de dados nunca conterá 7 zeros consecutivos, esse procedimento vai garantir que a troca não incluirá isso. Mas se você não puder garantir isso, o procedimento acima também não poderá garanti-lo.

Esse trecho requer melhores explicações:

```
        int consecutivos = 0;
        int contador = 0;
        boolean folgandoNoDia = false;
        try (ResultSet rs = ps.executeQuery()) {
            while (rs.next()) {
                boolean folga = rs.getInt(1) == 1;
                if (folga != (contador == 6)) {
                    consecutivos++;
                } else {
                    consecutivos = 0;
                }
                if (consecutivos == 7) return ResultadoFolga.NAO_PODE_TROCAR;
                if (contador == 6 && folga) folgandoNoDia = true;
                contador++;
            }
            return folgandoNoDia
                    ? ResultadoFolga.NAO_VAI_FOLGAR
                    : ResultadoFolga.VAI_FOLGAR;
        }
```

Primeiro, há 3 resultados possíveis determinados pelo enum `ResultadoFolga`. Isso ocorre porque os resultados são três:

- Não pode fazer a troca;
- Pode fazer a troca e o re que iria folgar não vai mais e;
- Pode fazer a troca e o re que não iria folgar, agora irá.

O que ocorre aqui é que temos o `contador` que contará os registros lidos, indo de 0 no primeiro registro até 12 no último. O `contador == 6` só será verdadeiro no sétimo dia (lembre-se que o primeiro é 0, logo o sétimo será 6). Esse dia será justamente o dia desejado para a realização da troca.

O `boolean folga = rs.getInt(1) == 1;` faz com que a variável `folga` receba `true` se o valor lido for igual a 1 e `false` se não for.

Nos dias que não são o da realização da troca, `contador != 6` é avaliado como `true`, e então `folga == true` é avaliado apenas como `folga` (se `folga` for `false`, isso resultará em `false`, e se `folga` for `true`, isso resultará em `true`). Já no dia da realização da troca ,`contador != 6` é avaliado como `false`, e então `folga == false` será equivalente a `!folga`, ou seja, será a inversão do valor lido do banco de dados. Ou seja, isso daí avalia se o dia é de folga de acordo com o banco de dados, mas invertendo o valor lido no dia desejado. Logo, isso determina se após feita a inversão, trata-se de um dia de folga.

Se após feita a inversão desejada, se isso for um dia de folga, `consecutivos` vai para zero, afinal de contas não é mais um dia de trabalho consecutivo. Caso contrário, conta como mais um dia consecutivo de trabalho, e portanto `consecutivos++`. Quando o valor de `consecutivos` chegar a 7, temos então 7 dias consecutivos de trabalho (se feita a troca), e portanto retorna-se `ResultadoFolga.NAO_PODE_TROCAR`, indicando que a troca não pode ser feita.

Se após percorrer todos esses 13 dias e não ocorrer de `consecutivos` chegar a 7 em momento nenhum, então a troca não vai introduzir uma sequência de 7 dias consecutivos sem folga. Mas ainda precisamos saber se o re trabalhará ou não nesse dia. É aí que entra a variável `folgandoNoDia`. Ela é inicializada como `false`. Se no dia em que `contador == 6`, ela for verdadeira, então é porque de acordo com o banco de dados, esse seria um dia de folga, e então `folgandoNoDia` passa a ser `true`.

No fim, após os 13 dias, supondo que não tenha achado 7 dias consecutivos de trabalho e tenha caído no `ResultadoFolga.NAO_PODE_TROCAR`, retornamos `ResultadoFolga.VAI_FOLGAR` ou `ResultadoFolga.NAO_VAI_FOLGAR` dependendo **do inverso** do valor se o re for ou não folgar no dia. Se ele folgaria, passará a não mais folgar com a troca. Se ele não folgaria, então vai folgar agora.

Olhando então para o caso de dois funcionários, fazemos esse processo para ambos separadamente (e chamamos os resultados de `a` e `b`) e depois verificamos se a troca é válida da seguinte forma: Se qualquer um deles não puder trocar, então a troca não é possível e retorna-se `false`. Se ambos puderem trocar, então é necessário que um vá folgar e o outro não (caso contrário não é uma troca), e isso é verdadeiro quando temos `a != b`.

Para consultar o banco de dados, utilizo o [*try-with-resources*](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/172909/132) para gerenciar o `Connection`, o `PreparedStatement` e o `ResultSet`. Há apenas um `Connection`, mas são executadas duas consultas no banco de dados (uma para cada re) e com isso temos dois `PreparedStatement`s e dois `ResultSet`s. Os campos `URL`, `USERNAME` e `SENHA` são os parâmetros de conexão com o banco de dados. O tratamento de qualquer `SQLException` resultante (isso significa erro ao conectar ou consultar o banco de dados) fica por sua conta.

Para datas, ao invés de usar strings, estou usando um tipo nativo e especializado que serve para representar datas, o [`LocalDate`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/9/docs/api/java/time/LocalDate.html). Faço isso porque [usar strings para representar datas é uma má prática de programação](http://desciclopedia.org/wiki/Gambi_Design_Patterns#Programa.C3.A7.C3.A3o_Orientada_a_Strings). Para saber mais sobre o `LocalDate`, veja [essa pergunta](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/177129/132).

É possível fazer-se tudo isso direto na SQL, mas a SQL resultante disso seria bastante complicada, provavelmente teria que estar amarrada ao MySQL/MariaDB (ou seja, não seria portável para outros bancos de dados) e isso reduziria pouca coisa da complexidade do lado do Java.

Se a tabela do banco de dados ter alguma lacuna em alguma data (por exemplo, para o re de número 123, ela pula do dia 14 para o dia 16), ela vai dar errado. É importante que você não deixe que o banco de dados possa ter lacunas desse tipo. Em especial, o pior caso é quando a data consultada não está no banco de dados. O código não verifica esses casos. Não é muito difícil acrescentar essas verificações, mas isso deixará o código um pouco mais complicado (basicamente, certificar-se de que há exatamente 13 linhas no resultado e decidir o que fazer se não houver).

Comment: Victor, primeiramente muito obrigado pela ajuda! Estou tentando executar o método conforme acima, mas está sempre me retornando como "falso", mesmo tendo menos de 7 dias sem folga. Tentei simular o comando sql direto no MySQL,mas ele não retorna valores. Você conseguiria simular no sqlfiddle?