# PSQLException: Nenhum resultado foi retornado pela consulta

Tags: java, postgresql

Não consigo identificar o erro que está retornando ao tentar inserir dados ao BD.

Acredito que o erro esteja na função inserir.

O erro retornado é:

> Exception in thread "main" org.postgresql.util.PSQLException: Nenhum resultado foi retornado pela consulta.

```
public class ConnectionFactory {

    public static Connection  getConnectionFactory() throws SQLException, ClassNotFoundException{

           String url = "jdbc:postgresql://localhost:5432/topografiaJava";  
           String usuario = "postgres";  
           String senha = "Maker@1";  
           Class.forName("org.postgresql.Driver");  
           Connection con;  
           con = DriverManager.getConnection(url, usuario, senha);  
           System.out.println("Conexão realizada com sucesso.");  
           Statement st1;  
           st1 = con.createStatement();
           return con;

    }
}
```

```
public class PessoaDAO {

private Connection conn;

private Pessoa resultSet2Model(ResultSet rs) throws SQLException, ClassNotFoundException {

     Pessoa p;
     p = new Pessoa(rs.getInt("id"),
             rs.getString("nome"),
             rs.getString("matricula"),
             rs.getString("setor"),
             rs.getString("login"),
             rs.getString("senha"),
             rs.getString("email"));
        return p; 
    }

    public Pessoa inserir(Pessoa p) throws SQLException, ClassNotFoundException {
        PreparedStatement st1=null;
        this.conn = new ConnectionFactory().getConnectionFactory();
        st1 = conn.prepareStatement("insert into pessoa (id, nome, matricula, setor, login, senha, email) values(?,?,?,?,?,?,?)");
         st1.setInt(1,p.getID);
         st1.setString(2, p.getNome());
         st1.setString (3, p.getMatricula());
         st1.setString(4, p.getSetor());
         st1.setString(5, p.getLogin());
         st1.setString(6,p.getSenha());
         st1.setString(7, p.getEmail());
         ResultSet rs1 = st1.executeQuery();
         rs1.next();
         st1.execute();
         return p;
    }
}
```

Comment: Recomendo que você leia este tópico: [**Como funciona o try-with-resources?**](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/172909/como-funciona-o-try-with-resources)

Comment: As duas linhas antes de `return p;` são completamente descartáveis neste código, e `insert` não retorna dado, então, `ResultSet` é desnecessário para esse tipo de query.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Note esta linha de código

```
rs1.next();
```

O método [**`next`**](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/sql/ResultSet.html#next%28%29) de `ResultSet` serve para mover o "cursor" para a próxima linha retornada pelo banco. Como um `insert` não retorna nada, ele está estourando este erro.

Vamos aos problemas do seu código:

No bloco abaixo você tenta executar a *query* duas vezes seguidas

```
ResultSet rs1 = st1.executeQuery(); // Aqui
rs1.next();
st1.execute(); // Aqui
```

O método [**`executeQuery`**](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/sql/PreparedStatement.html#executeQuery()) serve para executar uma *query* no banco e tenta retornar um objeto do tipo `ResultSet`.

Já o método [**`execute`**](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/9/docs/api/java/sql/PreparedStatement.html) serve para executar qualquer *statement* e retorna `true` se o resultado for um objeto do tipo `ResultSet` ou `false` se o primeiro resultado for uma contagem de *update* (quantas linhas foram alteradas) ou se não houve resultado.

Novamente. **Um `insert` não retorna algo**, então você pode simplesmente descartar as duas primeiras linhas.

Reorganize aquele bloco de código para ficar apenas

```
st1.execute();
```

Comment: O método `execute()` retorna true caso o resultado da instrução seja um ResultSet; e retorna false caso o resultado da instrução seja um número de linhas alteradas/inseridas/deletadas ou se não tem resultado.

Comment: @mutlei é, acabei de ver na documentação da v9