# Teste Unitário - Como testar um try-with-resources?

Tags: java, testes-de-unidade, try-with-resources

Gostaria de saber a melhor forma - ou a forma padrão - de Testar um [try-with-resources](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/172909/como-funciona-o-try-with-resources); com Casos de Teste para cada uma das Exceptions que podem ser lançadas (simulando o lançamento de cada uma dessas Exceptions para ver como o código testado se comportará), e, com um Caso de Teste para quando tudo corre bem e nenhuma Exception é lançada.

Exemplo de método com try-with-resources para ser testado:

```
public static void escreverNoFinalDoArquivo(String str, File arquivo) {
    try (BufferedWriter writer = new BufferedWriter(new FileWriter(arquivo, true))) {
        writer.write(str);
    } catch (NullPointerException | IOException e) {
        mostrarErroNaGUI(e);
    }
}
```

No código acima, gostaria de testar um Caso onde o FileWriter lance uma Exception ao ser construído, e outro caso onde a chamada a `write(str)` lance uma Exception, e ainda mais um caso onde nenhuma Exception seja lançada.

- Seria uma boa ideia *"mockar"* o FileWriter? Como isso poderia ser feito? Como posso lançar uma Exception ao construí-lo para testar este caso?
- E quanto a *"mockar"* o BufferedWriter para fazer o método `write(str)` lançar uma Exception?

Nos testes eu quero verificar se uma Exception foi lançada (forçando-a a ser lançada) e se o método `mostrarErroNaGUI(e)` recebeu esta Exception.
Também quero testar o caso em que nenhuma Exception é lançada verificando se o método `mostrarErroNaGUI(e)` **não** foi chamado.

**A ideia geral é simular em Testes todas as Exceptions que podem ser lançadas num  try-with-resources**, mas como posso **forçar nos Testes que essas Exceptions sejam lançadas** para depois fazer asserções que verificam se o programa lidou com elas como o esperado?

Então, o intuito é ter Testes que garantam que o trecho de código lidará como o esperado independentemente da Exception que ocorra dentro dele.

Sua resposta pode modificar esse código para torná-lo mais testável, não tem problema, mas não pode eliminar o *try-with-resources* porque simular Exceptions dentro dele para fazer asserções depois é foco desta pergunta.

<sub>***Obs.:** Estou usando JUnit5 e Mockito nos meus testes.*</sub>

Comment: O que você pretende testar? Continua sendo apenas um trecho de código que para o teste é uma blackbox.

Comment: @JeffersonQuesado editei para tentar deixar mais claro, veja se consegui expressar suficientemente bem minha pergunta agora :)