# Ler linhas de um TXT para ArrayList

Tags: java, arraylist, txt

Preciso ler um log gravado em um arquivo TXT que contém coordenadas geográficas na seguinte forma:

```
-54.123440,-21.123456
-54.123425,-21.123467
-54.123435,-21.123480
-54.123444,-21.123444
-54.123452,-21.123100
```

Cada linha possui a longitude e a latitude de cada coordenada (ponto do gráfico), separada por vírgula (,).

Vou utilizar essas coordenas para gerar um gráfico em que cada linha é um ponto, então preciso ter acesso à latitude e longitude de cada ponto. Gostaria de saber como armazenar a latitude e longitude de cada ponto em um `ArrayList`, e se essa é realmente a melhor forma melhor de fazer isso para eu ter acesso a esses dados para gerar o gráfico depois.

Eu consigo ler o arquivo e imprimir linha por linha, através da seguinte classe:

```
public class Leitura {

    public void leTXT() {
        Scanner ler = new Scanner(System.in);
        try {
            FileReader arq = new FileReader("c:/dados/log.txt");
            BufferedReader lerArq = new BufferedReader(arq);
            String str = lerArq.readLine();
            while (str != null) {
                System.out.printf("%s\n", str);
                str = lerArq.readLine();
            }
            arq.close();
        } catch (IOException e) {
            System.err.printf("Erro na abertura do arquivo!");
        }

        System.out.println();
    }
}
```

Comment: Acho que depende do componente de gráfico que você vai usar, não?

Comment: "*Cada linha possui a latitude e a longitude de cada coordenada (ponto do gráfico), separada por vírgula (,).*" - No seu caso, na verdade a longitude é o primeiro número e a latitude é o segundo.

Comment: Exatamente, editei a pergunta consertando o erro.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

No seu arquivo, cada linha corresponde a uma **coordenada** e cada **coordenada** tem uma **longitude** (entre -180 e +180) e uma **latitude** (entre -90 e +90). O conteúdo do arquivo é uma **lista de coordenadas**.

Observe que o conceito central que temos aqui é uma coordenada. Como Java é uma linguagem orientada a objetos, esses conceitos mapeiam para objetos que são modelados em classes. Assim sendo, `Coordenada` é uma classe:

```
public final class Coordenada {
    private final double longitude;
    private final double latitude;

    public Coordenada(double longitude, double latitude) {
        if (longitude < -180.0 || longitude > 180.0) {
            throw new IllegalArgumentException("Longitude inválida.");
        }
        if (latitude < -90.0 || latitude > 90.0) {
            throw new IllegalArgumentException("Latitude inválida.");
        }
        this.longitude = longitude;
        this.latitude = latitude;
    }

    public double getLongitude() {
        return longitude;
    }

    public double getLatitude() {
        return longitude;
    }

    public static Coordenada parse(String linha) {
        String[] partes = linha.split(",");
        if (partes.length != 2) throw new IllegalArgumentException("Linha malformada.");

        double a, b;
        try {
            a = Double.parseDouble(partes[0]);
            b = Double.parseDouble(partes[1]);
        } catch (NumberFormatException e) {
            throw new IllegalArgumentException("Linha malformada.");
        }
        return new Coordenada(a, b);
    }
}
```

Observe esse método `parse(String)`. Ele é o responsável por interpretar uma linha e converter em uma coordenada.

Você pode usar o [método `Files.readAllLines(Path, Charset)`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/10/docs/api/java/nio/file/Files.html#readAllLines(java.nio.file.Path,java.nio.charset.Charset)) para obter todas as linhas do arquivo facilmente.

Com isso, podemos fazer assim:

```
import java.io.IOException;
import java.nio.charset.StandardCharsets;
import java.nio.file.Files;
import java.nio.file.Path;
import java.nio.file.Paths;
import java.util.stream.Collectors;
import java.util.stream.Stream;

public class Leitura {

    public List<Coordenada> lerCoordenadas() throws IOException {
        return lerCoordenadas(Paths.get("c:/dados/log.txt"));
    }

    public List<Coordenada> lerCoordenadas(Path arquivo) throws IOException {
        return Files.readAllLines(arquivo, StandardCharsets.UTF_8)
               .stream()
               .map(Coordenada::parse)
               .collect(Collectors.toList());
    }
}
```

Nesse caso, você não precisa se preocupar em abrir, ler e fechar o arquivo manualmente porque o `Files.readAllLines` já faz isso. Mas se for fazer manualmente, lembre-se de usar o [*try-with-resources*](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/172909/132).

Comment: Entendi, então para eu ter vetor de coordenadas eu utilizo um arraylist do tipo coordenada, certo?

Comment: @BrunoPadilha Você usa o `List<Coordenada>` que o método `lerCoordenadas()` fornece (talvez com um laço `for` ou coisa parecida). Embora sejam muito similar, `List<Coordenada>` e `ArrayList<Coordenada>` são conceitos diferentes. Motivos para se invocar o construtor de `ArrayList` diretamente existem aos montes, mas para se utilizar uma variável do tipo `ArrayList<...>` ao invés de `List<...>` não existe quase que nenhum.

Comment: Entendido, agora ficou claro a sua implementação.

Comment: Uma última dúvida, como faço para acessar os valores em outra classe? Por exemplo para plotar uma linha em meu gráfico eu utilizo `linha.drawLine(latitudeP1, longitudeP1, latitudeP1, longitudeP1)`. Não consegui acessar instanciando um objeto `Coordenada c = new Coordenada;` e posteriormente `linha.drawLine(c.getLatitude, c.getLongitude, c2.getLatitude, c2.getLongitude)`.

Comment: @BrunoPadilha Não sei se entendi o que você está perguntando agora. Olhando o código do seu comentário, faltou os parênteses após o `getLatitude` e o `getLongitude` e também os parâmetros do construtor de `Coordenada`. No entanto, se for algo mais complicado que isso, sugiro criar uma nova pergunta colocando lá o código completo e um link para essa pergunta aqui, e então me chame para dar uma olhada.

Comment: Criei uma nova pergunta para tentar explicar minha dúvida.

Answer (score 0):

Sem saber qual a biblioteca gráfica que você vai utilizar, aqui vai uma solução genérica, que utiliza um `Map` para armazenar o conjunto de latitude / longitude.

```
public HashMap<Double, Double> getCoordenadas() throws IOException{     

    HashMap<Double, Double> retorno = new HashMap<>();

    List<String> linhas = Files.readAllLines(Paths.get("C:\\dados\\log.txt"));

    for (String linha : linhas) {
        String[] coordenadas = linha.split(",");
        retorno.put(Double.valueOf(coordenadas[0]), Double.valueOf(coordenadas[1]));
    }

    return retorno;
}
```

Note que utilizei um método diferente para ler o arquivo, a classe `Files`.

Se o seu projeto utiliza Java 8, recomendo utiliza-la, pois como pode observar, diminui bastante a complexidade do código.

Comment: Se houver dois ou mais pontos com a mesma longitude, mas com latitudes diferentes, o que acontece?

Comment: O gráfico irá plotar todos os pontos, caso sejam pontos iguais o desenho será sobreposto.