# Acessar dados de uma classe

Tags: java, orientação-a-objetos

Estou desenvolvendo um gerador de um gráfico para monitorar a navegação de um robô. Os dados das coordenas pelas quais o robô passa são armazenados em um arquivos txt, sendo que cada linha possui uma latitude e uma longitude, assim como descrito [nessa pergunta](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/300087/ler-linhas-de-um-txt-para-arraylist). Estou utilizando o exemplo do @VictorStafusa

Porém estou com dificuldades de acessar os dados da classe `Coordenada`.

Para plotar uma linha em meu gráfico, eu utilizo a latitude e longitude de duas coordenadas. Sendo assim  preciso que cada objeto possua as coordenadas de uma linha do txt. O código que utilizo para plotar uma linha é `linha.drawLine(longitudeCoordenada1, latitudeCoordenada1, longitudeCoordenada2, latitudeCoordenada2)`. Pensei então em instanciar objetos da seguinte forma `Coordenada c = new Coordenada()`, para utilizar assim: `linha.drawLine(c.getLongitude(), c.getLatitude(), c2.getLongitude(), c2.getLatitude())`. Porém não obtive sucesso.

Tenho pouca experiência em orientação a objetos, então poderia me informar como devo fazer para que cada objeto possua a coordenada de uma linha do txt e como acessar essas coordenadas?

Para testar estou usando a seguinte classe principal.

```
public class Main {

    public static void main(String[] args) throws IOException {
        double longitude1 = 0;
        double latitude1 = 0;
        double longitude2 = 0;
        double latitude2 = 0;

        Leitura l = new Leitura();
        l.lerCoordenadas();

        Coordenada c1 = new Coordenada(longitude1, latitude1);
        Coordenada c2 = new Coordenada(longitude2, latitude2);

        System.out.println(c1.getLongitude());
        System.out.println(c1.getLatitude());
        System.out.println(c2.getLongitude());
        System.out.println(c2.getLatitude());
    }
}
```

Comment: Veja bem. 
Ao fazer Coordenada c = new Coordenada() você está instanciando um objeto porém sem definir os valores dele, logo quando você acessa ele com c.getLongitude() o valor de longitude é null.

Comment: @LucasBrogni Nesse caso nem isso. É erro de compilação mesmo porque não há construtor sem parâmetros nessa classe.

Comment: "*eu utilizo a latitude e longitude de duas coordenadas*" - na verdade é o contrário. A primeira coordenada da sua lista é `-54.123440,-21.123456` e as demais coordenadas são similares e bem próximas dali. Interpretando como latitude-longitude, é um ponto no meio do Oceano Atlântico não muito longe da Antártida, não deve ser um local de seu interesse. Interpretando como longitude-latitude, é um local há uns 60km de Campo Grande - MS, que deve ser o que te interessa.

Comment: Obrigado por apontar o erro, editei a pergunta corrigindo-a.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use os parâmetros no construtor:

```
double longitude1 = ...;
double latitude1 = ...;
double longitude2 = ...;
double latitude2 = ...;

Coordenada c1 = new Coordenada(longitude1, latitude1);
Coordenada c2 = new Coordenada(longitude2, latitude2);

linha.drawLine(c1.getLongitude(), c1.getLatitude(), c2.getLongitude(), c2.getLatitude());
```

**Editado:**

Vez que você editou a pergunta, o problema é que você está lendo os valores do arquivo e não está fazendo nada com eles. Observe que o método `lerCoordenadas()` retorna uma `List<Coordenada>`. No entanto, você está ignorando totalmente a lista produzida e em vez disso, você cria duas coordenadas de valor zero totalmente independentes da lista que você leu do arquivo e então mostra essas coordenadas de valor zero.

Tente fazer isso:

```
import java.io.IOException;
import java.nio.charset.StandardCharsets;
import java.nio.file.Files;
import java.nio.file.Path;
import java.nio.file.Paths;
import java.util.stream.Collectors;
import java.util.stream.Stream;
import java.util.List;

public class Main {

    private static List<Coordenada> lerCoordenadas() throws IOException {
        return lerCoordenadas(Paths.get("c:/dados/log.txt"));
    }

    private static List<Coordenada> lerCoordenadas(Path arquivo) throws IOException {
        return Files.readAllLines(arquivo, StandardCharsets.UTF_8)
               .stream()
               .map(Coordenada::parse)
               .collect(Collectors.toList());
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) throws IOException {
        List<Coordenada> coordenadas = lerCoordenadas();

        for (Coordenada c : coordenadas) {    
            System.out.println(c.getLongitude());
            System.out.println(c.getLatitude());
        }
    }
}
```

A classe `Coordenada` é a mesma da [minha resposta à sua pergunta anterior](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/a/300104/132). A classe `Leitura` da pergunta anterior pode ser descartada, pois essa classe `Main` aí já absorveu o conteúdo dela.

Para desenhar um polígono com essas coordenadas, você faria algo mais ou menos assim:

```
public void desenhar(List<Coordenada> coordenadas) {
    Coordenada anterior = null;
    for (Coordenada c : coordenadas) {
        if (anterior != null) {
            linha.drawLine(anterior.getLongitude(), anterior.getLatitude(), c.getLongitude(), c.getLatitude());
        }
        anterior = c;
    }
    Coordenada primeira = coordenadas.get(0);
    linha.drawLine(anterior.getLongitude(), anterior.getLatitude(), primeira.getLongitude(), primeira.getLatitude());
}
```

É claro que para que isso funcione, é necessário saber o que é exatamente esse objeto `linha`.

Comment: editei a pergunta com o `main` que estou utilizando, mesmo assim ainda não consegui usar os valores do txt

Comment: @BrunoPadilha Resposta editada.

Comment: Agora funcionou corretamente, obrigado.