# While ResultSet.next() retornando só um resultado

Tags: java, mysql, jdbc, resultset

Estou com um problema, quando coloco o `ResultSet.next()` no `while` e pego a informação da coluna da Database me retorna somente um resultado.

Tabela 'Pessoas':

```
Pessoas:      Idade:
Marcos        22
Marcos        24
Marcos        25
Roberto       26
Roberto       21
```

Código:

```
private static String pegarTodasAsIdades(String pessoas) {
        query = "SELECT Idade FROM Pessoas WHERE Pessoas=?";
        try {
            ps = conn.prepareStatement(query);
            ps.setString(1, pessoas);
            rs = ps.executeQuery();
            while (rs.next()) {
                String idades = rs.getString("Idade");
                return idades+"\t";
            }
        } catch (SQLException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
        return "";
    }
```

Porém o código acima só me retorna a idade '19' (primeira da coluna)

Obs:

```
conn = Connection
ps = PreparedStatement
rs = ResultSet
```

Comment: Ora, se você tem um `return` dentro do `while`, como você acha que ele retornaria mais de um resultado?

Comment: Leitura recomendada: https://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/172909/132

Comment: Modifiquei, o post, Victor Stafusa, não tem como retornar dentro do while? Com a função sendo String?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Há um `return` dentro do seu `while`. Quando o `return` é encontrado, o método termina imediatamente. Assim sendo, ao ler o primeiro resultado, o método termina sem que os demais resultados sejam processados.

Supondo que você esteja gerenciando as conexões corretamente com o `conn` (acho que essa suposição é falsa, mas isso é assunto para outra pergunta), o seu código deveria ser assim:

```
private static final String IDADES_SQL =
        "SELECT Idade FROM Pessoas WHERE Pessoas = ?";

private static String pegarTodasAsIdades(String pessoas) {
    try (PreparedStatement ps = conn.prepareStatement(IDADES_SQL)) {
        ps.setString(1, pessoas);
        try (ResultSet rs = ps.executeQuery()) {
            StringBuilder idades = new StringBuilder();
            while (rs.next()) {
                idades.append(rs.getString("Idade")).append("\t");
            }
            return idades.toString();
        }
    } catch (SQLException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
        throw new RuntimException(e);
    }
}
```

Não deixe que o `PreparedStatement`, o `ResultSet` e o `Connection` sejam campos do seu DAO, a menos que você saiba muito, mas muito bem o que esteja fazendo. E lembre-se de utilizar sempre o [*try-with-resources*](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/172909/132).

Answer (score 1):

Há um return no meio do while... Ele que está fazendo o while parar.
Segue uma solução:

```
private static String pegarTodasAsIdades(String pessoas) {
    query = "SELECT Idade FROM Pessoas WHERE Pessoas=?";
    try {
        ps = conn.prepareStatement(query);
        ps.setString(1, pessoas);
        rs = ps.executeQuery();
        String idades = "";
        while (rs.next()) {
            idades += rs.getString("Idade") + "\t";
        }
        return idades;
    } catch (SQLException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
    return "";
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Se está vindo um resultado só e você não consegue incrementar idades basta trocar o while(){} pelo do-while e garantir que o processo execute ao menos uma vez:

```
private static String pegarTodasAsIdades(String pessoas) {
    query = "SELECT Idade FROM Pessoas WHERE Pessoas=?";
    try {
        ps = conn.prepareStatement(query);
        ps.setString(1, pessoas);
        rs = ps.executeQuery();
        do  {
            String idades = rs.getString("Idade");
            idades += rs.getString("Idade") + "\t";
        }while(rs.next());
        return idades;

    } catch (SQLException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }

}
```