# MySQL imprimindo múltiplas vezes

Tags: java, mysql, sql, jdbc

Estou com um problema para imprimir os dados do MySQL no Eclipse. Quando coloco para imprimir a lista dos dados cadastrados ele está imprimindo 3 vezes cada informação.

Eu sei onde está o problema, mas não consigo enxergar a solução. Meu banco de dados tem um *schema* e duas tabelas (`cliente` e `endereco`). O que acontece é que quando entro com as informações de 3 pessoas, por exemplo, o Eclipse imprime 3 vezes cada informação pois o `rs.next()` está pegando das duas tabelas.

Vejam:

```
public void listarClientes() {

   String sql = "SELECT * FROM locadora.cliente, locadora.endereco";

   try {

      PreparedStatement ps = jdbc.getConexao().prepareStatement(sql); ResultSet rs = ps.executeQuery();

      while (rs.next()) {

         System.out.println("Nome: " + rs.getString("nome") + " - Código: " + rs.getString("codigo") + " - Bom pagador: " + rs.getBoolean("seBomPagador") + " - Telefone: " + rs.getString("telefone"));

         System.out.println("Tipo de endereço: " + rs.getString("tipo_endereco") + " - Logradouro: " + rs.getString("logradouro") + " - Bairro: " + rs.getString("bairro") + " - Cidade: " + rs.getString("cidade") + " - UF: " + rs.getString("uf") + " - Cep: " + rs.getString("cep"));

         System.out.println(); 
      }

   System.out.println(); rs.close();

   } catch (Exception e) { // TODO: handle exception

   System.out.println("Erro na listagem dos clientes!"); 

   }
```

Comment: Seu problema deve ser no sql. Procure fazer mais ou menos dessa forma: `SELECT * FROM cliente as c INNER JOIN endereco as e ON (c.idEndereco = e.id)`. Como as duas tabelas devem possuir um relacionamento, a tabela `cliente` deve conter um id da tabela `endereco`, dessa forma você consegue trazer os dados do endereço do seu respectivo cliente.

Comment: Obrigado Thiago, vou ver se consigo!

Comment: Leitura recomendada: https://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/172909/132

Answer (score 2):

Melhore sua query vinculando as tabelas e agrupando valores com group by

```
SELECT nome, endereco FROM locadora.cliente, locadora.endereco 
where locadora.cliente.cli_id = locadora.endereco.cli_id
group by nome, endereco
```

a normalização não me parece boa, o exemplo acima é apenas uma referencia ao codigo que você postou.

Answer (score 0):

Voce pode solucionar esse problema com o comando DISTINCT do Mysql após o SELECT.

```
SELECT DISTINCT * FROM locadora.cliente, locadora.endereco
```

Porem eu recomendo que você melhore sua consulta.

```
SELECT cliente.nome, cliente.codigo, cliente.seBomPagador, cliente.telefone, 
       endereco.tipo_endereco, endereco.logradouro, endereco.bairro, endereco.cidade, endereco.uf, endereco.cep 
FROM cliente, endereco
 WHERE cliente.id = endereco.cliente_id;
```

Após o WHERE você relaciona o a chave primária de uma tabela com a chave estrangeira de outra para evitar que a consulta retorne com informações repetidas.

Answer (score 0):

Obrigado a todos pela ajuda! Foi resolvido dessa forma no eclipse:

select
ENDE.tipo_endereco,logradouro,bairro,cidade,uf,cep,
CLI.nome,codigo,seBomPagador,telefone
from endereco as ENDE
inner join cliente as CLI
on (CLI.id = ENDE.cliente_id);