# Método close() nos blocos try e catch é necessário?

Tags: java, try-with-resources

Estou estudando Java com banco de dados e depois de ver um pouco mais sobre esse método `close()` e esse bloco protegido, fiquei um pouco confuso, pois em alguns códigos e artigos eu vejo que não foi usado o `close()` nos blocos *try/catch* pois eles são "**auto-close**" ou algo do tipo.

Sei também que é muito importante usar esse método para poupar recursos de execução. No final das contas, se eu usar o `close()` dentro do bloco estarei cometendo ambiguidade de funcionalidades já que o bloco se encarrega de fechar a conexão? Ou estarei fazendo a coisa certa?

Comment: [Como funciona o try-with-resources?](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/172909/como-funciona-o-try-with-resources)

Comment: Alguma das respostas resolveu sua dúvida? Acha que pode aceitar uma delas? Veja o [tour] como fazer isso, se ainda não o fez. Você ajudaria a comunidade identificando qual foi a melhor solução para você. Pode aceitar apenas uma delas. Mas pode votar em qualquer pergunta ou resposta que achar útil no site todo.

Answer (score 5):

Primeiro precisa saber se todo o código está correto. Quando se trata desse tipo de coisa vejo muita coisa errada.

Segundo, precisa ver o contexto, porque pode ser que não queria fechar, então aí não deve usar.

É comum em muitos casos usar o `close()` em um `try-catch` tanto quanto fora dele. Na verdade as pessoas usam `try-catch` onde não devem e tem grande chance de estar usando errado aí. E se precisar mesmo provavelmente deveria usar um `try` *with resources*, e aí não é necessário usar o `close()` porque ele será chamado automaticamente e do jeito certo.

Se for usar um `try-catch` então o `close()` deveria ser usado no `finally` que é onde o `try` *with resources* coloca internamente.

De forma geral sempre que usa uma classe chamada *closeable*, ou seja, que possui um método `close()` (na verdade só quando faz parte da interface [`AutoCloseable`](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/20/docs/api/java.base/java/lang/AutoCloseable.html)) deveria usar o `try` *with resources*. Exceto nos casos que a ideia é não fechar naquele local.

Uma parte muito grande dos problemas de memória é não usar desta forma.

Colocar um `close()` onde ele será chamado não é um grande problema, só não servirá de nada. Justamente porque a pessoa pode fazer errado o `try` *with resources* é necessário que ele verifique antes se já está fechado que torna o código mais lento, ainda que faça bem pouca diferença. Mas é ambíguo.

Veja mais na [documentação](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/essential/exceptions/tryResourceClose.html).

[Coloquei no **GitHub** para referência futura](https://github.com/maniero/SOpt/blob/master/Java/Conceptual.md).

Answer (score 4):

A forma mais segura de se usar o `close()` é de forma indireta, com o [*try-with-resources*](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/172909/132). O *try-with-resources* foi introduzido no Java 7 que foi lançado em 2011. Então se você estiver vendo artigos mais antigos, eles não vão falar desse recurso e vão mostrar o gerenciamente à moda antiga.

Um exemplo do uso do *try-with-resources* é esse:

```
try (Connection con = getConnection()) {
    // Faz algo com a conexão.
}
```

O compilador vai colocar por conta própria um blcoo `finally` implícito para fechar o objeto `con` e já tratar todos os casos especiais de exceções no bloco `try` e exceções sendo lançadas pelo método `close()`. Se você colocar blocos `catch` ou um bloco `finally` explícito, o compilador vai saber como combinar tudo harmoniosamente. Veja mais detalhes na pergunta "[Como funciona o try-with-resources?](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/172909/132)".

Chamar o `close()` dentro de um bloco que já usa o *try-with-resources*, embora possível, não costuma ter muito sentido, mas também dificilmente causaria algum efeito nocivo, exceto se você tentar utilizar o recurso fechado como se ainda estivesse aberto, obviamente.

Se não puder usar o *try-with-resources* por alguma razão, prefira fazer o que o compilador faria se você usasse: Chame o `close()` dentro do bloco `finally`. Por exemplo:

```
Connection con = null;
try {
    con = getConnection();
    // ... faz um monte de coisas.
} catch (SQLException e) {
    // Faz algo para tratar a exceção, relançar ou encapsular e lançar outra exceção.
} finally {
    try {
        if (con != null) con.close();
    } catch (SQLException e) {
        // Faz algo para tratar a exceção, relançar ou encapsular e lançar outra exceção.
    }
}
```

Se você está lidando com um caso onde o recurso deve permanecer aberto após terminar a execução do método, então em geral há duas alternativas:

1. Retorne o objeto que representa o recurso que ficou aberto para que o método que o chamou se preocupe em fechar.
2. Armazene o objeto em algum atributo de instância da classe e faça essa classe implementar `AutoCloseable`. O método `close()` dessa classe delega então ao `close()` do recurso aberto. Esse recurso deve ser aberto preferencialmente no construtor.

Exemplo do caso 1:

```
// Deixa o recurso aberto e o retorna.
public InputStream abrirArquivo() {
    return new FileInputStream(new File("teste.txt"));
}

// Usa o recurso aberto pelo outro método.
public class utilizaArquivo() {
    try (InputStream x = abrirArquivo()) {
        // ...
    }
}
```

Exemplo do caso 2:

```
public class ChamadaTelefonica implements AutoCloseable {
    private final String destino;
    private final InputStream entrada;
    private final OutputStream saida;

    public ChamadaTelefonica(String destino) {
        this.destino = destino;
        this.entrada = ...;
        this.saida = ...;
    }

    // Um monte de métodos legais aqui que operar os atributos entrada e saída.

    @Override
    public void close() throws IOException {
        try {
            entrada.close();
        } finally {
            saida.close();
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Você não precisa usar o `close()` para fechar uma conexão quando ela é gerenciada por outro sistema. É comum em projetos grandes as conexões serem gerenciadas pelo `servidor de aplicação`, ou por um `framework JPA`, nesse caso não é necessário abrir ou fechar conexões, apenas pegar e usar.

Se você está fazendo tudo manualmente, abrir conexão, executar query, commit, etç, é necessário e fundamental fechar as conexões, caso contrário você pode estourar o limite do banco. Esse limite depende do tipo de banco e configuração que você está usando.