# Busca não é realizada após conectar-se ao banco de dados em Java

Tags: java, mysql, jdbc

Estou tentando realizar uma busca pelo banco de dados usando o código em java, mas não consigo. O banco de dados está conectado, mas a busca não é realizada. Eu criei duas classes, uma que possui a classe com o método da conexão, e a outra, que é a principal. Nela, eu chamo o método da conexão. Usei como base o livro do autor Deitel.

Segue o código:

```
public class Conexao {

    public static  Statement conectarBanco() {

            final String DATABASE_URL = "jdbc:mysql://localhost/locadora";
            final String ROOT = "root";
            final String SENHA = "";

            try(Connection connection = DriverManager.getConnection(DATABASE_URL, ROOT, SENHA);){
                Statement statement = connection.createStatement();

                System.out.println("Conectado!");
                return statement;
            }   

            catch(SQLException sqlException) {
                sqlException.printStackTrace();
                }
            return null;
        }
}
```

---

```
public class Principal   {
    public static void main(String args[]) throws SQLException {
        Statement statement;
        int numberOfColumns;
        final String SELECT_QUERY = "select*from cliente";


        statement =  Conexao.conectarBanco();   
        ResultSet resultSet = statement.executeQuery(SELECT_QUERY);
        ResultSetMetaData metaData =  (ResultSetMetaData) resultSet.getMetaData();
        numberOfColumns = metaData.getColumnCount(); 

        for(int i = 1; i<= numberOfColumns; i++) {
            System.out.println(metaData.getColumnName(i));
        }

        while(resultSet.next()) {
            for(int i = 1; i<= numberOfColumns; i++) {
                System.out.println(resultSet.getObject(i));
                System.out.println();
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Algumas coisas devem ser modificadas no seu código:

- Você está usando um try-with-resources no `conectarBanco()`, portanto ao final da execução do bloco a conexão será fechada implicitamente;
- Tente retornar um objeto do tipo Connection ao invés de retornar um Statement, seria algo como `public Connection getConnection()`. Assim você poderia criar um PreparedStatement também;
- Usar espaços na sua query (e de preferência conferir antes no banco de dados se elas funcionam): `select * from cliente`.

Veja abaixo as sugestões:

```
public static  Statement conectarBanco() {

   private final String DATABASE_URL = "jdbc:mysql://localhost/locadora";
   private final String ROOT = "root";
   private final String SENHA = "";

   try{
        Connection connection = DriverManager.getConnection(DATABASE_URL, ROOT, SENHA);

        if(connection != null) {
            System.out.println("Conectado!");
            return connection;
        }   

   } catch(SQLException sqlException) {
        sqlException.printStackTrace();
   }
   return null;
}
```

Na utilização você pode usar o try-with-resources:

```
public static void main(String args[]) throws SQLException {
    Statement statement = null;
    ResultSet rs = null;

    int numberOfColumns;
    final String SELECT_QUERY = "select * from cliente";

    try(Connection con = Conexao.conectarBanco()) {
        statement = con.createStatement(SELECT_QUERY) ;   
        rs = statement.executeQuery(SELECT_QUERY);
        ResultSetMetaData metaData =  (ResultSetMetaData) rs.getMetaData();
        numberOfColumns = metaData.getColumnCount(); 

        for(int i = 1; i<= numberOfColumns; i++) {
            System.out.println(metaData.getColumnName(i));
        }

        while(resultSet.next()) {
            for(int i = 1; i<= numberOfColumns; i++) {
                System.out.println(resultSet.getObject(i));
                System.out.println();
            }
        }
    } catch () {
        // Tratar sua exceção
    } finally {
        // Fechar o Statement e o ResultSet 
    }
```

Comment: Boa noite, Gustavo. Muito obrigado pelo comentário. Identifiquei o meu erro. Refiz o método e está parecido com a forma que você me explicou. Muito obrigado mesmo.

Answer (score 1):

Ora, a sua função `conectarBanco()` abre a conexão, mostra `"Conectado!"` e **então fecha a conexão**. Só depois que a conexão foi fechada é que você tenta extrair alguma informação do banco de dados.

Talvez você não tenha entendido direito como funciona o *try-with-resources* que você usa para fazer a conexão. A finalidade do *try-with-resources* é gerenciar automaticamente o fechamento dos recursos abertos, que no seu caso deveriam incluir o `Connection`, o `PreparedStatement` e o `RsultSet`, todos eles. Veja mais sobre isso [nessa resposta](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/172909/132).

Seu código deveria ficar assim:

```
public class Conexao {

    private static final String DATABASE_URL = "jdbc:mysql://localhost/locadora";
    private static final String ROOT = "root";
    private static final String SENHA = "";

    public static Connection conectarBanco() throws SQLException {
        return DriverManager.getConnection(DATABASE_URL, ROOT, SENHA);){
    }
}
```

```
public class Principal   {

    private static final String SELECT_QUERY = "select * from cliente";

    public static void main(String[] args) throws SQLException {
        try (
            Connection con = Conexao.conectarBanco();
            PreparedStatement statement = con.prepareStatement(SELECT_QUERY);   
            ResultSet resultSet = statement.executeQuery();
        ) {
            ResultSetMetaData metaData =  (ResultSetMetaData) resultSet.getMetaData();
            int numberOfColumns = metaData.getColumnCount(); 

            for (int i = 1; i <= numberOfColumns; i++) {
                System.out.println(metaData.getColumnName(i));
            }

            while (resultSet.next()) {
                for (int i = 1; i <= numberOfColumns; i++) {
                    System.out.println(resultSet.getObject(i));
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Ah, por sinal ignorar exceções e retornar `null` é uma péssima prática de programação. A única coisa que você vai conseguir com isso é esconder a causa real dos erros e transformá-los em `NullPointerException`s de origem misteriosa.

Comment: Victor, boa noite. Obrigado pelas dicas. Consegui perceber o meu erro. Não conhecia muito bem esta cláusula de exceção. Comecei a estudar pouco tempo.

Comment: @AlexandreSantosdaCruz Se essa resposta resolveu o seu problema e não restou nenhuma dúvida, marque-a como correta/aceita ao clicar no "✅" que está ao lado dela, o que também marca a sua pergunta como resolvida. Se preferir a outra resposta, pode marcá-la como correta/aceita, mas apenas uma resposta pode ser marcada dessa forma. Se ainda te resta alguma dúvida ou gostaria de maiores esclarecimentos, fique a vontade para comentar. 