# Como converter uma lista de Strings para uma lista de inteiros

Tags: java

Eu tenho arquivo TXT, e ele se encontra assim:

```
01 02 03;
01 02 04;
01 03 04;
02 03 04;
```

Bem, carrego esse arquivo em `ArrayList<String>` como está no código abaixo. Como faço para passar ele para `ArrayList<Integer>`, para manipular seu conteúdo?

```
package bola;

import java.io.BufferedReader;
import java.io.FileNotFoundException;
import java.io.FileReader;
import java.io.IOException;
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.List;

public class LerArquivo {

    public static ArrayList<String> lista = new ArrayList<>();

    public void leitura() throws FileNotFoundException {

        String path = "D:\\Conteudo\\teste.txt";
        BufferedReader br = null;
        FileReader fr = null;
        try {
            fr = new FileReader(path);
            br = new BufferedReader(fr);

            List<String> minhaList = new ArrayList<String>();           
            String line = br.readLine();
            String[] meuArray = null;

            while (line != null) {              
                line = br.readLine();
                minhaList.add(line);
                meuArray = minhaList.toArray(new String[0]);                

            }
            for(int i = 0; i < meuArray.length; i++) {
                System.out.println(meuArray[i]);
            }

        } catch (IOException e) {
            System.out.println("Error: " + e.getMessage());
        } finally {
            try {
                if (br != null)
                    br.close();
                if (fr != null)
                    fr.close();
            } catch (IOException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
        }
    }


    public static void main(String[] args) throws IOException {
        LerArquivo le = new LerArquivo();
        le.leitura();
    }
}
```

Answer (score 7):

Primeira coisa: Não use `FileWriter`, pois essa classe usa o encoding padrão da máquina ao invés de ter um encoding definido pelo usuário, levando a problemas de incompatibilidade de encoding. Inclusive há discussões/sugestões nas listas de discussão da Oracle para marcá-la como `@Deprecated` por causa disso. No lugar dela, use `OutputStreamWriter` passando o `Charset` desejado no construtor.

Em segundo lugar, use o [*try-with-resources*](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/172909/132) e isso vai simplificar bastante o seu código.

No entanto, vou reescrever seu código de uma forma que você pode deixar para lá essas duas dicas acima:

- É mais simples ler o arquivo todo com [`Files.readAllLines(Path)`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/10/docs/api/java/nio/file/Files.html#readAllLines(java.nio.file.Path)).
- Use a API de streams a seu favor.

Eis o código:

```
package bola;

import java.io.File;
import java.io.IOException;
import java.nio.file.Files;
import java.util.stream.Collectors;
import java.util.stream.Stream;
import java.util.List;

public class LerArquivo {

    private static Stream<Integer> ints(String s) {
        return Stream.of(s.replace(";", "").split(" ")).map(Integer::parseInt);
    }

    public static List<Integer> leitura() throws IOException {
        String path = "D:\\Conteudo\\teste.txt";
        Stream<String> linhas = Files.readAllLines(new File(path).toPath()).stream();
        return linhas.flatMap(LerArquivo::ints).collect(Collectors.toList());
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) throws IOException {
        System.out.println(LerArquivo.leitura());
    }
}
```

Eis a saída produzida:

```
[1, 2, 3, 1, 2, 4, 1, 3, 4, 2, 3, 4]
```

Comment: obrigado pela solução.