# Como pegar um item de um List< [ ] String>?

Tags: java, java-ee, jdbc

Como posso pegar um item de um `List< [] String>`?

```
// Monta a String
partsList.add(new String [] {StringUtils.trim(String.valueOf(peças.getCodigoProduto())),
                                              String.valueOf(peças.getCodigoFornecedor())});    

// Metodo recebe a lista de string do objeto    
public List<Object[]> searchPeças (final List<String[]> partsList, final java.math.BigInteger bkSubDivisionUidD ) {


    sql.append("\n BEGIN ");    
    sql.append("\n  SET NOCOUNT ON ");
    sql.append("\n  DECLARE @CodigoProduto     VARCHAR(10), ");
    sql.append("\n          @CodigoFornecedor  VARCHAR(10)  ");   
    sql.append("\n  SET     @subDivision     = ? ");
    sql.append("\n  SET     @perfitSerial    = ? ");

// Aqui Preciso pegar o código do fornecedor e passar como parametro

    int i = 1;
    query.setParameter(i++, partsList);
}
```

Answer (score 5):

Vejo que no seu programa, você usa os seguintes "padrões":

- [Black Cat in a Dark Room](https://desciclopedia.org/wiki/Gambi_Design_Patterns#BCDR).
- [Thunder Mega Zord](https://desciclopedia.org/wiki/Gambi_Design_Patterns#Thunder_Mega_Zord).
- [Um array vale mais que mil variáveis](https://desciclopedia.org/wiki/Gambi_Design_Patterns#Um_array_vale_mais_que_mil_vari%C3%A1veis).
- Um pouco de [Programação Orientada a Strings](https://desciclopedia.org/wiki/Gambi_Design_Patterns#Programa%C3%A7%C3%A3o_Orientada_a_Strings).

Sugiro abandonar esses "padrões" o mais rápido que for possível e abolir coisas como `String[]`, `Object[]`, `List<String[]>` e `List<Object[]>`. Isso advém do fato de que o que você está pedindo é um [problema XY](https://pt.meta.stackoverflow.com/q/499/132).

Ou seja, a declaração do método deveria ser algo assim:

```
public List<Peca> searchPecas(
        int codigoProduto,
        int codigoFornecedor,
        BigInteger bkSubDivisionUidD)
{
    // ...
}
```

Observe que o resultado é `List<Peça>` e não `List<Object[]>`. Afinal, Java é uma linguagem orientada a objetos, e portanto os dados referentes a uma peça devem estar em uma classe `Peça` e não dentro de um `Object[]`. Da mesma forma, um método que fornece uma lista de peças, deve retornar `List<Peça>` e não um `List<Object[]>`.

Trabalhar com um `Object[]` é difícil porque qualquer coisa pode estar em qualquer lugar de qualquer jeito e boa sorte ao coitado do programador que tiver que lidar com isso, algo bem diferente de caso de usar uma classe claramente definida. Logo, é melhor usar uma classe `Peça` ao invés de um `Object[]`.

Quanto aos parâmetros, a regra de ouro é separar as coisas de forma clara. A forma mais simples de fazer isso seria deixar os parâmetros sendo apenas tipos simples tais como `int`, `String`, `BigInteger`, etc. Ou então, criar uma classe para encapsular o significado dos parâmetros, tais como algo assim:

```
public final class BuscaPecasParametros {
    private final int codigoProduto;
    private final int codigoFornecedor;

    public BuscaPecasParametros(int codigoProduto, int codigoFornecedor) {
        this.codigoProduto = codigoProduto;
        this.codigoFornecedor = codigoFornecedor;
    }

    public int getCodigoProduto() {
        return codigoProduto;
    }

    public int getCodigoFornecedor() {
        return codigoFornecedor;
    }
}
```

E então, no método você colocaria isso:

```
public List<Peca> searchPecas(BuscaPecasParametros params) {
    // ...
}
```

Dependendo do caso (não dá para saber ao certo só com o código incompleto da pergunta), poderia ser assim também:

```
public List<Peca> searchPecas(
        List<BuscaPecasParametros> params,
        BigInteger bkSubDivisionUidD)
{
    // ...
}
```

A SQL seria construída fica mais ou menos assim:

```
private static final String SQL_PECAS = ""
        + "\n BEGIN "
        + "\n  SET NOCOUNT ON "
        + "\n  DECLARE @CodigoProduto     VARCHAR(10), "
        + "\n          @CodigoFornecedor  VARCHAR(10)  "
        + "\n  SET     @subDivision     = ? "
        + "\n  SET     @perfitSerial    = ? ";
```

Sim, use o velho operador `+` com `String`s aqui. Nada de ficar criando `StringBuilder`, `StringBuffer`, `append` ou qualquer uma dessas parafernálias porque o compilador é esperto o suficiente para fazer a concatenação de strings constantes em tempo de compilação. Se você olhar o bytecode resultante, verá a string já montada pelo compilador lá dentro e o peso no desempenho será tão próximo de zero que nem tem como ser medido facilmente, sendo a string carregada já inteira uma única vez quando a classe for carregada na memória pela JVM. Por outro lado, usando a abordagem do `append`s tal como você está usando, as strings acabarão sendo construídas e reconstruídas a partir de diversos pedaços sempre que o método for executado, o que significa que haverá impacto no desempenho e no coletor de lixo.

Para ver como fazer o interior do método, dê uma olhada [aqui](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/172909/132). Não dá para montar exatamente como seria nesta resposta porque estão faltando muitas partes do método na sua pergunta. Então vou copiar o exemplo que fiz na [minha resposta a uma outra pergunta](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/a/172910/132) para te servir de inspiração:

```
private static final String SQL_ALUNOS_POR_TURMA = 
        "SELECT id, nome, telefone FROM alunos WHERE id_turma = ?";

public static void localizarAlunos(String turma) throws ConexaoFalhouException {
    try (
        Connection c = Conexao.obter();
        PreparedStatement ps = c.prepareStatement(SQL_ALUNOS_POR_TURMA);
    ) {
        ps.setString(1, turma);
        try (ResultSet rs = ps.executeQuery()) {

            List<Aluno> alunos = new ArrayList<>();
            while (rs.next()) {
                Aluno a = new Aluno();
                a.setInt(rs.getInt(1));
                a.setNome(rs.getString(2));
                a.setTelefone(rs.getString(3));
                alunos.add(a);
            }

            return alunos;
        }
    } catch (SQLException e) {
        throw new ConexaoFalhouException(e);
    }
}
```

E mais um outro detalhe:

```
StringUtils.trim(String.valueOf(peças.getCodigoProduto()))
```

Ué? Se o resultado de `peças.getCodigoProduto()` precisa ser encapsulado em um `String.valueOf(...)`, então é porque isso provavelmente não é uma string. Se isso não é uma string, então o `StringUtils.trim(...)` é desnecessário. E mesmo se o `StringUtils.trim(...)` estiver sendo necessário, o certo seria o `peças.getCodigoProduto()` retornar algo que nunca vá criar espaços no começo ou no fim.

Comment: +1 pelos padroes de POGjetos que eu nem sabia q tinha nomes ate agora :p

Comment: Esses gambi design patterns são hilariantes. Já me ri aqui a valor com isso :D

Comment: Victor obrigado pelos esclarecimentos. Estou iniciando e irei considerar sua orientação na busca de boas práticas.