# Problema com uma estrutura de um metodo

Tags: java, jdbc

Bom eu fiz um metodo para alterar senha

onde ele faz um select no banco de dados  para ver se o login e a senha digitada são iguais no banco de dados

```
String sql = "SELECT id_usuario,nome,senha FROM usuario where login = ? and senha = ?";
    try {
        PreparedStatement stmt = con.prepareStatement(sql);
        stmt.setString(1, u.getLogin());
        stmt.setString(2, u.getSenha());
        ResultSet rs = stmt.executeQuery();
```

e depois eu fiz essa verificação com um if:

```
  if (rs.next()){
            String update = "UPDATE usuario SET senha=? WHERE id_usuario = " +Sessao.getInstancia().getUsuario().getId()+ "";
            PreparedStatement stmt2 = con.prepareStatement(sql);
            stmt2.setString(1, u.getNovaSenha());
            ResultSet rs2 = stmt2.executeQuery();

            return true;
        }
```

para fazer o update da senha se o id for igual o id do usuario conectado
eu debuguei e verifiquei que o está pegando o id do usuario normalmente, mas está dando esse error:

```
GRAVE: null
java.sql.SQLException: No value specified for parameter 2
```

eu sei que tem relação com a estrutura, mas eu não faço ideia onde eu errei 
e como e onde eu fecharia a conexão com o bd dps disso?

Comment: Porque começou fazendo o código do jeito certo e depois resolver abrir sua aplicação para ter um SQL Injection e ser invadida?

Comment: sou novo no java eu fiz isso na tentiva, mas eu iria fechar novamente a conexão.

Comment: Você poderia me dar uma ajuda como eu melhoraria isso? ou uma forma mais fácil.

Comment: Então comece aprendendo os princípios, fazer no chuto, tentando adivinhar as coisas não dá muito certo. Agora mesmo você tentou adivinhar de novo, achando que fechar alguma coisa vai eliminar o SQL Injection. Você terá sérios problemas tentando programador desta forma, tem que entender tudo o que está acontecendo com o código. Tudo o que você colocar nele e não dominar o que está ali, já está errado, mesmo que funcione.

Comment: O meu error foi ter aberto outra conexão? Vc poderia me ajudar me explicando melhor sobre isso e uma maneira como resolver ?

Comment: Talvez a melhor maneira seja dar um update quando o login / senha / id for igual a senha do usuario logado?

Comment: Leia meus dois primeiros comentários, vamos ficar em círculos aqui.

Comment: Recomendo: https://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/172909/132

Comment: Edite a pergunta e poste o código inteiro do método em questão. Tenho a impressão que sem isso não dá para responder a pergunta satisfatoriamente.

Comment: Ah, e como é que você obtém essa variável `con`?

Comment: Recomendo também: https://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/2402/132

Comment: @VictorStafusa opa man vlw eu já consegui resolver com um metodo, eu obtenho o con atraves do construtor da classe usuarioDAO :

Comment: acabou ficando assim:

Comment: public boolean mudarSenha(Usuario u){
        String sql = "UPDATE usuario SET senha=? WHERE id_usuario = " +Sessao.getInstancia().getUsuario().getId()+" and login='"+Sessao.getInstancia().getUsuario().getLogin()+"' and senha=?";
        try {
        PreparedStatement stmt = con.prepareStatement(sql);
        stmt.setString(1, u.getNovaSenha());
        stmt.setString(2, u.getSenha());
        stmt.execute();
        stmt.close();
        con.close();

Comment: será que agora está bom?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Cara, o ideal é você ter métodos para cada coisa que você quer fazer separadamente e não tudo em um só..
por exemplo, podes ter um método de verificar usuário (retornaria boolean), e outro para alterar senha (que receberia como parametro um id)
pronto!

```
public boolean verificarUsuario(Usuario u) {
        String sql = "SELECT * FROM usuario WHERE nome = ?";
        PreparedStatement stmt = null;
        ResultSet rs = null;
        try {
            stmt = con.prepareStatement(sql);
            stmt.setString(1, u.getNome());
            rs = stmt.executeQuery();
            rs.first();
            return rs.getString("senha").equals(u.getSenha());
        } catch (SQLException ex) {
            System.err.println("ERRO: " + ex);
        } finally {
            ConnectionFactoryMySQL.closeConnection(con, stmt, rs);
        }
    }
```

e depois ter o método de alterar senha:

```
public boolean updateUsuario(Usuario u) {
        String sql = "UPDATE usuario SET senha = ? WHERE nome = ?";
        PreparedStatement stmt= null;
        try {
            stmt= con.prepareStatement(sql);
            stmt.setString(1, u.getSenha());
            stmt.setString(2, u.getNome());
            stmt.executeUpdate();
            return true;
        } catch (SQLException ex) {
            System.err.println("ERRO: " + ex);
            return false;
        }finally{
            ConnectionFactoryMySQL.closeConnection(con, stmt);
        }
    }
```

Comment: vlw man eu consegui fazer com apenas um metodo, mas isso me deu algumas ideias para outras funções do programa, mt obrigado.