# O conteúdo não está sendo salvo no arquivo usando a classe PrintWriter

Tags: java

O arquivo, de fato, é criado, mas sem o conteúdo que deveria ter.

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Método `Program`:

```
String program() {

        return "import java.io.*;\n"
                + "import javax.swing.JOptionPane;\n"
                + "\n"
                + "public class Main {\n"
                + "    \n"
                + "    static final Runtime run = Runtime.getRuntime();\n"
                + "    static Process pro;\n"
                + "    static BufferedReader read;\n"
                + "\n"
                + "    public static void main(String[] args) {\n"
                + "        String[] cmds = {\n"
                + "            \"cd /d D:\\\\Desenvolvimento\\\\snippets-codes && concurrently \\\"cd snippets && serve\\\" \\\"cd backend && adonis serve --dev\\\"\",\n"
                + "        };\n"
                + "\n"
                + "        try {\n"
                + "            ProcessBuilder builder = new ProcessBuilder(\"cmd\", \"/c\",\n"
                + "                    String.join(\"& \", cmds));\n"
                + "\n"
                + "            builder.redirectErrorStream(true);\n"
                + "\n"
                + "            Process p = builder.start();\n"
                + "\n"
                + "            BufferedReader r = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(p.getInputStream()));\n"
                + "            String line;\n"
                + "\n"
                + "            while (true) {\n"
                + "                line = r.readLine();\n"
                + "                if (line == null) {\n"
                + "                    break;\n"
                + "                }\n"
                + "\n"
                + "                System.out.println(line);\n"
                + "            }\n"
                + "        } catch (Exception e) {\n"
                + "            JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, e.getMessage(), \"Atenção\", 1);\n"
                + "        }\n"
                + "    }\n"
                + "}";
    }
```

Código para criar o arquivo e inserir algum conteúdo nele:

```
try {
      PrintWriter writer = new PrintWriter("C:\\Users\\MY_USER_NAME\\Desktop\\teste.java", "UTF-8");

            String[] words = program().split("\\n");

            for (String word : words) {
                System.out.println(word);
                writer.println(word);
            }

        } catch (FileNotFoundException | UnsupportedEncodingException ex) {
            JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, ex.getMessage(), "Atenção", 1);
        }
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Internamente, [`PrintWriter`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/io/PrintWriter.html) possui um *buffer* no qual as escritas são feitas. Quando o *buffer* está cheio, aí o seu conteúdo é de fato escrito na *stream* correspondente (no caso, o arquivo). No seu caso, o conteúdo não foi suficiente para lotar o *buffer*, por isso nada foi escrito.

Existem algumas alternativas para resolver.

Uma delas é, ao final, chamar o [método `flush`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/io/PrintWriter.html#flush()), que força a escrita do conteúdo que está no *buffer*:

```
for (String word : words) {
    System.out.println(word);
    writer.println(word);
}
writer.flush();
```

Outra é chamar o [método `close`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/io/PrintWriter.html#close()), preferencialmente dentro de um bloco `finally` (pois o `close()` já faz o *flush*):

```
PrintWriter writer = null;
try {
    writer = new PrintWriter("teste.java", "UTF-8");
    String[] words = program().split("\\n");

    for (String word : words) {
        System.out.println(word);
        writer.println(word);
    }
} catch (IOException e) {
    // tratar a exceção
} finally {
    if (writer != null)
        writer.close();
}
```

Mas se estiver usando Java >= 7, pode usar a sintaxe de [*try-with-resources*](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/172909/112052):

```
try (PrintWriter writer = new PrintWriter("teste.java", "UTF-8")) {
    String[] words = program().split("\\n");

    for (String word : words) {
        System.out.println(word);
        writer.println(word);
    }
} catch (IOException e) {
    // tratar a exceção
}
```

Neste caso nem precisa do bloco `finally`, pois o `PrintWriter` já será fechado ao final do bloco `try` (e quando for fechado, será feito o *flush*).

---

Outra alternativa é usar um [construtor](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/io/PrintWriter.html#PrintWriter(java.io.Writer,%20boolean)) que recebe como parâmetro o valor do `autoFlush`, indicando se deve ser feito o *flush* automático:

```
PrintWriter writer = new PrintWriter(new FileWriter("teste.java"), true);
```

Passando o valor `true` para `autoFlush`, é feito o *flush* automático toda vez que forem chamados os métodos `println`, `printf` ou `format` (assim não precisa chamar `flush` ou `close` para forçar a escrita do conteúdo do *buffer*).

Se bem que eu particularmente prefiro os blocos `try` acima (*try-with-resources* se estiver usando Java >= 7, ou o `try`/`finally` para versões anteriores), para garantir que o recurso é fechado.

Comment: Obrigado, deu certo.

Answer (score 0):

Faltou o Flush e o Close

```
    try {
        PrintWriter writer = new PrintWriter("C:\\Users\\MY_USER_NAME\\Desktop\\teste.java", "UTF-8");

        String[] words = program().split("\\n");

        for (String word : words) {
            System.out.println(word);
            writer.println(word);
        }

        writer.flush();
        writer.close();

    } catch (FileNotFoundException | UnsupportedEncodingException ex) {
        JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, ex.getMessage(), "Atenção", 1);
    }
```