# mandar uma mensagem do servidor para o cliente Sockets

Tags: java, socket

Recentemente comecei a trabalhar com sockets esta semana e estou tendo dificuldades. Meu objetivo é quando o cliente envia uma mensagem  o servidor respondia com uma notificação. No lado do cliente, o envio para o servidor não tem problemas, mas quando o servidor envia para o cliente, nada aparece. Alguém pode me ajudar com este problema?

**CLIENTE:**

```
            socket = new Socket("localhost", 8080);

            PrintWriter out = new PrintWriter(socket.getOutputStream(), true);
            out.write(message);
            out.close();
            System.out.println("send to server");

            InputStreamReader in = new InputStreamReader(socket.getInputStream());
            BufferedReader bf = new BufferedReader(in);
            String string = bf.readLine();
            System.out.println("server said :" + string);
```

**SERVIDOR:**

```
    serverSocket = new ServerSocket(8080);
    while(true){
        System.out.println("Accepting...");
        socket = serverSocket.accept();
        System.out.println("Connected...");

        in = new InputStreamReader(socket.getInputStream());
        bf = new BufferedReader(in);

        PrintWriter out = new PrintWriter(socket.getOutputStream());

        messageFromClient = bf.readLine();

        System.out.println("Received: " + messageFromClient);
        message = "welcome";
        System.out.println("Sending...");

        out.write(message);
        out.flush();

        System.out.println("sending done");
    }
```

Comment: Veja [na documentação](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/net/Socket.html#getOutputStream--): quando vc fecha o `OutputStream`, o `Socket` também é fechado. Então feche-o somente no final (ou use um [bloco try-with-resources](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/172909/112052) que já garante que o socket é fechado, por exemplo)