# Como converter hexadecimal para decimal recebido por socket

Tags: java, socket, decimal, hexadecimal

Preciso converter uma entrada hexadecimal no cliente, para decimal, mas não achei informações de como fazer isso.

Exemplo do socket server:

```
byte[] HEXA = {(byte)0x00, (byte)0x96, (byte)0x07, (byte)0xBF};

ServerSocket serverSocket = null;
Socket client = null;
PrintStream out = null;

try {
    ServerSocket serverSocket = new ServerSocket(9090, 0, InetAddress.getByName(null));
    System.out.println("SOCKET ABERTO");

    client = serverSocket.accept();

    out = new PrintStream(client.getOutputStream());

    out.print(HEXA);
} catch (UnknownHostException ex) {
    Logger.getLogger(Main.class.getName()).log(Level.SEVERE, null, ex);
} catch (IOException ex) {
    Logger.getLogger(Main.class.getName()).log(Level.SEVERE, null, ex);
}finally{
    out.close();
    client.close();
    serverSocket.close();
}
```

No lado cliente, eu preciso converter cada byte hexa, para decimal (00 150 07 191). Tentei utilizando `InputStream` e `BufferedReader`, mas não obtive resultados tentando fazer a conversão.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

### Server

Quando você chama o método `print` de um `PrintStream` passando um array de bytes, ele acaba chamando [esta versão do método](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/11/docs/api/java.base/java/io/PrintStream.html#print(java.lang.Object)), que segundo a documentação escreve o resultado de [`String.valueOf(objeto)`](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/11/docs/api/java.base/java/lang/String.html#valueOf(java.lang.Object)). E o que acontece quando fazemos isso com um array?

```
byte[] HEXA = { (byte) 0x00, (byte) 0x96, (byte) 0x07, (byte) 0xBF };
System.out.println(String.valueOf(HEXA)); // [B@15db9742
```

Ele imprime algo como "[B@15db9742" (os números e letras podem variar, pois se trata do *hashcode* do array em questão, conforme explicado [aqui](https://stackoverflow.com/a/29140403)). Então na verdade você não está enviando os bytes do array `HEXA`, e sim os caracteres que correspondem ao retorno de `String.valueOf` (que será este "código" aí).

Na verdade o próprio [`System.out`](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/11/docs/api/java.base/java/lang/System.html#out) é um `PrintStream`, então podemos testar esse comportamento fazendo `System.out.print(HEXA)`, que produzirá o mesmo resultado. Isso tudo é para dizer que usar `PrintStream::print` talvez não seja o que você precisa.

---

Pelo seu exemplo, você não está trabalhando com texto/caracteres, e sim com bytes "brutos", então para enviar estes bytes você poderia usar um [`java.io.DataOutputStream`](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/11/docs/api/java.base/java/io/DataOutputStream.html) e seu [método `write`](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/11/docs/api/java.base/java/io/DataOutputStream.html#write(byte%5B%5D,int,int)), passando o array de bytes diretamente (recomendo ler [aqui](https://stackoverflow.com/q/6984130) e [aqui](https://stackoverflow.com/q/8921225) para mais detalhes).

E se estiver usando Java >= 7, também pode usar [*try-with-resources*](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/172909/112052), que já fecha os recursos automaticamente, sem a necessidade de um bloco `finally`:

```
// Server
byte[] HEXA = { (byte) 0x00, (byte) 0x96, (byte) 0x07, (byte) 0xBF };

try (ServerSocket serverSocket = new ServerSocket(9090, 0, InetAddress.getByName(null))) {
    System.out.println("SOCKET ABERTO");
    Socket client = serverSocket.accept();

    // enviando os bytes para o client
    try (OutputStream out = new DataOutputStream(client.getOutputStream())) {
        out.write(HEXA, 0, HEXA.length);
    } catch (etc...) {
        // mensagens de erro
    } // não precisa de finally, recursos são fechados automaticamente
} catch (etc...) {
    // mensagens de erro
} // não precisa de finally, recursos são fechados automaticamente
```

Claro que se quiser, pode usar também um [`BufferedOutputStream`](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/11/docs/api/java.base/java/io/BufferedOutputStream.html), que [dependendo do caso pode trazer benefícios](https://stackoverflow.com/a/8109770):

```
try (OutputStream out = new DataOutputStream(new BufferedOutputStream(client.getOutputStream()))) {
    out.write(HEXA, 0, HEXA.length);
} catch (IOException e) {
    etc...
}
```

---

### Client

Agora para ler esses bytes, vale explicar alguns detalhes antes.

Um `byte` em Java [é um tipo numérico](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/nutsandbolts/datatypes.html), que usa 8 bits e é *signed* (com sinal), ou seja, aceita valores positivos e negativos - para ser mais preciso, valores entre `-128` e `127`.

Internamente, o que ele tem são apenas bits, e o valor não está em hexadecimal, nem em decimal, nada disso. Um byte é um byte (um conjunto de 8 bits). Ponto.

Quando imprimimos um byte, aí ele é mostrado de alguma maneira (seja na base 10, 16, 8, 2, ou o que for). Mas isso é apenas uma representação do valor, não o valor em si.

Pense em um número - por exemplo, `2` - como um conceito: a ideia de uma determinada quantidade ("duas coisas"). Eu posso representar essa ideia - esse valor - de diferentes formas: como o dígito `2`, como `2.0` (ou `2,0`), como a palavra "dois", "two", e muitos outros formatos. Cada uma dessas formas é diferente, mas todas representam o mesmo valor.

Da mesma forma, quando você usa no seu código um literal como `0xBF`, isso é apenas uma notação da linguagem: uma forma que ela definiu para você colocar um número em hexadecimal no seu código (se você colocasse apenas `BF`, poderia ser confundido com um nome de variável/classe/método, por exemplo, então o `0x` na frente indica que `BF` deve ser interpretado como um número na base 16). Mas isso não quer dizer que o valor da variável estará em hexadecimal, pois internamente será tudo convertido para bits.

Tanto que se você fizer:

```
// colocando os valores em hexadecimal
byte[] hex = { (byte) 0x00, (byte) 0x96, (byte) 0x07, (byte) 0xBF };
System.out.println("HEXA:");
for (int i = 0; i < hex.length; i++) {
    byte b = hex[i];
    System.out.printf("hexa: %02X, oct: %03o dec: %04d, dec 'unsigned':%04d, bin: %s\n",
                      b, b, b, b & 0xff, Integer.toBinaryString(b & 0xff));
}

// colocando os valores em decimal
byte[] dec = { (byte) 0, (byte) 150, (byte) 7, (byte) 191 };
System.out.println("DEC:");
for (int i = 0; i < dec.length; i++) {
    byte b = dec[i];
    System.out.printf("hexa: %02X, oct: %03o dec: %04d, dec 'unsigned':%04d, bin: %s\n",
                      b, b, b, b & 0xff, Integer.toBinaryString(b & 0xff));
}
```

A saída será:

```
HEXA:
hexa: 00, oct: 000 dec: 0000, dec 'unsigned':0000, bin: 0
hexa: 96, oct: 226 dec: -106, dec 'unsigned':0150, bin: 10010110
hexa: 07, oct: 007 dec: 0007, dec 'unsigned':0007, bin: 111
hexa: BF, oct: 277 dec: -065, dec 'unsigned':0191, bin: 10111111
DEC:
hexa: 00, oct: 000 dec: 0000, dec 'unsigned':0000, bin: 0
hexa: 96, oct: 226 dec: -106, dec 'unsigned':0150, bin: 10010110
hexa: 07, oct: 007 dec: 0007, dec 'unsigned':0007, bin: 111
hexa: BF, oct: 277 dec: -065, dec 'unsigned':0191, bin: 10111111
```

Os valores que estão em ambos os arrays `hex` e `dec` são exatamente os mesmos. A diferença é que no primeiro caso eu usei a notação hexadecimal, e no segundo usei a notação decimal. Mas os bytes resultantes são exatamente os mesmos (são os mesmos valores, eu apenas usei representações diferentes desses mesmos valores para criar os arrays).

Repare também como eu mostro os mesmos valores (os mesmos bytes) de diferentes formas:

- na base 16
- na base 8
- na base 10 (e os valores maiores que 127 viram números negativos porque `byte` é um tipo *signed* - para entender melhor, leia [aqui](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Signed_number_representations))
- na base 10, mas usando um "truque" descrito [aqui](https://stackoverflow.com/a/44833887) e [aqui](https://stackoverflow.com/a/4266841) para convertê-lo para um `int` e assim ter o valor positivo correspondente aos seus bits
- na base 2, usando o mesmo "truque" do caso acima, para vermos os bits do número

Como eu já disse, todas essas formas são diferentes representações dos mesmos bits (dos mesmos valores). O resultado final (o "texto" ou "os dígitos/caracteres" que vemos na tela) pode ser diferente para cada caso (`96`, ou `226`, ou `-106`, etc), mas todos representam o mesmo valor (o mesmo `byte`, a mesma sequência de 8 bits).

Sendo assim, você não precisa "*converter cada byte hexa para decimal*". Você só precisa ler os bytes do *server*. Só isso.

Depois, se você quiser mostrá-los na tela em decimal (ou em qualquer outro formato), basta imprimi-los usando o código acima. Algo assim:

```
// Client
byte[] dados = new byte[1024]; // cria um buffer para ler vários dados de uma vez
try (Socket socket = new Socket(InetAddress.getByName(null), 9090)) {
    InputStream in = new DataInputStream(socket.getInputStream());
    int lidos;
    while ((lidos = in.read(dados)) > 0) { // enquanto tiver dados para ler
        System.out.println("dados lidos do server:");
        for (int i = 0; i < lidos; i++) {
            byte b = dados[i];
            System.out.printf("byte lido - hexa: %02X, dec: %03d\n", b, b & 0xff);
        }
    }
} catch (IOException e) {
    // tratar erros, etc
} // não precisa de finally, recursos são fechados automaticamente
```

A saída será:

```
dados lidos do server:
byte lido - hexa: 00, dec: 000
byte lido - hexa: 96, dec: 150
byte lido - hexa: 07, dec: 007
byte lido - hexa: BF, dec: 191
```

---

Ou, se quiser os valores como um `int`:

```
while ((lidos = in.read(dados)) > 0) {
    for (int i = 0; i < lidos; i++) {
        int x = dados[i] & 0xff;
        System.out.println(x);
    }
}
```

Que imprimirá:

```
0
150
7
191
```

Mas se estiver usando Java >= 8, também pode usar [`Byte.toUnsignedInt`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/lang/Byte.html#toUnsignedInt-byte-):

```
while ((lidos = in.read(dados)) > 0) {
    System.out.println("dados lidos do server:");
    for (int i = 0; i < lidos; i++) {
        System.out.println(Byte.toUnsignedInt(dados[i]));
    }
}
```

Que produz o mesmo resultado acima.