# Como faço para ler determinada posição de arquivo em java, e pegar os valores da mesma?

Tags: java

Meu código está da seguinte forma:

```
BufferedReader leitor = new BufferedReader (new FileReader("CARTEIRA\\Chart of accounts\\PlanConCxToReceive.txt"));
String texto = leitor.readLine();
String[] palavras = texto.split(" ->   ;");
 
while (texto !=null) {
    texto = leitor.readLine();
    System.out.println(palavras);     
}
```

Meu arquivo txt está com a seguinte estrutura

```
Bills to receive teste -> 1000.0;
Bills to receive teste -> 200.0;
```

Quero pegar os dois valores e fazer uma soma, eu não consegui fazer de forma alguma.

Answer (score 0):

Quando você usa `split`, tem que indicar a string que será usada para dividir.

Como você usou `" ->   ;"`, ele tentará buscar exatamente este trecho (espaço, hífen, `>`, espaços e ponto-e-vírgula). Mas esta sequência não existe no seu arquivo, pois depois de `->` tem um número, então o `split` não vai fazer a quebra da maneira que você precisa.

Uma maneira de resolver é fazer a quebra somente por `->`, depois no número você elimina o `;` manualmente. E por fim, você converte a string para número e soma ao total:

```
double total = 0;
try (BufferedReader leitor = new BufferedReader(new FileReader("CARTEIRA\\Chart of accounts\\PlanConCxToReceive.txt"))) {
    String texto;
    while ((texto = leitor.readLine()) != null) {
        String valor = texto.split(" -> ")[1];
        total += Double.parseDouble(valor.substring(0, valor.length() - 1));
    }
}
System.out.println(total); // 1200.0
```

No caso, `valor.substring(0, valor.length() - 1)` elimina o último caractere (que é o `;`), e [`Double.parseDouble`](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/14/docs/api/java.base/java/lang/Double.html#parseDouble(java.lang.String)) converte a string para número. Escolhi esta classe porque no arquivo os números possuem uma casa decimal, e `parseDouble` consegue lidar com isso (`Integer.parseInt` daria erro, por exemplo).

Também coloquei o `BufferedReader` em um bloco [*try-with-resources*](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/172909/112052) (disponível a partir do Java 7), que garante que o arquivo será fechado ao final.

E o programa não faz validações: ele assume que sempre terá o `->` e a segunda posição sempre tem um número. Mas se quiser validar, pode fazer algo assim:

```
double total = 0;
try (BufferedReader leitor = new BufferedReader(new FileReader("CARTEIRA\\Chart of accounts\\PlanConCxToReceive.txt"))) {
    String texto;
    while ((texto = leitor.readLine()) != null) {
        String[] partes = texto.split(" -> ");
        if (partes.length > 1) {
            String valor = partes[1];
            try {
                total += Double.parseDouble(valor.substring(0, valor.length() - 1));
            } catch (NumberFormatException e) {
                // não é número - mostrar alguma mensagem de erro, ignorar, etc
            }
        } else {
            // linha não tem "->" - mostrar alguma mensagem de erro, ignorar, etc
        }
    }
}
```