# Como usar split() dentro de um loop em Java?

Tags: java, orientação-a-objetos, arquivo, split

Boa noite, to aprendendo Java a pouco tempo e queria saber como que eu poderia ler um arquivo de texto que possua um ou dois números em no máximo 10 linhas. Algo como os arquivos abaixo:

16x9_resolutions.dat

```
640 360
1280 720
1366 768
1600 900
1920 1080
```

ranking.dat

```
10000
9000
8900
8878
8803
7995
7967
7960
7906
7845
```

Consegui fazer isso:

```
import java.io.BufferedReader;
import java.io.BufferedWriter;
import java.io.FileReader;
import java.io.FileWriter;
import java.io.IOException;
import java.util.Scanner;

public class Files{

    private String vet[] = new String[10];

    public void read(String path) throws IOException {
        BufferedReader buffRead = new BufferedReader(new FileReader(path));
        String line = "";
        int i = 0;
        while (true) {
            line = buffRead.readLine();
            if (line != null) {
                this.vet[i] = line;
                i++;
            } else{
            break;
            }
            if(i == 10){
               break;
            }
        }
        buffRead.close();
    }

    public int getResolutions(int pos){
        return Integer.parseInt(this.vet[pos]);
    }

}
```

Na classe acima eu consigo ler apenas um numero por linha. Quero que o método read() consiga ler os dois tipos de arquivos que eu mostrei, no caso de dois números por linha ele deve colocar o segundo número na próxima posição do vetor e pular pra próxima linha.

Vi alguns posts na internet falando sobre o split() mas nenhum mostrava como usa-lo dentro de um loop. Queria algo como:

```
while (true) {
    line = buffRead.readLine();
    if (line != null) {
        if(line.split() == "2 numeros separados por espaço"){
            this.vet[i] = line.split("primeiro numero");
            i++;
            this.vet[i] = line.split("segundo numero"); 
            i++;
        }else{
            this.vet[i] = line;
              i++;
        }
    }else{
       break;
    }
    if(i == 10){
        break;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Primeiramente, você precisa definir bem o problema:

- é para ler somente as 10 primeiras linhas do arquivo?
- ou é para ler o arquivo até encontrar 10 números, independente da quantidade de linhas?
- ou alguma outra opção?

Por ora, vamos manter simples e assumir que **ou** o arquivo tem 10 linhas (um número por linha), **ou** tem 5 linhas (com dois números por linha). Ou seja, sempre serão 10 números.

Sendo assim, você pode ler a linha, fazer o `split` para ver se tem um ou 2 números, e em seguida guardá-los no array. Lembrando que `split` quebra uma string em várias partes, usando um separador, e retorna um array com estas partes.

Outro ponto é que, se você quer ler números, então por que guardar tudo em um array de `String`? Se a ideia é ter números, então converta-os para o tipo apropriado (que no caso, parece ser `int`, já que seus exemplos só têm números inteiros).

Então uma solução simplificada seria:

```
public class LerArquivo {

    // se quer ler números, use um array de int (não de String)
    private int[] numeros = new int[10];

    public void read(String path) {
        try (BufferedReader reader = new BufferedReader(new FileReader(path))) {
            int pos = 0;
            String linha;
            // já leio a linha e verifico se é null
            leitura: while ((linha = reader.readLine()) != null) {
                String partes[] = linha.split(" "); // separa a linha por espaços
                // percorre as partes do resultado do split, e converte para números
                for (String parte : partes) {
                    // converte para número
                    this.numeros[pos] = Integer.parseInt(parte);
                    pos++; // incrementa a posição do array
                    if (pos == this.numeros.length) { // se já lotou o array, para de ler
                        break leitura; // interrompe o while
                    }
                }
            }
        } catch (IOException e) {
            // mostrar alguma mensagem de erro, etc
        }
    }
}
```

Usei um [bloco *try-with-resources*](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/172909/112052) (disponível a partir do Java 7), que garante que o arquivo é fechado no final (mesmo em caso de erro), assim você não precisa chamar `close` (e da forma que você fez, sem garantia que será chamado, caso dê algum erro no meio da leitura).

No `while`, usei um [*label*](https://stackoverflow.com/a/3821841) (`leitura:`), que é algo pouco usado, mas serve para dar um "nome" para o *loop*, assim eu consigo usar o `break leitura` para indicar que quero interromper a leitura assim que a quantidade de números lidos for igual ao tamanho do array.

Para cada linha lida, faço o `split` usando o espaço como separador. Assim, ele "quebra" a linha em várias partes (separando por espaço), e para cada parte eu converto para número e adiciono no array. Este código assume que sempre serão números (pois se não for, `parseInt` lança uma exceção - você pode adicionar um `try`/`catch` e decidir o que fazer se der erro, por exemplo).

Desta forma, tanto faz quantos números têm em cada linha. **Na verdade, pode até ter todos na mesma linha** que não fará diferença, já que eu pego cada linha, separo por espaço e vejo tudo que tem ali, até completar a quantidade de números.

---

Enfim, a forma "correta" depende do que você quer fazer exatamente (as perguntas que coloquei no início). Se quer sempre 10 números, é uma coisa. Se quer **validar** que as linhas têm sempre um (ou sempre dois) números, a solução é outra (teria que ver `if (partes.length == 2)`, por exemplo, e ainda teria que validar se são números mesmo, fazendo o `try`/`catch` no `parseInt`, etc).

Comment: Muito obrigado @hkotsubo. Pra deixar mais claro o que eu quero fazer é ler valores que podem ser int ou String e que podem estar em duplas ou sozinhos em cada linha. Eles não necessariamente precisam ser 10 mas essa é a quantidade máxima. Sua resposta já vai me ajudar muito.

Comment: Uma coisa que não entendi foi o for (String parte : partes), o que significa esse : ?

Comment: @kiss_cpp Isso é o [*enhanced for*](https://blogs.oracle.com/corejavatechtips/using-enhanced-for-loops-with-your-classes), é só um outro jeito de percorrer um array. Vc poderia fazer `for (int i = 0; i < partes.length; i++) { String parte = partes[i]; etc...}`, que daria na mesma (mas quando eu só quero percorrer os elementos do array, sem me importar com o índice, costumo usar o *enhanced for*, acho mais sucinto e direto).

Answer (score 1):

O método String.split recebe um separador como parâmetro. Então você poderia fazer algo como:

```
String[] campos = linha.split(" ");
for(String campo: campos) {
   // processa cada campo na linha
}
```

Uma outra opção melhor é usar a classe java.util.Scanner assim:

```
Scanner sc = new Scanner(linha);
while(sc.hasNext()) {
   String campo = sc.next();
}
```

Scanner tem outros métodos interessantes que facilitam ainda mais como Scanner.nextInt ou Scanner.nextLong. Vale uma olhada na documentação: https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/Scanner.html

Comment: No segundo exemplo, .hasNext() retorna true se tiver outro token. Então no caso se for "10 20" no input o resultado vai ser true?

Comment: o sc.next() não vai pegar a string inteira?

Comment: @kiss_cpp O Scanner quebra a string orginal em tokens ("10 20" cria dois tokens: "10" e "20") Cada Scanner.next() retorna um token. A primeira vez que chamar o next() retorna o "10", a segunda retorna o "20".